# Undocumented syntax of FilledCurve

Tags: graphics, version-8, undocumented

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undocumented form for FilledCurve[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/702/undocumented-form-for-filledcurve)

A nice trick to get the outline paths of letters is to use the PDF exporter/importer

```
el= 
First[
  First[
    ImportString[
      ExportString[
        Style["L", Italic, FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
        "PDF"
      ], 
      "PDF", 
      "TextMode" -> "Outlines"
     ]
   ]
];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightBlue, el}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The outline paths are given in a `FilledCurve` construction (new in MMA8):

```
el

(*
===>
{Thickness[0.07507507507507508], 
 Style[
   {FilledCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, 
                {{{12.887695983062486, 5.160000000000004}, 
                  {1.8237311169604027, 5.160000000000004}, 
                  {5.496094644083314, 22.410000000000004}, 
                  {7.823731116960403, 22.410000000000004}, 
                  {4.5834973678187225, 7.222500000000004}, 
                  {13.319824330510414, 7.222500000000004}
                }}
    ]
   }, 
   Thickness -> 0.07507507507507508
  ]}
 *)
```

This syntax variant is not given in the `FilledCurve` help page:`

[image: Mathematica graphics]
with *segments* defined as:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The doc page doesn't give a formal definition of *components*, BTW)

While the second argument of `FilledCurve` in the undocumented output above is pretty obvious (the coordinates of the outline), the first part is not. My hypothesis is that it has something to do with bezier control points or so. Anyone got an idea about this?

Comment: Sjoerd, I would like to merge this Q&A into [(702)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/702/121) to put the answers in one place.  Is that OK with you?

Comment: Merged, with your permission.