# Character edge finding

Tags: graphics, image-processing, sorting, conversion, smoothing

The following line of code finds the edge of a character:

```
pic = Binarize[GradientFilter[Rasterize[Style["\[Euro]", FontFamily -> "Times"], 
                              ImageSize -> 200] // Image, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The coordinates of the edges can be found as follows:

```
pdata = Position[ImageData[pic], 1];
```

Test:

```
Graphics[Point[pdata]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, the points are not sorted in an order usable by `Line` or `Polygon`:

```
Graphics[Polygon[pdata]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This brings me to my question:

- What would be an efficient method to sort the coordinates so that it would plot properly with `Line` or `Polygon`?

Additionally,

- How to thin and smooth the set of points?
- How to deal with characters with holes in them, like the ones below?

[image: Mathematica graphics] or [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: See http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Mar/msg00529.html

Comment: You can also use `EdgeDetect` for detecting the edges

Comment: @R.M. I tried that, but at first sight the gradient filter looked slightly better to me. The other one looked a bit more irregular. However, the edge detected version has a smaller set of points and that's actually good (question 2)

Comment: `FindCurvePath` (or `ListCurvePathPlot`) or `FindShortestTour` with one of its many `Method` option values (`"Greedy"`?) could be of use.  I don't have time to figure out a full solution now.

Comment: [A relevant question from SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740847) Sadly [Graham scans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) work only for convex polygons, but you can use it if the outline for the character is convex.

Comment: Related: [75855](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75855/finding-a-function-that-fits-the-shape-of-an-image)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think there is a neat solution. We have curios function `ListCurvePathPlot`:

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize[GradientFilter[Rasterize[Style["\[Euro]", 
FontFamily -> "Times"], ImageSize -> 200] // Image, 1]];

pdata = Position[ImageData[pic], 1];

lcp = ListCurvePathPlot[pdata]
```

[image]

Now this is of course `Graphics` containing `Line` with set of points

```
lcp[[1, 1, 3, 2]]
```

[image]

So of course we can do something like

```
Graphics3D[Table[{Orange, Opacity[.5],Polygon[(#~Join~{10 n})&
/@ lcp[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]]}, {n, 10}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

I think it works nicely with "8" and `Polygon`:

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize[GradientFilter[
Rasterize[Style["8", FontFamily -> "Times"], ImageSize -> 500] //Image, 1]]; 
pdata = Position[ImageData[pic], 1]; lcp = ListCurvePathPlot[pdata]
```

[image]

And you can do polygons 1-by-1 extraction:

```
Graphics3D[{{Orange, Thick, Polygon[(#~Join~{0}) & /@ lcp[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]]},
  {Red, Thick, Polygon[(#~Join~{1}) & /@ lcp[[1, 1, 3, 3, 1]]]},
  {Blue, Thick, Polygon[(#~Join~{200}) & /@ lcp[[1, 1, 3, 4, 1]]]}}]
```

[image]

=> To **smooth** the curve set `ImageSize ->` "larger number" in your `pic =` code.

=> To **thin** the curve to 1 pixel wide use `Thinning`:

```
 Row@{Thinning[#], Identity[#]} &@Binarize[GradientFilter[
 Rasterize[Style["\[Euro]", FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 ImageSize -> 200] // Image, 1]]
```

[image]

You can do curve extraction more efficiently with Mathematica. A simple example would be

```
text = First[
   First[ImportString[
     ExportString[
      Style["\[Euro] 9 M-8 ", Italic, FontSize -> 24, 
       FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], "PDF", 
     "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], text}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was aware of this possibility (see my earlier question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/563/57). The main reason for my question is I want to go 3D and `FilledCurve` doesn't do that.

Comment: (`FilledCurve` being the carrier of the above paths)

Comment: @R.M. That might be the ultimate goal, but a flat version living in 3D space would be nice for starters.

Comment: I completely forgot about `ListCurvePathPlot`.  +1!

Comment: I was playing with `ImportString` for the outlines and was reminded of this... I noticed that `"TextMode" -> "Outlines"` doesn't really do anything. You could replace it with `"TextMode -> "foo"` or remove it altogether, and it'll still give you the same result.The documentation uses the above syntax in a couple of places too... do you know if there are cases where setting the `"TextMode"` changes the result? Do you also know what other options are available for `"TextMode"`, perhaps bounding boxes?

Answer (score 26):

You can recast this to a problem of finding a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph constructed in a certain way from your points (distance graph). First, compute mutual distances:

```
distances = 
With[{tr = Transpose[N@pdata]},
 Function[point, Sqrt[Total[(point - tr)^2]]] /@ 
  N[pdata]];
```

Now, construct an adjacency matrix by stating that two vertices (points) are connected if their disctance is smaller than a certain radius (which I tweaked a bit):

```
radius = 1;
adj = Unitize@Clip[distances, {0, radius}, {0, 0}];
```

Now build an adjacency graph:

```
graph = AdjacencyGraph[adj];
```

And find the cycle:

```
cycle = FindHamiltonianCycle[graph];
```

Finally, the plot:

```
Graphics[Polygon[pdata[[cycle[[1, All, 1]]]]]]
```

This probably can be refined further.

[image]

Comment: This a pretty neat idea - love the span of approach. Could function `Norm` be used in your 1st snippet of code?

Comment: @Vitaly Thanks. Norm - yes, I could have used it. but it would slow things down, since here I used Listability.

Comment: I think there may be an extraneous `)` lurking in the definiton of `distances`.

Comment: @image_doctor Thanks, corrected. It is telling that this has only be noticed now, more than a year after it has been posted :-).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It seems the unit test was a little delayed this time around :)

Answer (score 26):

Possible answer using `ClusteringComponents`:

```
image=Rasterize[
 Style["Sjoerd!",Italic,FontSize->24,FontFamily->"Times"],
 "Image",ImageSize->200]

cluster=ClusteringComponents[ImageReflect[image,Left->Right]];

ListPlot3D[cluster,Mesh->False,BoxRatios->{3,1,1},Boxed->False,
 Axes->False,Lighting->"Neutral",
 ViewPoint->{-0.4340374864952124,0.8958897046884841,3.2340366567727856`}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another fun one, using `RegionPlot3D` on the same cluster data:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 cluster[[Round[x], Round[y]]] > 1.5, {x, 1, 66}, {y, 1, 202}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's neat. Is there a similar example in Documentation?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov - Not to my knowledge ...

Answer (score 23):

I tried `FindCurvePath` and `FindShortestTour`, but didn't succeed.  The latter is too slow to finish on my machine, except when using the `"Greedy"` method, which does not give a perfect solution.

Here's something different:

```
matrix = Rasterize[
    Style["\[Euro]", FontFamily -> "Times", Antialiasing -> False], 
    "Data", ImageSize -> 200][[All, All, 1]];

fun = ListInterpolation[matrix]

{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = fun["Domain"]

g = RegionPlot[fun[x, y] < 128, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The filling of the region is made of a large number of polygons, but the outline is just one or more lines, which we can easily extract ...

```
Graphics[Cases[Normal[g], Line[___], Infinity]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... or even make into polygons again:

```
% /. Line -> Polygon
```

---

**EDIT**

I noticed Vitaliy's `Thinning` solution.   With that `ListCurvePathPlot` works:

```
img = Thinning@
  EdgeDetect@
   Rasterize[Style["\[Euro]", FontFamily -> "Times"], "Image", 
    ImageSize -> 200]

points = N@Position[ImageData[img], 1];

ListCurvePathPlot[points]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`FindCurvePath` will give you the ordering of points.  This won't of course work for the image of number `8` or `9`.

We can also apply a slight smoothing:

```
orderedPoints = points[[First@FindCurvePath[points]]];    
ListLinePlot[MovingAverage[orderedPoints, 3]]
```

Warning: `FindCurvePath` may return a number of disconnected curves!

Answer (score 19):

A year late, but here are my thoughts:

As Szabolcs showed, extracting the `Line` primitives from a `RegionPlot` provides a convenient way to produce a polygon from an image. The function `imgToPolys` below does just that - it's essentially the same as Szabolcs' code but I use `ImageValue` instead of creating an interpolating function from the image data.

Of course, some of the polygons produced this way are the "holes" in letters. In order to display the text properly we need to identify which polygons are holes and which are "solids" (for want of a better word). The function `findHoles` takes a list of polygons and uses the undocumented function `` Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ `` to test whether the first point of each polygon lies inside any of the other polygons. I've assumed that any "holes" are completely contained within a surrounding "solid", so that testing a single point is sufficient. The expression returned by `findHoles` is a list of {solids, holes}.

```
imgToPolys[img_Image] :=
 Module[{w, h, rp},
  {w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
  rp = RegionPlot[
    ImageValue[img, {x, y}] < 0.5, {x, 0.5, w - 0.5}, {y, 0.5, h - 0.5}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100];
  Cases[Normal[rp], l_Line :> Polygon @@ l, -1]];

findHoles[p : {_Polygon ..}] := Module[{inq, holes, solids},
  inq = Outer[Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ, p, p[[All, 1, 1]], 1];
  holes = DeleteCases[inq ~Position~ True , {x_, x_}][[All, 2]];
  solids = Complement[Range[Length[p]], holes];
  {p[[solids]], p[[holes]]}];
```

Here's an example where I have shown the holes in white, so they look like, well, holes.

```
input = Style["{##}&/@", Bold, FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 12];

img = Rasterize[input, ImageSize -> 800] ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale" ~
  ImageResize~ 400;

{solids, holes} = findHoles@imgToPolys@img;

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Yellow, solids, White, holes}]
```

[image]

### Faster method using FilledCurve

The procedure above is rather slow, due to the `RegionPlot`. An alternative way to create polygons from text is from the `FilledCurve` primitives that can be obtained by converting via PDF (as in Vitaliy's answer). Below is some code to convert the filled curves into polygons.

The conversion is a two stage process, first the filled curves are converted to bezier curves, then the bezier curves are sampled at some number of points (default 10), and the coordinates fed into a `Polygon` expression.

As previously, the polygons can then be split into "solids" and "holes" using `findHoles`.

```
filledCurveToBeziers[fc_FilledCurve] := MapThread[processFCdata, List @@ fc];

processFCdata[desc_, pts_] := Module[{r, sd},
  r = Range @@@ 
    ReplacePart[
     Partition[Prepend[Accumulate[desc[[All, 2]]], 0], 2, 1], {1, 1} -> 1];
  sd = desc[[All, 3]] /. {0 -> 1};
  MapThread[BezierCurve[pts[[#1]], SplineDegree -> #2] &, {r, sd}]];

beziersToPolygons[x_, n_: 10] :=
 Module[{samples},
  samples = x /. BezierCurve[data__] :> BezierFunction[data] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/n];
  Polygon /@ Select[Split[Flatten[#, 1]][[All, 1]] & /@ samples, Length[#] > 1 &]];
```

This approach is much faster, since it completely avoids the rasterization and image processing.

```
{solids, holes} = 
  With[{fc = Cases[ImportString[ExportString[input, "PDF"]], _FilledCurve, -1]},
   Transpose[findHoles@beziersToPolygons[filledCurveToBeziers@#, 10] & /@ fc]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Yellow, solids, White, holes}]
```

[image]

Comment: Better late than never! Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

From the sublime to the ridiculous. By way of contrast, here's another approach to 3D text rendering:

```
sjoerd = Image[
     Rasterize[" sjoerd ", RasterSize -> 900, ImageSize -> 900]];

Manipulate[
   ImagePerspectiveTransformation[sjoerd, 
      ScalingMatrix[s, {v1, v2, v3}],  Padding -> "Periodic", 
      Resampling -> "Bicubic"], {{s, .2}, 0.1, 8}, 
         {{v1, -1}, -1, 1}, {{v2, -0.1}, -1, 1}, {{v3, .3}, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image: 3D lettering here]

Perhaps it's more fun to play with than to look at... :)

Answer (score 11):

Posting as an answer per request. See

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Mar/msg00529.html

Caveat: It's been almost a year since I've toyed with that code. Strange things can happen to code left on the dusty shelves of Usenet. The basic idea was similar to Leonid's: use some proximity measure to find neighbor pairs. And be prepared for some failure cases that may need further tweaking, that is to say, segment "jumps" to nearby lines.