# Ideas on how to improve the rendering of the letter B in this 3D region plot?

Tags: graphics, regions

I have been playing with the RegionPlot3D idea from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/643#643) and have been trying
to approximate the [Gödel, Escher, Bach logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GEBcover.jpg), but I am a little bit stuck on how to improve the
rendering of the letter B. Here is the code so far:

```
Letter[s_String] := 
 ClusteringComponents[
  Rasterize[Style[s, 128, Bold], "Image", RasterSize -> {100, 100}]]

Gödel = Letter["G"];
Escher = Letter["E"];
Bach = Letter["B"];

SetOptions[RegionPlot3D, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> Orange];

RegionPlot3D[
 Gödel[[Round[i], Round[j]]] > 1 && 
 Escher[[Round[i], Round[k]]] > 1 &&
 Bach[[Round[j], Round[k]]] > 1, 
 {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}, {k, 1, 100}]
```

This works nicely for the letter E and G as can be seen here:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the letter B is not looking as nice, I think because of the shape of the
letter G:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am wondering if anyone has any good suggestions to correct the rendering of the letter B?

Comment: What you need is a font that is as quadratic as possible. Just consider the extreme case of one of the letters being an *I*.

Comment: Simply setting the font family to "Helvetica" is a big improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the B appears incorrectly is not because of the shape of G, but rather because the horizontal length of G is less than the vertical length of B, resulting in B being decapitated. Here's how the letters look at present when one is laid on top of the other at 90º:

[image]

Notice that in the [actual GEB logo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/GEBcover.jpg), they use a squarish font, which solves this problem. So a possible solution, in the absence of a square font, is to set the aspect ratio of each of the letter shapes to 1, so that they sit well with each other.

Here is a solution that uses Vitaliy's [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/638/5) for extracting the outlines from letters.

```
letter[s_String] := ImageData@ Binarize@Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Black], 
     First[First[ImportString[ExportString[Style[s, FontSize -> 24], "PDF"], 
        "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 100]
```

Now you can see that the shapes now line up correctly:

[image]

Proceeding with your `RegionPlot3D` code, but with slight modifications,

```
{g, e, b} = letter /@ {"G", "E", "B"};
RegionPlot3D[
 g[[Round[i], Round[j]]] == 0 && e[[Round[i], Round[k]]] == 0 && 
  b[[Round[j], Round[k]]] == 0, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}, {k, 1, 100}]
```

we get a nice and pretty GEB logo that reproduces the B and all the other letters correctly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some square font from internet:

```
{Bach, Escher, Gödel} = ClusteringComponents /@
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Gödel[[Round[i], Round[j]]] > 1 && Escher[[Round[i], Round[k]]] > 1 &&
   Bach[[Round[j], Round[k]]] > 1, {i, 1, 120}, {j, 1, 120}, {k, 1, 
  120}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Mesh -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]