# How to make an inkblot?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, image-processing, generative-art

How to effectively create a polygon that looks like a realistic inkblot? So far, I could come up with this (borrowing from Ed Pegg Jr.'s [Rorschach demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RorschachTest/)):

```
RandomBlot[num_, opts___] := Module[{pts},
   pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, 2}];
   pts = pts[[Append[Last@FindShortestTour[pts, Method -> "TwoOpt"], 1]]];
   Graphics[{Polygon@
      Table[BSplineFunction[pts, SplineKnots -> "Clamped"][a], {a, 0, 1, 0.001}]}, opts]
   ];

blot = RandomBlot[40, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two problems with this:

- it is a bit slow due to `FindShortestTour`
- the blot contains corners being too sharp and has 'bays' reaching too far inward.

Compare it to a desired outcome:

[image: inkblot]

**Update:**

I should mention that it is not necessary to actually create a Rorschach-like image, so mirroring is not a requirement.

Comment: Is it important to have concave parts of in the shape?  Without concave parts it's easy ...

Comment: @Szabolcs, I noticed. ``ComputationalGeometry`ConvexHull`` does it quite well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I would say: let it be a parameter of the model, that specifies the amount of concavity/convexity. If the valu of this parameter is zero, the output could be an ellipse.

Comment: Can anyone post photographs of actual ink blots on paper, so we can judge what is realistic?

Comment: There's also the ink blot demonstration by Andy Ross [link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RandomInkBlot/)

Comment: I remember reading an approach to this using cellular automaton.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A bit of image processing:

```
Table[
  Blur[
    Dilation[
     Graphics[
      Table[
        Rotate[
           Disk[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {2}], {RandomReal[{1, 5}],RandomReal[{1, 5}]}],
           RandomReal[{0, 3.14}]
          ], 
         {40}
       ]
     ], 
     DiskMatrix[20]
   ], 20
  ]// Binarize, 
  {3}, {3}
] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lots of parameters to play with...

Now these are bitmaps and if vector graphics are required (the question seems to imply that) we can adapt a bit of Vitaly's code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/638/57):

```
img = Thinning@EdgeDetect@p;
points = N@Position[ImageData[img], 1];
pts = FindCurvePath[points] /. c_Integer :> points[[c]];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed, Thick, Red]],FilledCurve@({Line@#} & /@ pts)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with p our blob bitmap. (The contour is dashed to better show that we're dealing with vector graphics here).

Comment: Nice, these inkblots look more realistic than the others

Comment: Ah, I see fish bones ... What does that mean?  (+1)

Comment: I **love** parameters!

Answer (score 84):

This approach is based on a random walk of a shrinking disk. Several of these are combined and a Gaussian filter is used to smooth it out. Optionally the smoothed image can be multiplied by the original to restore the tiny "droplets" that are wiped out by the smoothing. There is a streakiness parameter which biases the random walk in a particular direction.

```
randomstep := RandomReal[{0,1}] Through[{Cos,Sin}[RandomReal[{0,2Pi}]]];

rndwalk[numpts_, streakiness_, numruns_] := Module[{streak}, Table[
streak = streakiness randomstep;
RandomChoice[{Identity, Reverse}]@
 NestList[# + streak + 0.1 randomstep &, randomstep, numpts]
, {numruns}]];

spatter[points_] := ImagePad[Rasterize@
Graphics[
 Thread[Disk[#, 
     Range[(Length@# - 1), 0, -1]/(10. (Length@# - 1))]] & /@ 
  points], 50, 1];

imageprocess[pic_, filterwidth_, threshold_, droplets_, reflect_] := 
Module[{smoothed, combined},
smoothed = Binarize[GaussianFilter[pic, filterwidth], threshold];
combined = If[droplets, ImageMultiply[smoothed, pic], smoothed];
If[reflect, ImageMultiply[combined, ImageReflect[combined, Left]], 
combined]];

Manipulate[
SeedRandom[seed];
imageprocess[spatter[rndwalk[numpts, streakiness, numspatters]], 
filterwidth, threshold, droplets, reflect],
{{seed, 0}, 0, 10^6, 1},
{{numpts, 100}, 10, 300, 1},
{{streakiness, 0}, 0, 0.05},
{{numspatters, 10}, 1, 20, 1},
{{filterwidth, 10}, 1, 20},
{{threshold, 0.6}, 0, 1},
{{droplets, True}, {True, False}},
{{reflect, True}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: inkblots]

Comment: Very realistic and fast, I love it!

Comment: +1, those are awesome! You get a lot of alien looking pictures, though.

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: @rcollyer, I'm glad I'm not the only one seeing aliens! I wasn't sure if it was some deep-seated psychological issue...

Comment: Here's two I made that I particularly liked: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aQjWa.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ljZO.png

Comment: I am pretty sure those are miraculous appearances of the spagetti flying monster.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24072/315) :)

Answer (score 48):

Here's a slow and concave version:

```
blot[smoothness_: 20, points_Integer: 10] :=
 With[
  {fun = Exp[-smoothness #.#] &, pts = RandomReal[1, {points, 2}]},
  RegionPlot[
   Total[fun[# - {x, y}] & /@ pts] > .5, {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5},
    Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
  ]

Grid@Table[blot[], {3}, {3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Per Leonid's suggestion, here's a considerably faster version using "just in time" compiling:

```
blotc[smoothness_: 20, points_Integer: 10] :=
 With[{fun = Exp[-smoothness #.#] &, pts = RandomReal[1, {points, 2}]},
  With[{fc = Compile[{xl, yl}, Total[fun[# - {xl, yl}] & /@ pts] > .5]},
   RegionPlot[fc[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, 
     Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
  ]
 ]
```

Thanks to the speed of the Mathematica compiler, this will speeds it up about 5 times on my computer.

---

Here's a fast but always convex version:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
pts = With[{points = RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]}, points[[ConvexHull[points]]]]
Graphics@FilledCurve[BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is desired but sometimes the slow code will generate multiple disconnected regions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NAu8N.png Upvote regardless! Haha you edited your answer while I was writing my comment.

Comment: @s0rce Yep, but real inkblots can be disconnected too :)  It's a good very good question how to get rid of disconnected parts.  One possibility is `MorphologicalComponents`.  If we're doing image processing, we might as well try implementing this in terms of image processing functions:  `Binarize@ImageAdjust@
  ImageCorrelate[
   ImagePad[
    Image@SparseArray@Thread[RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 2}] -> 1], 
    20], GaussianMatrix[40]]`  (It's a start, but it still has problems)

Comment: Next question could be leopard spots :D  Maybe someone will write a full reaction-diffusion system simulation

Comment: @Szabolcs, I've already done that but to make a 2D pattern out of an ODE system is not trivial :) The answer is really nice, I think that disconnected spots/holes make it more realistic!

Comment: Nice! +1. You can speed up your first function 8-10x by using `With[{fc = Compile[{xl, yl}, Total[fun[# - {xl, yl}] & /@ pts] > .5]}, RegionPlot[fc[x, y],...]]` in place of your `RegionPlot` call (compiled to MVM target, not C). I think this is a good example of JIT compilation in action for mma.

Answer (score 41):

An inkblot used to look like this, in the days when I used fountain pens and indian ink, rather than Mathematica:

```
blot = Image[BubbleChart[RandomReal[1, {20, 3}] , Axes -> None,  
  Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> Function[Black],  
  BubbleSizes -> {.001, .3}, Background -> LightGray, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "NoiseBubble", ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image: inky blot]

Edit: The paper is then to be folded in half to stimulate those revealing subconscious thoughts:

```
ImageAdjust[ImageMultiply[blot, ImageReflect[blot, Left]], {0, .2}]
```

[image: folded inky blot]

Comment: Now you just need to factor in the porosity of the blotting paper, throw in some surface tension and capillary action and you'll be all set =)

Comment: Blotting paper was not yet invented in those days

Comment: But since benches in those times were not flat but [slanted](http://www.refiskolaoh.hu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Oszt%C3%A1lyterem.jpg) any ink splattered on the paper immediatly ran off.

Comment: It would be nice to extract/reproduce the actual method "NoiseBubble" uses, as this could be a wrapper applied to the other solutions to give more realistic blot-edges. I guess it is just a radial positive noise over points of the circle.

Comment: To continue the food theme, the last one looks like a crab.

Answer (score 31):

This solution uses [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) to generate the blobs.

To generate the noise we use the following function. Here, `range` is the domain on which we will generate the noise, `res` is the number of points in `x` and `y` direction, and `seed` is the seed for the random number generator.

```
perlinNoise[range_: {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, res_: {30, 30}, seed_: 1] :=
 With[{
   grid = (SeedRandom[seed]; Table[With[{t = RandomReal[2 Pi]},
       {Cos[t], Sin[t]}], {res[[1]]}, {res[[2]]}]),
   intf = 3 #^2 - 2 #^3 &},
  Function[{x, y},
   Module[{ind, xr, yr, pmat},
    (* ind=={{xmin,xmax},{ymin,
    ymax}} *)
    {xr, yr} = 
     MapThread[Rescale[#1, #2, {1, #3}] &, {{x, y}, range, res}];
    ind = Floor[{xr, yr}];
    ind = MapThread[Min[#1, #2 - 1] &, {ind, res}];
    {xr, yr} -= ind;

    pmat = {{{xr, yr}.grid[[ind[[1]], ind[[2]]]],
       {xr, yr - 1}.grid[[ind[[1]], ind[[2]] + 1]]},
      {{xr - 1, yr}.grid[[ind[[1]] + 1, ind[[2]]]],
       {xr - 1, yr - 1}.grid[[ind[[1]] + 1, ind[[2]] + 1]]}};

    {1 - intf[xr], intf[xr]}.pmat.{1 - intf[yr], intf[yr]}]]]
```

Next we're going to superpose some noise on top of a two-dimensional Gaussian function and we use `ListContourPlot` to plot the region where the resulting function is larger than some level (note that we could use RegionPlot as well, but `ListContourPlot` is faster). There are a lot of parameters to play with here, such as the resolution of the noise, the ratio between the noise and Gaussian surface, and the level of the contour. For example for

```
res = 30; seed = 3; level = .6; ratio = .15;
```

we get

```
f = perlinNoise[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {res, res}, seed];
tab1 = Table[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] + ratio*f[x, y], {x, -1, 1, 1/(2 res)}, {y, -1, 1, 
    1/(2 res)}];
pl = ListContourPlot[ArrayPad[tab1, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 2, Contours -> {level}, ContourShading -> None, 
   Frame -> False];
pl/. {___, a__Line} :> FilledCurve[Thread[{{a}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By increasing the ratio get more splattering:

```
res = 30; seed = 3; level = .6; ratio = .8;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And by lowering the resolution you get smoother blobs:

```
res = 8; seed = 3; level = .6; ratio = .8;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For the last one, I see a butterflied chicken, or possibly a face. Guess that indicates that I'm crazy.

Comment: @rcollyer First fish bones, now a butterflied chicken. Maybe you're just hungry.

Comment: Not anymore, just had pie, or if you prefer Pi/4.

Comment: There's a Perlin noise example on the doc page of `Compile`, if you're interested

Answer (score 31):

This solution is based on a generation of blots that are deformations of a circle:

```
drop[
    tan_ /; NumberQ[N[tan]] && NonNegative[tan], 
    rad_ /; NumberQ[N[rad]] && NonNegative[rad], 
    n_Integer /; Positive[n], num_Integer /; Positive[num]] := 
    Module[{phi, radialDirection, tangentialDirection, radialAmplitudes,
        tangentialAmplitudes, tmp},
        radialDirection[phi_] := N[{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}];
        tangentialDirection[phi_] := N[{-Sin[phi], Cos[phi]}];
        radialAmplitudes = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}];
        tangentialAmplitudes = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}];
        tmp = Table[radialDirection[phi] + Apply[Plus, 
        Map[N[rad*radialAmplitudes[[# - 2]]*
        radialDirection[# phi]/#^2] &, Range[3, n + 2]]] + Apply[Plus,
        Map[N[tan*tangentialAmplitudes[[# - 2]]*
        tangentialDirection[# phi]/#^2] &, Range[3, n + 2]]],
        {phi, 0, N[2 Pi - Pi/num], N[2 Pi/num]}]; Append[tmp, First[tmp]]
];
```

Then ink splatters can be generated in this way:

```
inksplatter = Image[Graphics[
    Table[With[{loc = {RandomReal[{-5, 5}], RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}},
    Scale[Polygon[Map[(# + loc) &, 
    drop[RandomReal[{.5, 1.5}], RandomReal[{.5, 1.5}], 10, 100]]],
    RandomReal[{.1, 1.2}]]
    ], {20}], PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, AspectRatio -> 1]]
```

that produces this:

[image: ink splatter]

and a nice inkblot:

```
ImageAdjust[ImageMultiply[inksplatter, ImageReflect[inksplatter, Left]], {0, .2}]
```

[image: ink blot]

Comment: The last one's definitely a panda with mutton chops!

Comment: @R.M possibly a pig.

Answer (score 24):

While I enjoyed fiddling with each of the beautiful solutions you gave, I chose two that are the closest to what I needed in *form*, *splatter-distribution*, *parameterization* and *speed*. As a token of my appreciation I've reworked them into a dynamic demo, showcasing Szabolcs's and Sjoerd's solutions. This does not mean that the other solutions could not be included: I think all of them could be easily extended to comply with the specified parameters. I simply don't have more time. But if anyone feels like doing it, please go ahead, and edit this post!

Both methods are wrapped in a smoothing function (`Blur` & `Binarize`), and then in a "fractalization" function that detects the edge and applies some noise to it in the form of black and white disks (idea coming from Sjoerd's solution). This can be done recursively, with disks of smaller and smaller sizes, adding more subtle details.

```
Options[RandomBlot] = 
  Join[Options@Graphics, {RandomSeed -> Automatic, Elevation -> 2, 
    EdgeRecursion -> 2, EdgeResolution -> 300, EdgeSmoothing -> 7, 
    Method -> Automatic}];

RandomBlot[bulk_: .1, pat_: 0, smo_: .2, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ratio, seed, ele, rec, res, rad, method, edgeNoise, range},
   ratio = OptionValue@AspectRatio /. Automatic -> 1;
   ele = OptionValue@Elevation /. Automatic -> 2;
   rec = OptionValue@EdgeRecursion /. Automatic -> 2;
   res = OptionValue@EdgeResolution /. Automatic -> 300;
   rad = OptionValue@EdgeSmoothing /. Automatic -> 5;
   method = OptionValue@Method /. Automatic -> "Szabolcs";
   seed = 
    OptionValue@RandomSeed /. 
     Automatic -> RandomInteger@{0, 99999999999999};

   edgeNoise[img_, lev_, num_: 300] := 
    Module[{pt = 
       N@Position[
         Reverse[Transpose@ImageData@Thinning@EdgeDetect@img, {2}], 
         1], new},
     pt = Take[RandomSample@pt, Min[num, Length@pt]];
     new = 
      Show[img, 
       Graphics[({RandomChoice@{Black, White}, 
            Rotate[Disk[#, RandomReal[{0, 15/lev}, {2}]], 
             RandomReal@{0, \[Pi]}]} & /@ pt)]];
     Blur[new, rad] // Binarize];

   BlockRandom[SeedRandom@seed;
    Show[
     Fold[edgeNoise[#1, #2, res] &,
      Blur[Switch[method,
         "Szabolcs", range = 10;
         With[{fun = Exp[-Round[pat*100] #.#] &, 
           pts = Transpose@{RandomReal[{-range, range}, {Round[100*bulk]}], 
              RandomReal[{-range, range}*ratio, {Round[100*bulk]}]}},
          With[{fc = Compile[{xl, yl}, 
              Total[fun[# - {xl, yl}] & /@ (pts*.9)] > 1/ele]},
           RegionPlot[
            fc[x, y], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range*ratio, 
             range*ratio}, PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black,
             Frame -> False]]],

         "Sjoerd",
         Dilation[Graphics[{
            Black, 
            Table[Rotate[
              Disk[{RandomReal@{-10, 10}, 
                RandomReal@({-10, 10}*ratio)}, 
               RandomReal[{.1, 4}, {2}]], 
              RandomReal@{0, \[Pi]}], {Round[100*bulk]}],
            White, 
            Table[Rotate[
              Disk[{RandomReal@{-10, 10}, 
                RandomReal@({-10, 10}*ratio)}, 
               RandomReal[{.1, 2}, {2}]], 
              RandomReal@{0, \[Pi]}], {Round[100*bulk*pat]}]
            }], DiskMatrix@ele]
         ], 100*smo] // Binarize,
      Range@rec],
     FilterRules[{opts}, Options@Graphics]
     ]]];

Manipulate[
 RandomBlot[bulk, pat, smo, AspectRatio -> ratio, RandomSeed -> seed, 
  ImageSize -> size, Elevation -> ele, EdgeRecursion -> rec, 
  EdgeResolution -> res, EdgeSmoothing -> rad, Method -> method],
 {{seed, 0}, 
  Button["randomize", seed = RandomInteger@{0, 99999999999999}] &},
 {{method, "Szabolcs", 
   "method"}, {"Szabolcs" -> "RegionPlot (Szabolcs)", 
   "Sjoerd" -> "Disks (Sjoerd)"}},
 Delimiter,
 {{bulk, .1, "bulkiness"}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{pat, .05, "patchiness"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{smo, .6, "smoothness"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ele, 2, "elevation"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter,
 {{rec, 0, "edge recursion"}, 0, 3, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{res, 300, "edge resolution"}, 0, 600, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{rad, 7, "edge smoothness"}, 0, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter,
 {{ratio, 1, "ratio"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{size, 300, "size"}, 100, 1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A collection of blots:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 22):

Hopefully, this entry is not too late. As with Heike, I also work with Perlin noise, but here I restrict myself to the one-dimensional version, and consider what happens when I treat it as a polar function:

```
fBm = With[{permutations = 
     Apply[Join, ConstantArray[RandomSample[Range[0, 255]], 2]]},
   Compile[{{x, _Real}},
    Module[{xf = Floor[x], xi, xa, u, i, j},
     xi = Mod[xf, 16] + 1;
     xa = x - xf; u = xa*xa*xa*(10.0 + xa*(xa*6.0 - 15.0));
     i = permutations[[permutations[[xi]] + 1]]; 
     j = permutations[[permutations[[xi + 1]] + 1]];
     (2 Boole[OddQ[i]] - 1)*xa*(1.0 - u) + 
     (2 Boole[OddQ[j]] - 1)*(xa - 1)*u], "CompilationTarget" -> "WVM", 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];

With[{a = 1, b = 3/4, c = 30, d = 15}, 
 Graphics[Cases[
    ParametricPlot[(a + b fBm[c + d t/(2 Pi)]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 
      0, 2 Pi}], _Line, Infinity] /. Line -> Polygon]]
```

[image: sample ink blot]

Here are a few more I got:

[image: some more inkblots]

Play around with various values of `a,b,c,d` (and maybe tweak `SeedRandom[]` while you're at it) and see what you get.

Here's how to generate an entire zoo of them:

```
Graphics[Table[
  With[{h = RandomReal[100], k = RandomReal[100], 
    a = RandomInteger[{1, 6}], b = RandomInteger[{1, 6}], 
    c = RandomInteger[255], d = RandomInteger[{3, 30}], 
    n = RandomInteger[{3, 30}]}, 
   Cases[ParametricPlot[
        {h, k} + (a + b fBm[c + d t/(2 Pi)]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
        {t, 0, 2 Pi}], _Line, Infinity] /. Line -> Polygon], {30}]]
```

[image: zoo of blots]

---

**(added 5/15/2012)**

If one wants inkblots with inherent bilateral symmetry, it is a simple matter to modify the code for generating them:

```
With[{a = 4, b = 3, c = 4, d = 6, n = 1}, 
 Graphics[Cases[
    ParametricPlot[(a + b fBm[c + d Sin[n t]]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 
      0, 2 Pi}], _Line, Infinity] /. Line -> Polygon]]
```

[image: bilaterally-symmetric inkblot]

Here are a few more:

[image: a few more inkblots]

Again, tweak the parameters to taste.

---

Here, we do something similar to cormullion's ink splotches:

```
Graphics[Table[
  With[{h = RandomReal[100], k = RandomReal[100], 
    a = RandomInteger[{4, 6}], b = RandomInteger[{1, 3}], 
    c = RandomInteger[255], d = RandomInteger[{3, 30}], 
    n = RandomInteger[{3, 30}]}, 
   Cases[ParametricPlot[
        {h, k} + (a + b fBm[c + d Sin[n t]]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
        {t, 0, 2 Pi}], _Line, Infinity] /. Line -> Polygon], {30}]]
```

[image: splotches]

Comment: Never too late, and vector-graphics are always welcome as they are usually much faster than image-processed solutions.

Comment: You already got my vote, what more do you want? :)

Comment: @rcollyer: nothing else, really. :) But I do have a few more inkblot-related ideas on the pipeline... which I will add to this answer later when I've polished them up.

Comment: Your last figure looks like plankton.

Comment: @Szabolcs [Or viruses.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:524px-Arenaviridae-esquema.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a cellular automaton based approach. I guess it has the advantage that you can see the inkblot in the making.

[image]

## Cellular Automaton Rules

The rules I'm using is called a "twisted majority" or "anneal" rule with a Moore neigbourhood (diagonal cells count as neighbours). It basically means that if there is a majority of live neighbours, then the cell stays alive, otherwise it dies. The "twisted" part comes from switching the 4-neighbour and 5-neighbour rule, where 5 neighbours lead to a dead cell and 4 to a live one. It effectively introduces "noise" and prevents the array from settling into a permanent state too soon.

So let's get the Wolfram code for this rule first

```
FromDigits[Reverse[{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}], 2]
```

> 976

## Getting the Inkblots

And that's it! All that's left is to plot the evolution of the array.
Using a random grid as initial condition:

```
Module[{rule = {976, {2, 1}, {1, 1}},
  init = SparseArray[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {300, 300}]],
  iterationmax = 500},
 Manipulate[
  ArrayPlot[First@CellularAutomaton[rule, init, {{iterations}}]]
  , {iterations, 0, iterationmax, 1}]
 ]
```

[image]

Anyone who's familiar with cellular automatons knows this is a classic pattern, I just thought that if you plotted it in monochrome, the patterns look very much like ink blots.

Of course, you then have to compromise between your blot resolution and the rendering speed. And the shape you get is very much dependent on the initial array.

Use an inset random array for the "ink on paper feel":

```
Module[{rule = {976, {2, 1}, {1, 1}},
  dim = 500,
  factor = 1./6,
  iterationmax = 500,
  init},
 init = SparseArray[
   Flatten[Table[{i, j} -> RandomInteger[], {i, Round[dim*factor], 
      Round[dim*(1 - factor)]}, {j, Round[dim*factor], 
      Round[dim*(1 - factor)]}]], {dim, dim}];
 ArrayPlot[First@CellularAutomaton[rule, init, {{iterationmax}}]]
 ]
```

[image]

Use a normally-distributed random array for a "splatter" feel:

```
Module[{rule = {976, {2, 1}, {1, 1}},
  iterationmax = 10,
  dim = 500,
  amplitude = .5,
  widthfactor = 100000,
  init},
 init = Table[
   RandomChoice[{1 - (amplitude*
         Exp[-((i - dim/2)^2/widthfactor + (j - dim/2)^2/
             widthfactor)]), 
      amplitude*
       Exp[-((i - dim/2)^2/widthfactor + (j - dim/2)^2/
           widthfactor)]} -> {0, 1}], {i, dim}, {j, dim}];
 ArrayPlot[First@CellularAutomaton[rule, init, {{iterationmax}}]]
 ]
```

[image]

And a classic reflected inkblot:

```
ImageAdjust[
 ImageMultiply[inkblot, ImageReflect[inkblot, Left]], {0, .2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) function
[`RandomRorschach`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomRorschach/). Here are examples:

```mathematica
SeedRandom[112];
Multicolumn@
 Table[ResourceFunction["RandomRorschach"][
   "NumberOfStrokes" -> {12, 12, 6}, "OrderedStrokePoints" -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[RandomReal[{0, 0.24}]] &), 
   "ImageEffects" -> RandomChoice[{{{"Jitter", 10}, {"OilPainting", 3}}, {{"OilPainting", 6}}}]], 16]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can also use [`ImageSynthesize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSynthesize.html):

```mathematica
ImageSynthesize["Rorschach test inkblot", 3]
```

[image]