# How to determine the convex hull of some text?

Tags: text, computational-geometry

How can I get the co-ordinates of the convex hull of a piece of `Text`?

Comment: Anyone would have a method that doesn’t first rasterize the text?

Answer (score 21):

An alternative approach that does not require the `ComputationalGeometry` package: You can use a combination of `ClusteringComponents` and `ComponentMeasurements` as follows:

Define

```
  chVertices[txtimg_] := 
  Insert[#, First@#, -1] &@
  ComponentMeasurements[ClusteringComponents[Binarize@txtimg, 2], 
  "ConvexVertices"][[2, 2]]
```

Example data:

```
  textimg1 = Image[Graphics[
  Text[Style["'., ab cgixyz,...", Green, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 72]]], 
  ImageSize -> {600, 100}];
  textimg2 = Image[Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Brown, 
  ImportString[ExportString[
  Style[".t e q s t,", Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 36], 
  "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]]}], ImageSize -> {600, 100}];
  textimg3 = Image[Graphics[
  Text[Style["Get Convex Hull points.", Orange, 56]]], 
  ImageSize -> {600, 100}];
```

Input pictures:

[image: input text images]

Results:

```
 Row[Show[#, Graphics@{Red, Thick, Line[chVertices[#]]}] & 
 /@ {textimg1, textimg2, textimg3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The question could be rephrased: how do we get a vector graphic from a bitmap?
The solution is pretty simple by using the code we can find [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3375/685).

```
p = Image[Graphics[Text[Style["Get Convex Hull points.", Large]]]];
img = Thinning@EdgeDetect@p;
points = N@Position[ImageData[img], 1];
pts = Union@Flatten[FindCurvePath[points] /. c_Integer :> points[[c]], 1];
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
chp = ConvexHull[pts];
Show[
Graphics@{Red, Thick, Line[Append[pts[[chp]], pts[[chp]][[1]]]]},
ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Another method:

```
text = Rasterize["Text"];
data = Position[text[[1, 1]], {0, 0, 0}];
rotated = RotationMatrix[90 Degree].# & /@ data;
data2D = {-#1, #2} & @@@ rotated;
<< ComputationalGeometry`
Quiet[convexhull = ConvexHull[data2D]];
hull = PlanarGraphPlot[data2D, convexhull];
Graphics[{Black, Point[data2D], hull[[1, 2]]}]
```

[image]

Working it a bit more:

```
t = Text[Style["Text", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 48]];
text = Rasterize[t, ImageResolution -> 80];
data = Position[text[[1, 1]], Table[Except@255, {3}]];
rotated = RotationMatrix[90 Degree].# & /@ data;
data2D = {-#1, #2} & @@@ rotated;
<< ComputationalGeometry`
Quiet[convexhull = ConvexHull[data2D]];
hull = PlanarGraphPlot[data2D, convexhull];
Graphics[{Black, Point[data2D], hull[[1, 2]]}]
```

[image]

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ Transpose[data2D];
Graphics[{Black, 
  Inset[text, {xmin + (xmax - xmin)/2 - 1, ymin + (ymax - ymin)/2},
   Center, Reverse@Most[Dimensions[text[[1, 1]]]]],
  Red, hull[[1, 2]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{xmin - 3, xmax + 3}, {ymin - 3, ymax + 3}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In **Version 10**, this can be elegantly done in one line. First we create some text (stealing from @kguler) as follows:

```
img = Image[Graphics[Text[Style["'., ab cgixyz,...", Green, FontFamily -> "Times", 
                 FontSize -> 72]]], ImageSize -> {600, 100}];
```

Then:

```
cvx = ConvexHullMesh @ ImageValuePositions[EdgeDetect[img, 3], White];
```

Visualize:

```
Show[img, Graphics[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[cvx], {Thick, Red, MeshCells[cvx, 1]}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]