# Strange Tilt on error notification

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking, error-trapping

I was testing the source code of the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-to-make-an-inkblot?answertab=votes#tab-top).

And when I tried [this response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3579/1190) and maxed out most of the manipulators, this is what I got.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What went wrong that the errors are tilted. Can anyone explain?

[Here’s the link for the Notebook](http://goo.gl/hVjA9).

P.S. These are not  Photoshopped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `Shuffle` is not defined. If you define it (say, replace it with `RandomSample`) it works. Apparently, `Rotate` in the latter part of the code is being applied to the output of a function that uses `edgeNoise` which, in turn, (because `Shuffle` is undefined) is producing the error message you are seeing.

To replicate what is happening in a simple setting try

```
 Rotate[Graphics@Disk /@ Take[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}, something], 30 Degree]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, that was one of my packaged functions. Corrected!

Comment: @István, nice piece of code btw.