# xkcd-style Plots

Tags: plotting, generative-art

[image: xkcd 1064]

I received an email to which I wanted to respond with a xkcd-style graph, but I couldn't manage it. Everything I drew looked perfect, and I don't have enough command over `PlotLegends` to have these pieces of text floating around. Any tips on how one can create xkcd-style graphs? Where things look hand-drawn and imprecise. I guess drawing weird curves must be especially hard in *Mathematica*.

**EDIT:**

FWIW, this is sort of what I wanted to create. I used Simon Woods's `xkcdconvert`. By "answers" in this plot, I of course don't mean those given by experts to well-defined problems at places like here, but those offered by friends and family to real-life problems.

[image: my plot]

Comment: For the text floating around you might just use `Text` in combination with `Graphics` instead of `PlotLegend`.

Comment: Making wiggly curves shouldn't be a problem say with splines; another issue is the font...  you probably also need to interrupt curves when they intersect which implies you need to find the intersections.

Comment: Another challenge is the obvious white gap in a curve where another curve crosses over it. Do you prefer to have it?

Comment: @Vitaliy couldn't you just draw two lines, a thicker white one behind and the thinner colored one in front?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's a grand idea !

Comment: @chris, [the font's already been taken care of...](http://xkcdsucks.blogspot.com/2009/03/xkcdsucks-is-proud-to-present-humor.html) (see [this](http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf) as well.)

Comment: This does the wiggly curve... `pts = Table[{x, 5*Sin[x]/x}, {x, 0.01, 10, 0.1}];
pts2 = pts + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}/2, Dimensions[pts]];
f = BSplineFunction[pts2];
ParametricPlot[f[x], {x, 0.1, 0.9}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker[Cyan, 0.3], AbsoluteThickness[3]}]`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74878/430

Comment: Another clone: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12675147

Comment: Latex users can use the pgf package with the 'random steps' or 'bent' line decorations, as already answered in [this tex.stackexchange question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines).

Comment: To all the new users who have been attracted by this question, we encourage you to stick around and get to know what else Mathematica can do.

Comment: Where did all the visitors come from?  How did everyone hear about this challenge?

Comment: @DavidCarraher It quickly became a hot question and was featured on the SE hot questions page. I shared it on reddit, which caused the views and votes to explode

Comment: @DavidCarraher Also got to the top of hacker news.

Comment: Now I am seriously thinking of using this for the [Tech Conference Mathematica.SE promotion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/607/131)...

Comment: @Amatya, you should send the question's link to Randall Munroe.

Comment: @FredrikD I tweeted the link to him.

Comment: [Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701841/xkcd-style-graphs-in-matlab) version of the question.

Comment: This answer was highlighted as an exceptional in the  Wolfram Blog - thank you for excellent contribution! http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/

Comment: *Mathematica* 9 users please see the follow-up post at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17272/xkcdconvert-routines-perform-slower-in-mathematica-9 concerning slower speeds.

Comment: @J. M. I notice you changed "Woods'" to "Woods's" -- I thought the former was the correct form.  Does this rule differ geographically?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the rule that I was accustomed to was that since "Woods" is Simon's fine surname, and manifestly not plural, the proper course for forming the possessive is "Woods's", and AFAICT this is not one of those exceptions of a singular noun whose possessive is formed by simply appending an apostrophe. There is a mention of this in Strunk and White, off the top of my head.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for the education. :-)

Comment: [Analogous functionality in matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html#xkcd-style-sketch-plots).

Comment: Haven't been on Mathematica before so I don't have the rep for an answer, but if people are looking for interactive solutions then I've just discovered *amcharts* and they have a ['hand drawn' option](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/#theme-chalk) that gets you most of the way to this style. (ignore the blackboardesque theme, you can style black on white with CSS easily)

Answer (score 506, accepted):

The code below attempts to apply the XKCD style to a variety of plots and charts. The idea is to first apply cartoon-like styles to the graphics objects (thick lines, silly font etc), and then to apply a distortion using image processing.

The final function is `xkcdConvert` which is simply applied to a standard plot or chart.

The font style and size are set by `xkcdStyle` which can be changed to your preference. I've used the dreaded Comic Sans font, as the text will get distorted along with everything else and I thought that starting with the Humor Sans font might lead to unreadable text.

The function `xkcdLabel` is provided to allow labelling of plot lines using a little callout. The usage is `xkcdLabel[{str,{x1,y1},{xo,yo}]` where `str` is the label (e.g. a string), `{x1,y1}` is the position of the callout line and `{xo,yo}` is the offset determining the relative position of the label. The first example demonstrates its usage.

```
xkcdStyle = {FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS", 16};

xkcdLabel[{str_, {x1_, y1_}, {xo_, yo_}}] := Module[{x2, y2},
   x2 = x1 + xo; y2 = y1 + yo;
   {Inset[
     Style[str, xkcdStyle], {x2, y2}, {1.2 Sign[x1 - x2], 
      Sign[y1 - y2] Boole[x1 == x2]}], Thick, 
    BezierCurve[{{0.9 x1 + 0.1 x2, 0.9 y1 + 0.1 y2}, {x1, y2}, {x2, y2}}]}];

xkcdRules = {EdgeForm[ef:Except[None]] :> EdgeForm[Flatten@{ef, Thick, Black}], 
   Style[x_, st_] :> Style[x, xkcdStyle], 
   Pane[s_String] :> Pane[Style[s, xkcdStyle]],
   {h_Hue, l_Line} :> {Thickness[0.02], White, l, Thick, h, l},
   Grid[{{g_Graphics, s_String}}] :> Grid[{{g, Style[s, xkcdStyle]}}],
   Rule[PlotLabel, lab_] :> Rule[PlotLabel, Style[lab, xkcdStyle]]};

xkcdShow[p_] := Show[p, AxesStyle -> Thick, LabelStyle -> xkcdStyle] /. xkcdRules

xkcdShow[Labeled[p_, rest__]] := 
 Labeled[Show[p, AxesStyle -> Thick, LabelStyle -> xkcdStyle], rest] /. xkcdRules

xkcdDistort[p_] := Module[{r, ix, iy},
   r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 10, Padding -> White];
   {ix, iy} = 
    Table[RandomImage[{-1, 1}, ImageDimensions@r]~ImageConvolve~
      GaussianMatrix[10], {2}];
   ImagePad[ImageTransformation[r, 
     # + 15 {ImageValue[ix, #], ImageValue[iy, #]} &, DataRange -> Full], -5]];

xkcdConvert[x_] := xkcdDistort[xkcdShow[x]]
```

Version 7 users will need to use this code for `xkcdDistort`:

```
xkcdDistort[p_] := 
 Module[{r, id, ix, iy, samplepoints, funcs, channels},
  r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 10, Padding -> White]; 
  id = Reverse@ImageDimensions[r];
  {ix, iy} = Table[ListInterpolation[ImageData[
      Image@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, id]~ImageConvolve~GaussianMatrix[10]]], {2}]; 
  samplepoints = Table[{x + 15 ix[x, y], y + 15 iy[x, y]}, {x, id[[1]]}, {y, id[[2]]}]; 
  funcs = ListInterpolation[ImageData@#] & /@ ColorSeparate[r]; 
  channels = Apply[#, samplepoints, {2}] & /@ funcs; 
  ImagePad[ColorCombine[Image /@ channels], -10]]
```

**Examples**

Standard `Plot` including `xkcdLabel` as an `Epilog`:

```
f1[x_] := 5 + 50 (1 + Erf[x - 5]);
f2[x_] := 20 + 30 (1 - Erf[x - 5]);
xkcdConvert[Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 10},
  Epilog -> 
   xkcdLabel /@ {{"Label 1", {1, f1[1]}, {1, 30}}, {"Label 2", {8, f2[8]}, {0, 30}}},
  Ticks -> {{{3.5, "1st Event"}, {7, "2nd Event"}}, Automatic}]]
```

[image]

`BarChart` with either labels or legends:

```
xkcdConvert[BarChart[{10, 1}, ChartLabels -> {"XKCD", "Others"},
  PlotLabel -> "Popularity of questions on MMA.SE",
  Ticks -> {None, {{1, "Min"}, {10, "Max"}}}]]
```

[image]

```
xkcdConvert[BarChart[{1, 10}, ChartLegends -> {"Others", "XKCD"},
  PlotLabel -> "Popularity of questions on MMA.SE",
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Green}]]
```

[image]

Pie chart:

```
xkcdConvert[PieChart[{9, 1}, ChartLabels -> {"XKCD", "Others"},
  PlotLabel -> "Popularity of questions on MMA.SE"]]
```

[image]

ListPlot:

```
xkcdConvert[
 ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[10, 15], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

3D plots:

```
xkcdConvert[BarChart3D[{3, 2, 1}, ChartStyle -> Red, FaceGrids -> None,
  Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -4, 1},
  PlotLabel -> "This is just silly"]]
```

[image]

```
xkcdConvert[
 Plot3D[Exp[-10 (x^2 + y^2)^4], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  MeshStyle -> Thick,
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},
  PlotLabel -> Framed@"This plot is not\nparticularly useful"]]
```

[image]

It should also work for various other plotting functions like `ParametricPlot`, `LogPlot` and so on.

Comment: The distortion in the fonts looks really great!

Comment: Just realised my original had distortion only in one direction - now edited.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, for v7 I think the same effect could be acheived using interpolating functions. I'll have a look.

Comment: nice! the blurry font is neat too

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, v7 code added. I suspect there is a more efficient way to write it, but it works.

Comment: Fantastic answer Simon. The Fonts look amazing!

Comment: This is probably the _only_ time that someone has used Comic Sans and not gotten stoned for it ;)

Comment: @rm-rf, LOL. I wasn't sure if I'd get away with it or not :-)

Comment: LOL. Rake ´em in!

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I love this. This is by far my favourite of all answers here

Comment: take my upvotes. **take them!**

Comment: Congrats on the gold badge!

Comment: The best answer. Congratulations.

Comment: Diversity of objects it can be applied to is wonderful. I wonder would it take a lot to be able to apply `//xkcdConvert` to the **output** of 3D functions, so user can adjust/rotate/zoom `Graphics3D` first with mouse.

Comment: I would so upvote your answer again if I could... love the pie and 3D charts!!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Since in Mathematica you can use graphics in expressions just like anything else, you can just rotate it, and then apply `xkcdConvert` on the rotated graphics (just make sure you really apply it to the rotated graphics in the front end, not to the unrotated one stored in `Out`; if necessary, use Copy/Paste).

Comment: @celtschk I am aware of this. Nevertheless `xkcdConvert` produces pink fail box if you do that. I am on M8 Win7.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: What does the message on the pink fail box say? (I don't currently have access to a front end, so I can't check.)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, can you try changing the LHS of the first rule in `xkcdRules` to `EdgeForm[ef:Except[None]]` and tell me if that works for you?

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes, works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: This answer was highlighted as an exceptional in the  Wolfram Blog - thank you for excellent contribution! http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, awesome - thanks!

Comment: Oh I'm SO LOVE your answer! that I decide to use it in all my working reporter PPTs!

Comment: [DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE using Mathematica v9 for which the code is really slow](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17272/xkcdconvert-routines-perform-slower-in-mathematica-9)

Comment: Very Nice but it is very slow also... Any Improvement ?

Comment: @tchronis, follow the link in the comment above yours.

Comment: gosh: the inevitable is approaching fast: your (much better I must admit) answer is going to overtake the score of mine! :-)  I should have thought about this having worked on phase screens for my master's thesis.

Comment: Shows the power of Mathematica.

Answer (score 336):

Mostly thanks to Belisarius's elegant wrapping, you can do

```
h[fun_, divisor_, color_, at_] := Module[{k},
   k = BSplineFunction[Table[fun@x + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}/divisor], {x, 0.01, 10, .1}]];
   ParametricPlot[k[x], {x,0.1,0.9}, PlotStyle->{color, AbsoluteThickness@at}, Axes-> None]];

Show[{
  h[{#, 1.5 + 10 (Sin[#]^2/Sqrt[#]) Exp[-(# - 5)^2/2]} &, 3, Darker[Cyan, 0.3],  3],
  h[{#, 3 + 10 (Sin[#]^2/Sqrt[#])   Exp[-(# - 7)^2/2]} &, 3, White,              8],
  h[{#, 3 + 10 (Sin[#]^2/Sqrt[#])   Exp[-(# - 7)^2/2]} &, 3, Darker[Red, 0.3],   3],
  h[{1, #} &,                  4, Black, 3],    h[{0.65 + #/3, 0.1} &,       4, Black, 2],
  h[{5.65 + #/3, 0.1} &,       4, Black, 2],    h[{#, 1} &,                  4, Black, 3],
  h[{3 + #/6, 7 - 2 #/5} &,    8, Black, 1.25], h[{5, 7.5 + #/4} &,          4, Black, 2.5],
  h[{4.5 + #/2, 9.7 + #/75} &, 4, Black, 3],    h[{9, 7.5 + #/4} &,          3, Black, 2.25],
  h[{4.5 + #/2, 7.7} &,        1, Black, 2.25], h[{3 + #/6, 7 - 2 #/5} &,    8, Black, 1.25],
  h[{4.85, 0.5 + 2 #/25} &,    8, Black, 1.25],
 Graphics[{
   Text[Style["What's wrong with \n this challenge?",FontFamily->"Humor Sans", 14],{7,8.75}],
   Text[Style["This is a nice curve isn't it ?",     FontFamily->"Humor Sans", 14],{4,7   }],
   Text[Style["Peak",                                FontFamily->"Humor Sans", 14],{5.,0.1}],
   Arrow[{{1, 7},      {1, 9}}],         Arrow[{{7, 1},      {9, 1}}],
   Arrow[{{8.5, 0.1},  {9, 0.1}}],       Arrow[{{1.75, 0.1}, {1., 0.1}}],
   Arrow[{{4.5, 3.5},  {4.6, 3.2}}]}]},
 AspectRatio -> 2.5/3, PlotRange -> All]
```

to get this:

[image: xkcd-style plot with "Humor Sans" caption]

Then the sky is the limit ;-)

**EDIT**

The code of Mr.Wizard below is in fact more powerful.
As an Illustration,

```
  Show[{{AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[{-0.2, 0.2}, 1],
  Line[{{0, -1}, {1/2, -4}}],
  Line[{{1/2, -4}, {-1/2, -8}}],
  Line[{{1/2, -4}, {3/2, -8}}],
  Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -2}}],
  Line[{{1, -2}, {3, -2}}],
  Line[{{0, -1}, {3, -3/2}}],
  Line[{{0.2, 1.5}, {0.2, 3}}],
  Line[{{0.2, 5}, {0.2, 7}}],
  Text[Style["It's time to automate\n comic Strip production", 16], {-0.7, 8}],
  Text[Style["It's so easy\n to do in mathematica !", 16], {-0.7, 4}]} // Graphics,
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  PlotPoints -> 30, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black]
  } ]// xkcdify
```

produces this
[image: xkcd-style plot with "Humor Sans" caption]

**EDIT2**

Couldn't resist one of [my favorites](http://xkcd.com/54/) (using Simon Wood's solution this time):

```
  << BlackBodyRadiation`
  pl = BlackBodyProfile[4000 Kelvin, 5000 Kelvin, 6000 Kelvin, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2.0*10^-6}, {0, 1.1*10^14}}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
  Style["\nSCIENCE: \nit works bitches !", 64], {15 10^-7, 
   5 10^13}],Text[I[f] == (2*f^3*h)/(c^2*(-1 + E^((f*h)/(k*T)))), {15 10^-7, 
   0.8 10^14}]
  }] // xkcdConvert
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh ... don't delete it. Perhaps the code isn't elegant, but the result is quite good!

Comment: chris, I sense your first "Good Answer" badge coming. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it seems this community is fond of xkcd!

Comment: Now, if this gets accepted, you'll get the even rarer Guru badge, also. Note, the Good Answer badge is still rare: I have one, on the [entire network](http://stackexchange.com/users/67854/rcollyer)!

Comment: Oh This is beautiful Chris! @Mr. Wizard, belisarius and others, should I wait for a couple of days before accepting an answer so more people can attempt refinements or not since Chris has pretty much nailed the problem.

Comment: Before I start deconstructing that code: Do you add variations to both X and Y coordinates, or only Y (it looks to me so). The totally wicked solution would be to distort along the curves' normals.

Comment: @datenwolf both.

Comment: Before I forget: Instead of a normal random a better result may be obtained by using Perlin noise, which has been created for applications exactly like this.

Comment: @datenwolf well at least that way I have actually learnt something from this silly challenge!

Comment: And, then there was the [Great Answer badge](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/25/great-answer); the second one on this site in fact. They are very rare: on SO with 377k questions, there are only ~4.4k Great Answers.

Comment: @rcollyer - On EE.SE there's only 1 (125 upvotes). And don't forget OP's two gold badges: great question *and* famous question in a couple of hours! (40k views in 13 hours, on EE.SE it usually takes a couple of years to get 10k)

Comment: @Amatya - You can accept it if you're convinced this can't be outdone. But in my experience questions with an accepted answer get fewer new answers, so I would wait a couple of days. In any case, if you wish to accept now, you can always change your mind later.

Comment: @stevenvh well rm-rf has a way with getting [publicity](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist?userid=5). And, I wasn't forgetting about the other two golds (and [silver](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/52)) awarded.

Comment: Funny, it was just yesterday that you were asking me for a list of highly upvoted answers... now yours is at the very top! :)

Comment: This is crazy.  I see that my prophecy of "Good Answer" (made when there were only seven votes I think) was seriously underestimated.  Do you realize that many more people have voted for this answer than participated in the moderator election?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A huge majority of those votes are from random SE users who wouldn't have been able to vote anyway in the mod election. See the long string of "Supporter" badges awarded in the past 12 hrs or so. I shared it on reddit, causing the votes and views to explode... blame me :D

Comment: @datenwolf: alright, I did a version using Perlin noise...

Comment: I ummm.. well ... ummm .. _might_ have taken advantage of the account association bonus to up vote this answer and the question. It was that Lizard guy, Bill sharing a link on Twitter that made me do it. But in all fairness, when a single answer inspires me to try the same thing in not one but _two_ different languages, said answer and the question it answers are worthy of an up vote :)

Comment: @TimPost the more the merrier. I'm sure I don't have to explain the _rules_ here to you, but if you get out of line ... :)

Comment: @rm-rf yes though i) the other answers are atually better (less sweat) and ii) I have no idea why this topic gets so much hype.

Comment: 200 upvotes in 2 days, congrats!! (shouldn't we have a new badge for this, a platinum one?)

Comment: The circle for the head is too perfect - perhaps there needs to be an additional transformation rule?

Comment: @Verbeia sorted the circle (lack of) pb.

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: Signed in just to +1 this awesomeness

Comment: @mplungjan - welcome! please feel free to stick around and learn more Mathematica awesomeness :)

Answer (score 106):

Time to join in the fun.  **version 2**

## Result

[image: xkcd-style plot]

## Method

I produce the basic plot with ticks and labels:

```
Plot[{x/2, (x + Sin[x])/2.2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, Axes -> False, Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameTicks -> {{{0.2, "Start", 0.07}, {3, "lunch", 0.05}, {6, "Finish", 0.06}}, None},
 PlotLabel -> Style["the race", 20],
 Epilog -> {Text["Hare", {1.7, 2}], Text["Tortoise", {4, 0.6}]}
]
```

I add a couple of lines from the labels to the plot lines with the 2D Drawing Tools "Line segments" tool, then `xkcdify`:

[image: plot before xkcdify]

I make sure that vertical lines also receive a proper wiggle as shown here:

```
Plot[{3 Sin@x, Cos@x, Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
  Axes -> False, Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
  FrameTicks -> {
    {{1, "ThrEe", 0.07},
     {3.5, "LitTle", 0.04},
     {6, "Pigs", 0.06}}, None}
] // xkcdify
```

[image: xkcd-style trig plots]

## Code

```
(* Thanks to belisarius & J. M. for refactoring *)

split[{a_, b_}] :=
  If[a == b, {b}, With[{n = Ceiling[3 Norm[a - b]]}, Array[{n - #, #}/n &, n].{a, b}]]

partition[{x_, y__}] := Partition[{x, x, y}, 2, 1]

nudge[L : {a_, b_}, d_] := Mean@L + d Cross[a - b];

gap = {style__, x_BSplineCurve} :>
        {{White, AbsoluteThickness[10], x}, style, AbsoluteThickness[2], x};

wiggle[pts : {{_, _} ..}, d_: {-0.15, 0.15}] :=
  ## &[# ~nudge~ RandomReal@d, #[[2]]] & /@ partition[Join @@ split /@ partition@pts]

xkcdify[plot_Graphics] :=
  Show[FullGraphics@plot, TextStyle -> {17, FontFamily -> "Humor Sans"}] /.
    Line[pts_] :> {AbsoluteThickness[2], BSplineCurve@wiggle@pts} //
  MapAt[# /. gap &, #, {1, 1}] &
```

Comment: Now put all that in a palette and I'll upvote again

Comment: Mr: This should download a palettized version of your function. Tell me if it works `NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[Import@ "http://i.stack.imgur.com/tZigg.png","Byte"],"NB"]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, that simple sin bug is fixed now, thx. I see that function `xkcdify` suppose to take only `Graphics` objects, but not always, right? Like `BarChart[{1, 2, 3}]` and `ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, Mesh -> All]` will not work.

Comment: @Vitaliy this is still far from complete but I think it illustrates a usable framework.  I've spent about an hour and a half on this so far, believe it or not, and I'm not sure how much more I care to spend, but I may extend it a bit tonight.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hey, I did not mean that ;) What you did is awesome. You got my +1 from the start. I really like that one can apply `//xkcdify` directly to graphics outputs.

Comment: Nice, except for one little detail http://xkcd.com/833/ :)

Comment: It's not respecting `AspectRatio` in MMA9. See `Plot[Sinc[2 x], {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1] // xkcdify`

Comment: `FullGraphics` seems to be broken in current Mathematica (10), so your (very cool =) ) code doesn't work anymore. Perhaps any suggestion on how to replace it?

Comment: @Pietro It does seem broken. :-(  At the moment all I can think of is possibly exporting and importing the the graphic to some standard format, hopefully splitting it as FullGraphics did in the process.  I shall try that later if I remember.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I tried that, with `ExportString` and `ImportString` using PDF as format. I get `JoinedCurve` instead of `Line` in the Graphics, I tried some substitutions but I couldn't get `xkcdify` to work yet :/ My knowledge of Mathematica language is quite limited...

Answer (score 92):

I'm very late to the party, but here's a convenient xkcd guy generator:

[image: xkcd-guys]

This was generated as:

```
With[{
    h = xkcdGuy[-10, "hat", 0.2, {20, -90}, {-57, -10}, {-20, 0}, {20, 0}],
    n = xkcdGuy[0, "none", -0.2, {-10, 0}, {50, 10}, {-20, 0}, {20, 0}]},
    Graphics[{First@n, Rotate[Translate[First@h, {3.3, 0}], 10 Degree]}]
] // xkcdConvert
```

using Simon's `xkcdConvert`. The first three arguments to `xkcdGuy`, in order are head tilt, character, spine bend (0.1-0.2 is a good value). The last four arguments are the angles for each of the four limbs (see definition for order) and the first value controls the angle of the upper half of the limb about the clamping point (e.g. shoulder for the arms) and the second value controls the angle of the lower half of the limb relative to the upper half.

This generates plain xkcd guy and the hat guy. Beret guy can be easily extended from this. Now Megan...

The full definitions follow:

```
head[ang_:30, type_] := Module[{h},
    h = Switch[type,
        "hat",{{Thick, Line[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, Rectangle[{-1/Sqrt[2], 1}, {1/Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}]},
        "none",{}
    ];
    Graphics[Rotate[{Translate[{h}, {0, -0.25}], 
        {Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}}, ang Degree]
    ]
]

torso[x_] := Graphics[{Thick, BezierCurve[{{0, -1}, {x, -2},{0, -4}}]}] /; -1 <= x <= 1

arm[{ang1_, ang2_}, x_] := Module[{upper,lower,clamp = {x/2,-2}},
    upper = Line[RotationTransform[ang1 Degree, clamp]@{clamp, {0, -3}}];
    lower = Module[{o = upper[[1, 2]], e},
        e = AffineTransform[{IdentityMatrix@2, Normalize[o - clamp]}]@o; 
        Line[RotationTransform[ang2 Degree, o]@{o, e}]];    
    Graphics[{Thick, upper,lower}]
]

leg[{ang1_, ang2_}] := Module[{upper,lower,clamp = {0,-4}},
    upper = Line[RotationTransform[ang1 Degree, clamp]@{clamp, {0, -5.5}}];
    lower = Module[{o = upper[[1, 2]], e},
        e = AffineTransform[{IdentityMatrix@2, Normalize[o - clamp]}]@o; 
        Line[RotationTransform[ang2 Degree, o]@{o, e}]];        
    Graphics[{Thick, upper,lower}]
]

xkcdGuy[h_,type_,bend_,aR_,aL_, lR_,lL_] := Show[head[h,type], torso[bend], arm[#,bend]& /@ {aR, aL}, leg /@ {lR, lL}]
```

Comment: Maybe you can put default values for angles in arms and legs? So that `xkcdGuy[]` has a default status ;-)

Comment: Great. Now that we have xkcd graphs and xkcd guys, now all we need is an xkcd humour generator, and we can replicate the site in Mathematica.

Comment: @chris Yes, I had that in my test functions, but it slipped out in my final version. I'll edit it in later, but if you want a default, ±50 for the arms and ±30 for the legs looks good and 30 for the head if it's hat guy

Comment: @celtschk Yeah, I wonder if Randall actually likes this development here... :)

Comment: You could wrap that in a manipulate with locators ...

Comment: @belisarius locators would be cool: we could start making our own cartoon interactively. What a major waste of time though! :-)

Comment: @belisarius Yes, will do it, but will have to wait till a bit later

Comment: Brilliant! Randall's stick guys have their arms joined on at the top of the torso, directly under the head. Not sure if these are deliberately different?

Comment: @SimonWoods I agree, the neck is too long; will correct it in an update... with locators too :)

Answer (score 85):

To implement [datenwolf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2579)'s suggestion to perturb curves with Perlin noise to give that "hand-drawn" look and feel, here's one way to use one-dimensional Perlin noise for the perturbation:

```
fBm = With[{permutations = Apply[Join, ConstantArray[RandomSample[Range[0, 255]], 2]]},
   Compile[{{x, _Real}},
    Module[{xf = Floor[x], xi, xa, u, i, j},
       xi = Mod[xf, 16] + 1;
       xa = x - xf; u = xa*xa*xa*(10.0 + xa*(xa*6.0 - 15.0));
       i = permutations[[permutations[[xi]] + 1]]; 
       j = permutations[[permutations[[xi + 1]] + 1]];
       (2 Boole[OddQ[i]] - 1)*xa*(1.0 - u) + (2 Boole[OddQ[j]] - 1)*(xa - 1)*u],
     "CompilationTarget" -> "WVM", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];

handdrawn[fun_, fr_, divisor_, color_, at_] := 
 Graphics[{Directive[color, AbsoluteThickness[at]], 
   BSplineCurve[Table[fun@x + fBm[fr x]/(5 divisor), {x, 0.01, 10, .1}]]}]
```

I had previously used the one-dimensional Perlin noise routine in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4981).

In any event, here's a stripped-down version of chris's plot:

```
Show[
 handdrawn[{#, 1.5 + 10 (Sin[#]^2/Sqrt[#]) Exp[-(# - 5)^2/2]} &,
           30, 3, Darker[Cyan, 0.3], 3], 
 handdrawn[{#, 3 + 10 (Sin[#]^2/Sqrt[#]) Exp[-(# - 7)^2/2]} &, 30, 3, White, 8], 
 handdrawn[{#, 3 + 10 (Sin[#]^2/Sqrt[#]) Exp[-(# - 7)^2/2]} &, 30, 3, Darker[Red, 0.3], 3],
 handdrawn[{1, #} &, 30, 4, Black, 3], handdrawn[{#, 1} &, 30, 4, Black, 3],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: xkcd-style curves]

As a bonus, here's a "hand-drawn" arrow routine you can use:

```
hArrow[{p_, q_}, fr_, divisor_] := 
 Arrow[BSplineCurve[Table[p (1 - u) + q u + 
        RotationMatrix[Arg[#1 + I #2] & @@ (p - q)].{u, fBm[fr u]/(5 divisor)},
        {u, 0, 1, 1/50}]]]
```

Replicating the comic strip in the OP with these routines (along with using the "Humor Sans" font) is left as an exercise.

Comment: Now a nice palettized version for selecting a `Plot[]` and turn it `handdrawn` is a must ... +1

Comment: @J.M. this would be my vote!

Comment: @J.M. The ultimate solution would be `somegraphic//handraw[#,some parameter]&` wouldn't it?

Comment: @chris, that would take more thought and effort, of course.

Answer (score 46):

Another way to approach the xkcd-ification of plots is from an image processing perspective. The idea is to warp the space in which the image lies rather than to try and warp the lines themselves. When the image-space warps, the lines appear to vary in thickness.

First define the following function, which is *nearly* just a line with slope one. The important part is that it has small sinusoidal oscillations about this slope. A function that does this is

```
 f[x_, freq_, str_] := 0.99 x + Sin[(freq + 12 Sin[4 Pi x]) x]/str ;
```

which has two parameters: one controls the frequency of the oscillation and the other controls the strength/amount of the warping. To see how this function can be applied to the image space, start with a simple plot (from Mr. Wizard's "the race"). Since the lines are so thin, they need to be widened, which is done here using erosion. The function `f` is applied to both the x and y directions (the pure functions `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]`) using `ImageTransformation`

```
plot = Plot[{x/2, (x + Sin[x])/2.2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
       Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameTicks -> None]
ImageTransformation[Erosion[Image[plot], 1], 
       {f[#[[1]], 80, 500], f[#[[2]], 105, 500]} &]
```

[image]

If there are no thin lines, there is no need to do the erosion:

```
GraphicsRow[{piePlot = Image[PieChart[{9, 1}]], 
    ImageTransformation[piePlot, {f[#[[1]], 70, 180], f[#[[2]], 80, 180]} &]}, 
          ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Here's another example (taken from Mr. Wizard's answer) of this image transformation

```
GraphicsRow[{plot3 =Plot[{3 Sin@x, Cos@x, Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
   Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameTicks -> None, Axes -> False], 
ImageTransformation[ Erosion[Image[plot3], 1], 
   {f[#[[1]], 64, 300], f[#[[2]], 80, 400]} &]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Using a Manipulate, it is easy to explore a fairly wide variety of hand-drawn effects. Using the plot from above

```
Manipulate[
   ImageTransformation[ Erosion[Image[plot],1], 
     {f[#[[1]], freq, m], g[#[[2]], freq + 10, m]} &],
       {{freq, 40,"frequency"}, 0, 200}, {{m, 500, "strength"}, 100, 1000, 10}]
```

[image]

The same idea an also be applied to text

```
text = Style["Every font is comic sans", FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Geneva"]
ImageTransformation[Image[Rasterize[text]], 
      {f[#[[1]], 64, 200], f[#[[2]], 90, 200]} &]
```

[image]

which has the interesting property that different occurrence of a letter will not be the same (because they are warped differently by the underlying space). In this example, notice how the three s's, two n's and c's differ from each other.

And finally (I promise to stop adding new examples) it can be applied to any image. Here is a pattern that shows how the underlying space is warped by the function `f`:

```
 GraphicsRow[{img2 = ColorNegate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Plt.png"]],  
    ImageTransformation[img2,{f[#[[1]], 90, 100], f[#[[2]], 80, 50]} &]},
       ImageSize->500]
```

[image]

And here is a full StackExchange xkcdified plot using the above transformation. The bulk of the code handles the labels and coloring. The `Tooltip` allows a secret mouse-over message, in the best xkcd tradition.

```
f[x_, freq_, str_] := 0.99 x + Sin[(freq + 12 Sin[4 Pi x]) x]/str;
fTicks = {{{{0.2, "hmm"}, {0.8, "wow!"}}, {{0.2, "boring"}, {0.8, "very\nboring"}}}, {{{0.2, "not enough"}, {0.8, "too much"}}, None}};
fLabels = {{Style["Today's StackExchange\nquestions", FontSize -> 13, Darker[Red]],  Rotate[Style["Today's work", FontSize -> 13, Darker[Blue]], Pi]}, {Style["Time spent on Mathematica StackExchange", FontSize -> 13, Black], None}};
tip = Style["This seems to be a complex optimization problem.\nCan someone write the code for me?", FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS", FontSize -> 13];
fTickStyle = {{Darker[Red], Darker[Blue]}, {Black, None}}; 
plot1 = Plot[{x^2, Exp[- 2 x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> False];
plot2 = Plot[None, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, None}}, FrameTicks -> fTicks,  FrameTicksStyle -> fTickStyle, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"],  FrameLabel -> fLabels]; 
xkcdified = ImageTransformation[ Erosion[Image[plot1], 2], {f[#[[1]], 80, 500], f[#[[2]], 105, 500]} &];
Tooltip[ImageCompose[ImageResize[Image[plot2], 600], ImageResize[xkcdified, 350],{Center, 210}], tip]
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that you put this up here. +1, of course.

Answer (score -3):

This is nice, but outdated:

For Mathematica 12.0.0:

```
Show[Plot[{3 Sin@x, Cos@x, Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, Axes -> False], 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> None, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{1, "ThrEe", 0.07}, {3.5, "LitTle", 0.04}, {6, 
      "Pigs", 0.06}}, None}] // xkcdify
```

[image: xkcdified graphics]

Mind two changes were made:

- changed the font to `"Comic Sans MS",
- Graphics and text input for the labels match now.

Same for

```
Show[Plot[{x/2, (x + Sin[x])/2.2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, Axes -> False], 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameLabel -> None, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{0.2, "Start", 0.07}, {3, "lunch", 0.05}, {6, 
      "Finish", 0.06}}, None}, PlotLabel -> Style["the race", 20], 
  Epilog -> {Text["Hare", {1.7, 2}], 
    Text["Tortoise", {4, 0.6}]}] // xkcdify
```

[image: Graphics for the "race"]

```
Show[{{AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[{-0.2, 0.2}, 1], 
     Line[{{0, -1}, {1/2, -4}}], Line[{{1/2, -4}, {-1/2, -8}}], 
     Line[{{1/2, -4}, {3/2, -8}}], Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -2}}], 
     Line[{{1, -2}, {3, -2}}], Line[{{0, -1}, {3, -3/2}}], 
     Line[{{0.2, 1.5}, {0.2, 3}}], Line[{{0.2, 5}, {0.2, 7}}], 
     Text[Style["It's time to automate\n comic Strip production", 
       16], {-0.7, 8}], 
     Text[Style["It's so easy\n to do in mathematica !", 16], {-0.7, 
       4}]} // Graphics, 
   ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
    PlotPoints -> 30, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black]}] // xkcdify
```

[image: monolog]

And this works for me too:

```
f[x_, freq_, str_] := 0.99 x + Sin[(freq + 12 Sin[4 Pi x]) x]/str;
fTicks = {{{{0.2, "hmm"}, {0.8, "wow!"}}, {{0.2, "boring"}, {0.8, 
      "very\nboring"}}}, {{{0.2, "not enough"}, {0.8, "too much"}}, 
    None}};
fLabels = {{Style["Today's StackExchange\nquestions", FontSize -> 13, 
     Darker[Red]], 
    Rotate[Style["Today's work", FontSize -> 13, Darker[Blue]], 
     Pi]}, {Style["Time spent on Mathematica StackExchange", 
     FontSize -> 13, Black], None}};
tip = Style[
   "This seems to be a complex optimization problem.\nCan someone \
write the code for me?", FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS", 
   FontSize -> 13];
fTickStyle = {{Darker[Red], Darker[Blue]}, {Black, None}};
plot1 = Plot[{x^2, Exp[-2 x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> False];
plot2 = Plot[None, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, None}}, FrameTicks -> fTicks, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> fTickStyle, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"], 
   FrameLabel -> fLabels];
xkcdified = 
  ImageTransformation[
   Erosion[Image[plot1], 
    2], {f[#[[1]], 80, 500], f[#[[2]], 105, 500]} &];
Tooltip[ImageCompose[ImageResize[Image[plot2], 600], 
  ImageResize[xkcdified, 350]], tip]
```

[image: Time spend on Mathematica Stackexchange]

Comment: You're just showing more examples using Mr.Wizard's code for `xkcdify` and bill s's wiggly `f[]`?