# Download xkcd Click and Drag comic

Tags: image-processing, data-format, html, data-acquisition, internet

Inspired by the recent question about [xkcd styled plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11350/121) I started looking at xkcd again and I came across a comic titled [Click and Drag](http://xkcd.com/1110/).  And if you do that, you start exploring a larger drawing.  A *much* larger drawing.  How large?  I don't know, but I spent about half and hour exploring it before my arm wore out.

Now I want to see all the comic but I don't want to give myself [RSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) in the process.  That leads me, finally, to my questions:

- How can I use *Mathematica* to download the entire scrollable drawing?
- How can it be assembled and stored?  This will surely be a tremendously large image; what data formats does *Mathematica* support that can handle it?
- Is it possible to navigate the image from within *Mathematica*?

In fairness people may ask "what have you tried" and I must say: nothing.  Not long after posting I realized that the tiles are stored as PNG files with names that describe the location.  This was also mentioned in the comments.  This makes acquisition easier than I anticipated, and shifts the emphasis of this question to the second and third points.

Comment: While waiting for a solution, you can peek at the large drawing [here](http://xkcd-map.rent-a-geek.de/#10/1.0999/0.1998).

Comment: You've seen [the source](http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1110.js), I presume?

Comment: The images have the form `http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/NaMb.png` with M & N integers and a={N(orth), S(outh)}, b={E(ast),W(est)}

Comment: The full grayscale image is 1.3 terapixels large and about 12+GB in size...

Comment: @J.M. I hadn't before posting the question.  I assumed a different method that would be harder to map.

Comment: @belisarius So I discovered.  I'm working on a solution, but I'm afraid that trying it might constitute an abuse of the site, as I expect it to produce tens of thousands of 404 errors.

Comment: @rm I'm guessing you know this from external sources?  That's even crazier than I thought

Comment: @VLC Thanks.  I knew this must have been done b other people, but I'm still interested in the points in my question.

Comment: Yes, and I also think that Mathematica is probably the worst possible platform to do this in... I can't imagine the front-end not crashing 3 mins into the download process.

Comment: Each image is 2048 × 2048 pixels, for a total of 165888 × 79872. So it is 81 squares wide and 39 high.

Comment: @rm lol -- not much trust in the software? :o)

Comment: Only three 404 errors. One east, one north, one west

Comment: @belisarius I don't understand.

Comment: it's rectangle. you only need to find the limit in each direction

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You beat me to that question: a friend sent me a version of this 2 days ago ;-)

Comment: is it the same as http://xkcd-map.rent-a-geek.de/#10/1.0999/0.2005

Comment: @belisarius but many of the tile URLs you might try within that rectangle are not actually there.  If the search space VLC gave is correct it's not as bad as running to 99 in each direction however.

Comment: @chris beat me to it. Yes, that is the same thing.

Comment: @rm-rf - according to VLC's numbers only 13 gigapixel. Which is it now?

Comment: A link to a version of this map *in a different format* was posted in GIS chat a couple weeks ago. (Well, it's a different interface anyway; I did not check the actual data source.)  It's down right now (503 error), but for those who are curious, try http://research.geodan.nl/sites/xkcd/ a little later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Comment**

This was originally answered on Oct 2, 2012 using V8.  The performance can be dramatically improved using V9's `URLFetchAsynchronous`, as now shown below.

---

Fortunately, we needn't download all the tiles at once.  We can use `Dynamic` to set up a little pan-and-zoom explorer.  The first load takes a bit and zooming out takes a bit.  Panning and zooming into previously visited spots are pretty snappy since we cache the tile URLs.

```
xRad = 2; (* Number of tiles to add to the right and left of the center tile. *)
yRad = 1; (* Number of tiles to add above and below the center tile. *)
xPad = 0; (* Number of extra tiles to cache to the right and left for perfomance. *)
yPad = 0; (* Number of extra tiles to cache above and below for perfomance. *)

Clear[indices2xkcdTile, indices2xkcdTileRecord, center];

indices2xkcdTileURL[m_, n_, z_] := 
  "http://xkcd1.rent-a-geek.de/converted/" <> ToString[z] <> "-" <>
    ToString[n] <> "-" <> ToString[m] <> ".png";

redraw[m0_,n0_,z_] := Map[
  Function[mn,
    Module[{m,n},
      m=First[mn]; n=Last[mn];
      If[indices2xkcdTileRecord[m,n,z] =!="Done",
        indices2xkcdTileRecord[m,n,z]="Done";
        If[m<0 || m>2^z-1 || n<0 || n>2^z-1,
          indices2xkcdTile[m,n,z] = blue,
          URLFetchAsynchronous[indices2xkcdTileURL[m,n,z],
           If[#2 == "data", indices2xkcdTile[m,n,z] = 
              ImportString[FromCharacterCode[First[#3]]]]&]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  Table[{m,n},{m, m0-yRad-yPad, m0+yRad+yPad}, {n, n0-xRad-xPad, n0+xRad+xPad}],{2}];

blue = Image[Array[{0.2,0.2,1}&,{256,256}]];
waiting = Image[Array[0.8&,{256,256}]];
indices2xkcdTile[_,_,_] := waiting;
dynamicIndices2xkcdTile[m_,n_,z_] := Dynamic[Image[indices2xkcdTile[m, n, z],ImageSize->All]];

DynamicModule[{m0,n0,z},
 z = 10; m0 = 508; n0 = 512;
 center[10] = {m0,n0};
 redraw[m0,n0,z];
 redraw[Floor[m0/2],Floor[n0/2],9];
 Deploy[Panel[Column[{
     Dynamic[Grid[Table[dynamicIndices2xkcdTile[m,n,z], {m, m0-yRad, m0+yRad}, {n, n0-xRad, n0+xRad}],
       Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True]],
     Row[{"zoom: ",
       ButtonBar[{
         "+" :> If[z<10,
           center[z]=.;
           z = z + 1;
           {m0,n0} = center[z];
           redraw[m0,n0,z];
           If[z<9,
             redraw[center[z+1][[1]], center[z+1][[2]],z+1]]],
         "-" :> If[z>1,
           z = z - 1;
           m0 = Floor[m0/2];
           n0 = Floor[n0/2];
           center[z]={m0,n0};
           redraw[m0,n0,z];
           If[z>2,
             redraw[Floor[m0/2],Floor[n0/2],z-1]]]
         }],
       "                                 ",
       Grid[{
         {"", 
          Button["pan up", 
            m0 = m0-1;
            Do[
              center[zz] = {center[zz][[1]] - 2^(zz-z),center[zz][[2]]},
             {zz,z,10}
            ];
            redraw[m0,n0,z];
            If[z>2,
             redraw[Floor[m0/2],Floor[n0/2],z-1]];
            If[z<9,
             redraw[center[z+1][[1]], center[z+1][[2]],z+1]],
            ImageSize -> Automatic
          ], ""},
         {Button["pan left",
            n0=n0-1;
            Do[
              center[zz] = {center[zz][[1]],center[zz][[2]] - 2^(zz-z)},
             {zz,z,10}
            ];
            redraw[m0,n0,z];
            If[z>2,
             redraw[Floor[m0/2],Floor[n0/2],z-1]];
            If[z<9,
             redraw[center[z+1][[1]], center[z+1][[2]],z+1]],
            ImageSize -> Automatic], "",
          Button["pan right", 
            n0 = n0+1;
            Do[
              center[zz] = {center[zz][[1]],center[zz][[2]] + 2^(zz-z)},
             {zz,z,10}
            ];
            redraw[m0,n0,z];
            If[z>2,
             redraw[Floor[m0/2],Floor[n0/2],z-1]];
            If[z<9,
             redraw[center[z+1][[1]], center[z+1][[2]],z+1]],
            ImageSize -> Automatic]},
         {"", 
          Button["pan down", 
            m0 = m0+1;
            Do[
              center[zz] = {center[zz][[1]] + 2^(zz-z),center[zz][[2]]},
             {zz,z,10}
            ];
            redraw[m0,n0,z];
            If[z>2,
             redraw[Floor[m0/2],Floor[n0/2],z-1]];
            If[z<9,
             redraw[center[z+1][[1]], center[z+1][[2]],z+1]],
            ImageSize -> Automatic], ""}
         }]
       }]}, Alignment -> Center]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: More compactly: `indices2xkcdTile[m_, n_, z_] := 
indices2xkcdTile[m, n, z] = Import[ToString[StringForm["http://xkcd1.rent-a-geek.de/converted/\`3\`-\`2\`-\`1\`.png", m, n, z]]]`

Comment: @J.M. Theo Gray always likes to say that everything is a one-liner in Mathematica, for a sufficiently long line. Personally, I'm a big fan of the intermediate definition.

Comment: I suppose; I just thought it was profligate to have to call `ToString[]` thrice when you only need to do it once...

Comment: Very nice!  It would be even better with key events for arrow keys...

Answer (score 5):

You can download all the original tiles using the following functions. 404 and file not founds are handled gracefully. I'm avoiding displaying to the FE so as to lower the chances of crashing.

```
url[n1_Integer, d1_String, n2_Integer, d2_String] := 
    "http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/" <> ToString@n1 <> d1 <> ToString@n2 <> d2 <> ".png"

download[dir_String, url_String] := 
    With[{file = First@StringCases[url, Longest[___] ~~ "/" ~~ x__ :> x]},
        CheckAbort[
            Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, file}], 
                Quiet@Check[Import[url], Abort[], FetchURL::conopen]
            ], 
            ## &[]
        ]
    ]

download["/path/to/xkcd/dir", #] & /@ Flatten@Table[
    url[n1, d1, n2, d2], {n1, 99}, {d1, {"n", "s"}}, {n2, 99}, {d2, {"e", "w"}}]
```

The tiles are numbered neatly, so you can easily stitch them together to form the full-res image.

Comment: I'll update with a possible stitching routine when this darned thing finishes downloading. I gotta go now...

Comment: I came up with something very similar though I didn't try running the full thing.  One thing I realized in the exercise is that I don't know how to simply *download* a file without Importing and Exporting it.  I guess you don't know a way either?

Comment: No, I don't know of a way in mma, but I guess any download function must import the data to read it and only then write to disk (unless it is a specialized tool like `curl` or `wget`). By not displaying to the FE, you bypass all the formatting process which takes a long time and kills the FE.

Comment: Alternatively: `url[n1_Integer, d1_String, n2_Integer, d2_String] := ToString[StringForm["http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/\`1\`\`2\`\`3\`\`4\`.png", n1, d1, n2, d2]]`

Answer (score 5):

There's no easy way, it's a custom script that assembles the image out of individual slices, and it's written by someone who clearly didn't intend anyone to read it again (including himself).

1. **Reverse engineering.** The script responsible is http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1110.js, the image to be displayed is assembled in line 86 (`$image=...`). Scanning the line further reveals the image data to be `<img ... src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/'+name+'.png" .../>`; so what you're looking for is hidden in `http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/`, with some `name`.

   The `name` variable is defined in line 81, referring to `tile_name(...)`, which is a function of some position (current image centre, I suppose). It first does something with some size array (possibly a pixel-to-picture-count conversion), and then returns `return (y>=0?(y+1)+'s':-y+'n')+(x>=0?(x+1)+'e':-x+'w');`. Stripping away the logical operators, the first parenthesis results in `ys` or `yn` with `y` being a number, depending on whether the initial number is positive. The second parenthesis is the same, except with w/e. This sounds a lot like geographical directions to me, and since the result is some kind of location this makes sense. Completing this interpretation, we can assume that the `name` parameter is calculated to be something along the lines of `YnXe`.

   Let's take it to a test and call [`http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1n1e.png`](http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1n1e.png) - bingo, it's the center image with the guy hanging on the balloon.

   What's left is finding out how far the whole thing goes in each direction. One possible way would be loading all pictures from -1000 to +1000 by brute force, but there must be some other way, since the script stops you from dragging the picture when you've reached the (far left) end. (Guess how I found out). The script has a line `map_size=[(size[1]+size[3])*tilesize,(size[0]+size[2])*tilesize];`, which is a 2-dimensional array of what is hopefully the x/y extension of the whole picture. This suggests that 1/3 are the extensions in n/s (or e/w), and 0/2 is the other direction. Let's give it a shot and call a couple of the extremes. [1n48e](http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1n48e.png) [2n48e (404!)](http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/2n48e.png) [1n33w](http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1n33w.png) [1n34w (404!)](http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1n34w.png) - So it really extends 48 tiles east and 33 west, and not necessarily everything is filled up to the top/bottom.

   Taking everything together, we're looking to generate many filenames:

   ```
   t = Table[
         {x, y},
         {x, Union[Range[-33, 1], Range[1, 48]]},
         {y, Union[Range[1, 14], Range[-25, 1]]}
   ] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
   tupleToDir[{x_, y_}] := StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {Abs[x], If[x > 0, "e", "w"], Abs[y], If[y > 0, "n", "s"]}
   tupleToDir /@ t

   ==> {"33w25s", "33w24s", "33w23s", ... [3280 elements]}
   ```

   I may have the table order at some point, but some trial and error could fix that. Exercise to the reader etc.
2. **DDOS.** I don't want hundreds of people sending 3280 requests to XKCD, therefore I'll stop here. If you really want to download the whole thing on your own, you'll have to write the explicit code yourself. The solution is basically mapping a "download corresponding image" function over the array shown above, replacing 404s with black/white placeholders, and then assembling the whole thing to a large composite. Seeing how large the picture is, this will take a huge amount of memory. Good luck! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: More compactly: `t = Tuples[{Range[-33, 48], Range[-25, 14]}];` You seem to have swapped the places for north/south and east/west, tho.

Comment: You gotta be careful to exclude coordinates with zeros in the ranges though. (Also I hope nobody puts my code to use, so I hereby declare the coordinate disorder a feature.)

Comment: In that case, `Range[-33, 1]` *does* include $0$, though. Maybe you intended `Range[-33, -1]`?