# Scraping High-Res images from the MoMA and the Van Gogh Museum websites

Tags: image-processing, internet

Many art websites allow the user to zoom into an image to see it at high resolution by using image tiles. It is great on the website, but presents problems if one wishes to compile a complete high resolution picture from these tiles. I am currently using the following:

```
mOMA[name_, catalogueNumber_] := 
With[{src = 
Import[StringJoin["http://www.moma.org/collection/works/", 
  ToString[catalogueNumber], "?locale=en"], "Source"]}, 
With[{aa = 
 StringReplace[
  StringReplace[
   StringDrop[
    StringTake[src, 
     StringPosition[src, "allZoomBounds"][[1, 1]] - 11], 
    StringPosition[src, "allImageTiles"][[1, 2]] + 2], 
   "/media/" -> "http://www.moma.org/media/"], "]]" -> ","]}, 
With[{bb = StringDrop[aa, (Last@StringPosition[aa, "[["])[[2]]]}, 
With[{cc = {Length@StringPosition[bb, "["], Length@bb}}, 
 With[{dd = 
    StringReplace[StringReplace[bb, "[" -> ""], "]" -> ""]}, 
  With[{ee = StringPosition[dd, ","][[All, 1]]}, 
   With[{ccc = {Length@ee/(cc[[1]] + 1), (cc[[1]] + 1)}}, 
    With[{d1 = StringReplace[bb, "[" -> ""]}, 
     With[{d2 = Length@StringPosition[d1, "]"][[All, 1]] + 1}, 
      With[{cccc = {(Length@ee)/d2, d2}}, 
       With[{ff = 
          StringReplace[
             StringReplace[
              StringDrop[StringTake[dd, ee[[#]]], 
               If[# == 1, 0, ee[[# - 1]] + 1]], "\"" -> ""], 
             "," -> ""] & /@ Range@(Times @@ ccc)}, 
        With[{img = {ff, cccc}}, 
         With[{imgim = Import[#] & /@ img[[1]]}, 
          Rasterize[
           ImageAssemble[
            Table[imgim[[#]] & /@ (x + 
                img[[2, 1]] Range[0, img[[2, 2]] - 1]), {x, 1, 
              img[[2, 1]]}]], ImageResolution -> 100, 
           ImageSize -> 600]
          ]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

which works with something like `mOMA[Picasso_Minotauromachy _ 1935, 60110]`, but seems like an awful lot of fiddling to isolate & `ImageAssemble` relevant image tiles *(which on the MOMA site are sandwiched between `allImageTiles` and `allZoomBounds` in the source code)*. Is there a more straightforward way, eg with `Cases` and `"XMLObject"`, or similar?

## Update

In response to requested edits below, the following is the basis of the code:

```
With[{src = Import[StringJoin["http://www.moma.org/collection/works/", 
ToString[60110], "?locale=en"], "Source"]}, 
StringReplace[StringReplace[StringDrop[StringTake[src, StringPosition[src, 
"allZoomBounds"][[1, 1]] - 11], StringPosition[src, "allImageTiles"][[1, 2]] 
+ 2], "/media/" -> "http://www.moma.org/media/"], "]]" -> ","]]
```

with the rest of the code botched together to isolate each tile (each http string is a tile).

I agree that the code above, as presented is rather unreadable, with a load of nested `With` arguments that probably don't help. I will do my best to format appropriately, but am giving basic info in update for now, to hopefully clarify things a bit.

## Update 2

Using @belisarus' code, thithe following works for the specific image request from @bills in the comments

```
With[{aa = ToExpression@Most[StringDrop[#, 2] & /@StringCases[
Import["https://vangoghmuseum-assetserver.appspot.com/tiles?id=\
4820945634066432", "Text"], Shortest["url" ~~ a : __ ~~ "},"] -> a]]},
Rasterize[ImageAssemble[Table[Import@# &@aa[[x + 15*#]], {x, 1, 15}] & /@   
Range[0, 9]], ImageResolution -> 100, ImageSize -> 600]]
```

... still working on generalisation.

## Generalisation

```
doc = d0364V1968;
pollard = With[{num = StringReplace[StringReplace[StringReplace[StringCases[
Import[StringJoin["http://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/en/collection/", 
ToString[doc]], "Text"], Shortest["tiles?id=" ~~ a : __ ~~ "data"] -> a], 
"\"" -> ""], "\n" -> ""], " " -> ""][[1]]},
With[{aa = 
  Import[StringJoin[
    "https://vangoghmuseum-assetserver.appspot.com/tiles?id=", 
    num], "Text"]}, 
With[{x = 
   Max@ToExpression@
     StringReplace[
      StringDrop[#, 3] & /@ (StringTake[#, 5] & /@ 
         StringCases[aa, Shortest["x" ~~ a : __ ~~ "},"]]), 
      "," -> ""]},
With[{y = 
    Max@ToExpression@
      StringReplace[
       StringDrop[#, 3] & /@ (StringTake[#, 5] & /@ 
          StringCases[aa, Shortest["y" ~~ a : __ ~~ "},"]]), 
       "," -> ""]},
With[{bb = 
     ToExpression@
      Most[StringDrop[#, 2] & /@ 
        StringCases[aa, Shortest["url" ~~ a : __ ~~ "},"] -> a]]},
   Rasterize[ImageAssemble[
    Table[Import@# &@bb[[xx + (x + 1)*#]], {xx, 1, x + 1}] & /@ 
     Range[0, y - 1]], ImageResolution -> 100, ImageSize -> 600]
   ]]]]]
```

**Disclaimer**

*Please read the terms of use for images from each website before assembling large image sizes from tiles (hence the use of `Rasterize` and setting appropriate `ImageResolution`).*

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11369/7167) might be related.

Comment: Martin, do you think you could format the code in such a way that it is human-readable (i.e. add indents, new lines)? As it is now, I cannot even begin to make any sense of it.

Comment: Naming the variables "dd", "cccc", and so on is really not helping, either.

Comment: Not to be *that* guy, but is this content public domain?

Comment: @ScottSEA If the painting itself is old enough, then I believe this is fine in the USA: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54787/can-a-photo-of-a-book-page-be-copyrighted  But this legal stuff can be complicated, so just take my link as a starting point for research.  If a museum make a high quality digital reproduction of a painting, and the painting itself is public domain, then the reproduction cannot be copyrighted in the USA.  In other countries it may be different.

Comment: It looks like I'm late to the party, but I find it a shame, that you've deleted so much of your code from previous revisions. It added some specific examples to the problem, as well as a bit of context on where to look. A question in the state it is in now would almost certainly be closed as too-broad/unclear-what-youre-asking.

Comment: Please do not remove details from your question again. Without the context and code, it is useless to anyone else.

Comment: @TheToad I am concerned about legal implications. Please advise.

Comment: Right now the code is just words on a screen. It contains no images that are subject to copyright and the code, I presume, is your own work which is licensed CC by SA 3.0. Legal implications fall on the person executing the code, who would be the person doing the downloading of said images. Belisarius' answer also uses a value of 1 which is allowed, per my reading of the meta post that you asked and is now deleted. Most jurisdictions have exclusions for non-commercial, home use, fair use, etc. so don't think it'd be a problem. I'm not a lawyer, though.

Comment: @TheToad  I agree with you that it is just words on a page, but it is going against my wishes to keep the text as it currently stands. Could you please suggest a compromise?

Comment: @martin What sort of compromise would satisfy you? We try to discourage people asking detailed questions, getting others to spend time on it and answer it, only to then realize that they probably should not have posted it/their teacher might find out that they cheated/it was their company's proprietary data/the question was silly, etc. People have all sorts of reasons, but unless there is a demonstrable case of actual, explicit copyright infringement, we don't remove stuff. And I don't think your question comes even close to actual infringement (enables it, with the right parameters, perhaps).

Comment: @martin I suppose you could add something like that to work around it. I haven't read your code in detail and it's hard to follow because of the variable names and deep nesting, but now that you know the issue, the site's stance and what could be done (if it needs to be done), I trust you'll make the necessary (hopefully minor) modifications to the code, mostly for your own peace of mind :)

Comment: @TheToad many thanks for your advise on this. I have made the necessary minor adjustments. Please let me know if suitable or not.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your patience and for making these edits :)

Comment: @TheToad no problem - glad we could work together to get a satisfying solution for both parties :)

Comment: @R.M. Could you tell please where did you find that only *value of scale 1 is allowed* for downloading? 
Seems like they allow to download any image data from their website for non-commercial educational usage. https://www.moma.org/about/about_site/index

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## MoMA

`res`= {1,2,3..} is the resolution.Use `res = -1` for the max available resolution, but beware of [a shipload of lawyers, middle managers, telephone sanitisers and hairdressers](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/hitchhikers/guide/golgafrincham.shtml) that may try to prosecute you if you use a value greater than `1`,

```
moma[catalogueNumber_, res_] := 
  Module[{m = "http://www.moma.org", src, sj, rep, exp, a},
  rep = {"]" -> "}", "[" -> "{"};
  exp = Shortest["allImageTiles =" ~~ a : __ ~~ ";"] -> a;
  src = Import[StringJoin[m, "/collection/works/", ToString@catalogueNumber], "Source"];
  sj = Map[Import[m <> #] &, (ToExpression@
                         StringReplace[StringCases[src, exp], rep])[[1,1,res]], {2}];
  ImageAssemble@Transpose@sj]

moma[60110, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you - much clearer! & well done for deciphering my awful  unreadable code!! :)

Comment: @martin I didn't :) I just took a look at the input and output ;D

Comment: *much* more sensible! ;)

Comment: The `name` variable isn't used. So for example, you can get a Van Gogh using just the item number: `moma[xxx, 79802, 1]`

Comment: @belisarius -- This is an amazing piece of detective work! Can you see how to modify the calls to import the highest resolution images from the Van Gogh museum... for instance, from here: http://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/en/collection/d0364V1968

Comment: @bills I'm all ears :)

Comment: @bills tiles for that one can be found here `Most[StringDrop[#, 2] & /@ 
  StringCases[
   Import["https://vangoghmuseum-assetserver.appspot.com/tiles?id=\
4820945634066432"], Shortest["url" ~~ a : __ ~~ "},"] -> a]]`

Comment: @belisarius re bill s' request, tiles can be found here @bills tiles for that one can be found here `Most[StringDrop[#, 2] & /@ 
  StringCases[
   Import["https://vangoghmuseum-assetserver.appspot.com/tiles?id=\
4820945634066432"], Shortest["url" ~~ a : __ ~~ "},"] -> a]]` - still working on putting htem together!

Comment: @martin Working on it. It can be done in a cleaner way

Comment: @belisarius at one point, I managed to find the full resolution image somewhere, but like George's Marvellous Medicine, I have no idea how I did it! - Can't seem to get it back, but it is hiding there somewhere!

Comment: @bills See the other answer

Comment: @belisarius snap! (almost!!) ;)

Comment: @bills See update to OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27248/discussion-between-martin-and-belisarius).

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I would appreciate greatly if you could write the same snippet in python:) Or if it is possible, explain please how it works. I don't know Mathematica very well, but I need to scrap a couple of thousands of images from MoMA:)

Comment: @Temak That is off topic here.I suggest you as for it on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 13):

## Van Gogh Museum

Here is the same for the tiles structure of the Van Gogh Museum at @bills' request. Note that the structure is completely different. I preserved the same resolution convention:

```
vanInTheSkyWithLucy[catalog_, res_] := 
 Module[{i, df, zooms, c, maxXY, t}, 
  i = Import["http://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/en/collection/" <> catalog, "XMLObject"];
  df = First@  Cases[i, XMLElement[__, {___, "data-url" -> a__, ___}, ___] -> a, ∞];
  zooms = Reverse["levels" /. Import[df, "JSON"]];
  If [$VersionNumber >= 10,
     c = Cases[#, {"x" -> x_, "y" -> y_, "url" -> u_} :>{x, y,  u},∞],
     c = Cases[#, {"url" -> u_, "x" -> x_, "y" -> y_} :>{x, y,  u},∞]] &@zooms[[res]];
  maxXY = Max /@ (Transpose[c][[;; 2]]) + 1;
  t = ConstantArray[1, Reverse@maxXY];
  (t[[#[[2]] + 1, #[[1]] + 1]] = #[[3]]) & /@ c;
  ImageAssemble@Map[Import, t, {2}]]

vanInTheSkyWithLucy["d0364V1968", 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Warning** The code works differently on V9 and V10, so I added a version check.Thanks  lot to @bills for the debugging! Apparently the JSON import works differently.

Comment: I encounter a problem in running your code above, `c` is an empty set, and so the `Transpose` in `maxXY ` gives an error. That is the right picture though, so it is very close!

Comment: @belisarius I get an error on this one too ...

Comment: @belisarius quit kernel & am getting `ImageAssemble[ConstantArray[1, 2 $Failed]]`

Comment: @bills I can't repro the problem here. Care to help me to debug it?

Comment: @martin What resolution are you using?

Comment: @belisarius have tried from `-1` to `2`

Comment: @bills after discussion in chat with belisarius, worked out must be prob with cases & JSON in v10. Should work fine in v9 apparently.

Comment: @belisarius scraping the barrel here, but [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91917/strange-behavior-with-cases-and-position-with-setdelayed)?

Comment: I've edited the Cases command and it works now. I changed it to: `{"x" -> x_, "y" -> y_, "url" -> u_}` whereas it had been `{"url" -> u_, "x" -> x_, "y" -> y_}`. Somhow in v. 10 the order of the arguments is crucial whereas it appears not to be crucial in v. 9. (Unless, of course, I've accidently broken in in v. 9)

Comment: @belisarius have asked [this meta question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/possible-legal-issues-with-question). What are your thoughts?

Comment: @martin The "difficult" thing is doing it in mathematica. Any good web crawler will do it for you almost automatically. I would just add a disclaimer. The rest is scientific curiosity

Comment: @martin By monitoring the communication channel I found that they load things like [**this**](https://lh6.ggpht.com/MKQUZEFGlpHwPjl7ZR9Qn1fN3deKDIXQGlqXFWKpc50t0dU3CNggPQbn_ns=x6-y3-z5-tvA_9Vqsh5QWwYMzkzSpFURH_39k) which fail to load as images, so I suspect they transform the image after reception (encryption?). I don't believe that kind of scheme is funny to intercept, sorry.

Comment: @belisarius agreed :)