# How can I prevent graphics scaling with CDF notebook size?

Tags: plotting, cdf-format

Recently we saw how to produce [xkcd-style graphs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs). I evaluated the same code and deployed the result to CDF. Everything is working fine except that, in the CDF notebook, the graph is scaled according to the size of the window.

To start with, we have:

[image: Original size]

But, on resizing the window, the graphic also gets smaller:

[image: Resized window]

I don't want the graph to be scaled with the window. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @subbu when your question is so badly spelled, formatted, and tagged that people cannot even tell what you are asking, then we have a problem. On this occasion I have cleaned it up, but would ask you to try harder in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give explicit `ImageSize` option to the final Graphics function that makes your graph. Examples:

- `ImageSize -> Medium`
- `ImageSize -> {550, 300}`

For the excepted xkcd answer this would be here:

```
xkcdDistort[p_] := Module[{r, ix, iy}, r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 10, Padding -> White];
{ix, iy}=Table[RandomImage[{-1, 1},ImageDimensions@r]~ImageConvolve~GaussianMatrix[10],{2}];
Show[ImagePad[ImageTransformation[r, # + 15 {ImageValue[ix, #], ImageValue[iy, #]} &, 
      DataRange -> Full], -5], ImageSize -> Medium]];
```

Notice new `Show[... , ImageSize -> Medium]`

Comment: what is the final Graphics function name?

Comment: @subbu see updated answer

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov >.< thanks! :D (removed stupid comment of mine)