# xkcdConvert routines perform slower in Mathematica 9

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, image-processing

I am experiencing some rather large performance decreases in *Mathematica* version 9.0 using the *xkcd-styled* plotting routines.

I had used the `xkcdConvert` code from Simon Woods [as seen here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs) (also described/annotated by Vitaliy Kaurov, [as seen here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/)) a few months back under version 8.0.4.  This code worked great under version 8.0.4 and ran the following sample code in about **1.68 seconds**:

```
f1[x_] := 5 + 50 (1 + Erf[x - 5]);
f2[x_] := 20 + 30 (1 - Erf[x - 5]);
xkcdConvert[
  Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
   Epilog -> 
    xkcdLabel /@ {{"Label 1", {1, f1[1]}, {1, 30}}, {"Label 2", {8, 
        f2[8]}, {0, 30}}}, 
   Ticks -> {{{3.5, "1st Event"}, {7, "2nd Event"}}, 
     Automatic}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This code will produce a simple xkcd-styled plot as given by Simon Woods example.

When I run the same code under version 9.0, the output takes **~17.0 seconds** to produce!?  I'm not sure why the performance degradation is happening in version 9.0.

I was hoping to produce a number of comic styled plots for a meeting.  I have produced the desired plots, but all the plot-rendering took a really long time (one plot took ~8 minutes to render).

I welcome insight on how to improve the rendering performance under version 9.0 for future rendering efforts!

Comment: whaow... xkcd has become a fully supported functionality of  mathematica ;-)

Comment: Sadly, I have also noticed a speed decrease in much of my own code in Mathematica 9 vs Mathematica 8.  Can't say I can really track it to anything specific ....

Comment: It would be a good idea to go through the various steps one by one to see which specific function is causing the slowdown. Also check if the image size produced by `Rasterize` is the same in v8 and v9.

Comment: I have been working on that process. Once I am finished I will report back.  Thank you!

Comment: For anybody who is keeping score, my benchmarks shows that Date and Time functions slowed down by about 10% between 8.04 and 9.

Comment: 17 seconds really isn't that slow...it took me that long to type this comment... :-)

Comment: @MichaelStern, do you have any concrete examples of date/time slowdowns?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, meaning do you want quantitative examples (code + results on a v8 system VS. code + results on a v9 system)?

Comment: @Joel Klein: I put together an extensive Date/Time benchmark in December, comparing Mathematica 8 to Mathematica 9 to VBA and Objective C. One of the date routines that slowed between Mathematica 8 and Mathematica 9 was Timing[
 Do[DateDifference["11/15/1997", "12/1/1998", "Day"], {100000}];
 ]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By the power of CUDALink and a CUDA-enabled GPU, this code drastically increases the speed of `xkcdDistort` by almost 120x. It takes circa 60s to transform a 400 × 400 image using `xkcdDistort` on my laptop (i5-2410M + NVIDIA GT540M + 4GB memory), and `CUDAxkcdDistort` can do the same in just 0.5s. Distortion of a 1000 × 1000 image takes just 2.5s.

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]

CUDAxkcdDistort[p_, s_List, blockDim_Integer] :=
  Module[{
    code =
     "#include<math.h>
     __global__ void CUDATransform( float * in, float * out , float * \
aux , int width, int height, int channels, int distort ) 
     {
        int Index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x ;
         int xIndex = Index % width ; 
        int yIndex = Index / width ;
         if ( xIndex >= width || yIndex >= height )
                return ;

         int xfrom , yfrom ;
         int xfetch , yfetch ;
         int from , to , ii;

        xfrom =  xIndex + yIndex * width ; 
         yfrom = ( width - 1 - xIndex ) + ( height - 1 - yIndex ) * width ;
         xfetch =  (int) ceil( xIndex + aux[xfrom] * distort ) ; 
         yfetch =  (int) ceil( yIndex + aux[yfrom] * distort ) ; 
         if ( xfetch > 0 && xfetch < width && yfetch > 0 && yfetch < height )
           {
             from = xfrom * channels;
             to = ( xfetch + yfetch * width ) * channels;
             for ( ii = 0 ; ii < channels ; ii++)
                out[ from + ii ] = in [ to + ii ];
           } 

     }", func, InMem, OutMem, AuxMem, width, height, pad = 15, 
    channels, distort = 20, result}, 
    func = CUDAFunctionLoad[code, "CUDATransform", {
       {"Float"},
      {"Float"},
      {"Float"},
      "Integer32",
      "Integer32",
      "Integer32",
      "Integer32"
      }, {blockDim, 1, 1}, TargetPrecision -> "Single"]; 
     If[ImageQ[p], InMem = ImagePad[p, pad, Padding -> White],
     InMem = ImagePad[Rasterize[p, ImageSize -> s], pad, Padding -> White]];
      {width, height} = ImageDimensions[InMem];
      channels = ImageChannels[InMem]; 
      InMem = CUDAMemoryLoad[Flatten[ImageData[InMem]], "Float"];
      OutMem = CUDAMemoryLoad[Flatten[ParallelTable[1, {i, height}, {j, width},{k,channels}]], "Float"];
      AuxMem = CUDAMemoryLoad[Flatten[ImageData[CUDAImageConvolve[RandomImage[{-1, 1},{width, height}], GaussianMatrix[10]]]], "Float"];
      CUDAMemoryCopyToDevice[InMem];
      CUDAMemoryCopyToDevice[OutMem];
      CUDAMemoryCopyToDevice[AuxMem];
      func[InMem, OutMem, AuxMem, width, height, channels, distort];result = ImagePad[Image[Partition[Partition[CUDAMemoryGet[OutMem], channels], width]], -3];
       CUDAMemoryUnload[InMem];
       CUDAMemoryUnload[OutMem];
       CUDAMemoryUnload[AuxMem];
       Return[ImageAdjust@GaussianFilter[result, 1]];];
       CUDAxkcdConvert[x_, s_List, blockDim_Integer] :=CUDAxkcdDistort[xkcdShow[x], s, blockDim];
```

Comment: Very nice timing on two counts!  Just got a new laptop with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M graphics processor.  Thank you!!

Comment: I take it that the s parameter contains the image dimensions. What about blockDim?

Answer (score 26):

After some sleuthing through the `xkcdConvert` code I found the routine that is causing the execution slow down.  The function containing the problem is the `xkcdDistort` function.  See the following code:

```
 xkcdDistort[p_] := Module[{r, t, ix, iy},
   r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 10, Padding -> White];
   {ix, iy} = Table[RandomImage[{-1, 1},
                    ImageDimensions@r]~ImageConvolve~GaussianMatrix[10],{2}];
   ImagePad[ImageTransformation[r, # + 15 {ImageValue[ix, #], ImageValue[iy, #]}&,
   DataRange -> Full], -5]
 ];
```

Isolating the problem further, the real slow down is caused by the `ImageValue` function.  The `ImageValue` function is used to generate distortion values on the raster image 'r' pixels, which are used within the `ImageTransformation` function.  For some reason the `ImageValue` function has become very slow.

To support the statement about the `ImageValue` function's slow performance, I created a new `xkcdDistort` function, see following code:

```
xkcdDistort2[p_] := Module[{r, ix, iy, f},
   r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 5, Padding -> White];
   f[x_, y_] := {x + 2.1*Sin[0.18* x], y + 2.1*Sin[0.18 *y]};
   ImagePad[ImageTransformation[r, f @@ # &, DataRange -> Full], -2] 
  ];
```

This function is not as good at providing a cartoon like appearance, but it demonstrates that the `ImageValue` function is most likely causing the performance problem.  Here is an example, which shows the performance differences on a Mac OSX computer running Mathematica 9.

```
 f1[x_] := 5 + 50 (1 + Erf[x - 5]);
 f2[x_] := 20 + 30 (1 - Erf[x - 5]);
 test1a = xkcdConvert[
          Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
              Epilog->xkcdLabel /@ {{"Label 1", {1, f1[1]}, {1, 30}}, 
                                    {"Label 2", {8, f2[8]}, {0, 30}}}, 
              Ticks -> {{{3.5, "1st Event"}, {7, "2nd Event"}}, Automatic}]
          ]//AbsoluteTiming

 test1b = xkcdConvert2[
          Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
              Epilog->xkcdLabel /@ {{"Label 1", {1, f1[1]}, {1, 30}}, 
                                    {"Label 2", {8, f2[8]}, {0, 30}}}, 
              Ticks -> {{{3.5, "1st Event"}, {7, "2nd Event"}}, Automatic}]
          ]//AbsoluteTiming

 GraphicsRow[{test1a[[2]], test1b[[2]]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

This code will produce output with timing results. The original `xkcdConvert` function creates an image in **21.113965 seconds**, while the new `xkcdConvert2` function creates an image in **0.974976 seconds**.
[image: image comparion]

Comment: +1 for the analysis - even though I still prefer making ugly plots by hand.

Comment: It's a shame that `ImageValue` is so much slower in v9. You might want to look at the code in Vitaliy's blog post, using `BSplineFunction` for the distortion. That will avoid the problem with `ImageValue` but keep the randomness of the distortion.

Comment: I took your suggestion on using Vitaliy's example and created a function using the BSplineFunction, but it seems to produce a blank image!?  Not sure where I am going wrong... Any hints on using the BSPlineFunction is welcome!

Comment: `ImageValue` is actually pretty fast in v9, as one can see by querying for a million coordinate pairs at one go.  What you have discovered is that it is not a recommended programming practice (when speed is a concern) to call a million times `ImageValue` with a single coordinate pair.

Answer (score 16):

I had a look at an evaluation copy of v9 today, and did some digging around in `ImageValue`. It looks like the main cause of the slowdown is the handling of `Span` notation in the position specification. `ImageValue` calls `` Image`ImageDump`extractCoordinates `` with the requested position and the image dimensions as arguments. This function then does various checks and ultimately, for a numerical position argument, returns the position unchanged. So a somewhat clunky workaround is to temporarily redefine `` Image`ImageDump`extractCoordinates `` to simply return its first argument:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Image`ImageDump`extractCoordinates},
 Unprotect[Image`ImageDump`extractCoordinates];
 Image`ImageDump`extractCoordinates = #1 &;
 xkcdConvert[plot]]
```

This is much faster, though still not as fast as v8.

Probably the best solution is to use the idea from [Vitaliy's blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/), using a `BSplineFunction` to define the distortion. This is way faster than my code. A drop-in replacement for `xkcdDistort` and `xkcdConvert` with optional amplitude and frequency arguments is:

```
xkcdDistort[p_, am_, fr_] := Module[{r, f},
   r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 10, Padding -> "Fixed"];
   f = BSplineFunction[Table[
      {x + (am/fr)*RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
       y + (am/fr)*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]},
      {x, 0, 1, 1./fr}, {y, 0, 1, 1./fr}], 2, 
     Method -> {"Extrapolation" -> "Repeat"}];
   ImageTransformation[r, f @@ # &, ImageDimensions[r],
    DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Padding -> "Fixed"]];

xkcdConvert[x_, am_: 0.3, fr_: 50] := xkcdDistort[xkcdShow[x], am, fr];
```

Comment: This is perfect! Just what I was looking for...  On my v9 system your new solution is ~3.6 times faster than the original xkcdConvert on a v8 system (comparison done on nearly the same hardware, just different Mathematica versions)