# Using ImageTransformation[] with a lookup table

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, geometric-transform

I need to transform images by `ImageTransformation` in a time critical application. Therefore I precalculate a lookup table `lut` of the transformation function for the true pixel range `{{0,width},{0,height}}`. However, when I use

```
ImageTransformation[img, lut[[#[[1]],#[[2]]]]&, DataRange->Full]
```

I get the error message

> ImageTransformation::imgtrnsfun: The function lu should map a pixel position of form {x, y} to {x', y'}. >>

Is it possible to provide a lookup table to `ImageTransformation`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the problem is that the transformation function is slow to compute, a simple way to create and use a look-up table is to memoize the function:

```
(* create an example image *)
image = RandomImage[1, {30, 20}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] ~ ImageResize ~ Scaled[10]

(* define the transformation function with memoization *)
mem : func[{x_, y_}] := mem = {x + 0.01 Abs@BesselJ[1, 10 x], y^2}
```

The first time you use the transformation, it will be slow:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ImageTransformation[image, func]]
```

[image]

But next time you use it, it will be much faster, as the values have been remembered (you could say your look-up table is stored in the `DownValues` of `func`)

```
AbsoluteTiming[ImageTransformation[image, func]]
```

[image]

**More speed**

The nice thing about `ImageTransformation` is that it will interpolate between pixels so that you can sample the image at non-integer pixel positions. If you can tolerate losing the interpolation feature (i.e. so that each pixel in the output image is a direct copy of a pixel from the input image), you can get some more speed by manipulating the image data directly.

*(Updated with faster code)*

The code below creates a fast image transformation function for a specific size of image. Briefly, the procedure is:

1. Create an `Image` expression in which the pixel values are just the integers from 1 to n (effectively labelling each pixel position with a unique identifier)
2. Run the standard `ImageTranformation` on that image. The option `Padding -> "Reflected"` is used to ensure that the resulting image consists only of pixels in the input image. `"Periodic"` would also work.
3. The result of the image transformation is flattened and rounded - this is the look-up table.
4. Create a compiled function to flatten the input image data, apply the look-up table using `Part`, and partition the result.
5. Sandwich the compiled function between `Image` and `ImageData`

The output is a function which can be applied directly to an image.

```
makeFastTransformation[func_, {cols_, rows_}] := Module[{lut, cfunc},
  lut = ImageData @ ImageTransformation[Image @ Partition[Range[rows*cols], cols], 
     func, Resampling -> "Nearest", Padding -> "Reflected"];
  cfunc = With[{lut = Round @ Flatten @ lut}, Compile[{{data, _Real, 3}}, 
     Partition[Flatten[data, 1][[lut]], cols]]];
  Composition[Image, cfunc, ImageData]]
```

The resulting function is very fast

```
trans = makeFastTransformation[func, ImageDimensions[image]];

AbsoluteTiming[trans @ image]
```

[image]

To measure the time properly we need to do the transformation several times. It came out at about about 1.4 ms on my PC, about 80 times faster than `ImageTransformation` with the memoized function.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[trans @ image, {1000}]]
(* {1.3593228, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

`ImageTransformation` works with functions, not tables. It should be straightforward to define a function that carries out the same transformation as the table, but you will need to be aware that the `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]` arguments go from 0 to 1 (across the image) so you will need to design the function to handle this input range. For example, you might want a 256x256 element table. Then you would take the `#[[1]]` as input to the function, multiply by 255, Round to the nearest integer, and add 1 (i.e., `Round[255 #[[1]]+1]`) and the same for the second parameter. Then use these to index into your table. Your function/table will need to have appropriate outputs, that is, each element of the table will need to be a pair of numbers in the range (0,1).

For example, in an answer to this [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs/24974#24974) question, I created a function using the `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]` arguments, to that may help as you are designing your function to imitate the action of a table.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to make sure that your transformation function always handles input cleanly. Here's a test you can do to see what goes into your function. (And I think you *can* use real coordinates if you use the `DataRange` option.)

```
i = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], {20, 20}];
```

The function:

```
f[pt_] := (Print[pt]; {pt[[1]], pt[[2]]});
```

Call it:

```
ImageTransformation[i, f, DataRange -> Full]
```

The output:

```
{1034.,17475.}
{0.5,19.5}
{1.5,19.5}
{2.5,19.5}
{3.5,19.5}
{4.5,19.5}
{5.5,19.5}
{6.5,19.5}
{7.5,19.5}
{8.5,19.5}
...
```

Apart from the hard-to-explain first line (‽), you can see that none of these coordinate pairs are going to be very useful as look-up table pointers. So, as [bill's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25259/61) points out, make sure your function handles inputs cleanly.