# Enlarge the axes text

Tags: graphics, formatting

```
Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x value", Sin[x^2]}]
```

In the above code give a graph. In the graph the axes fonts are too small. My problem is that, how can I enlarge the axes text `x` and `x^2` without changing the basic.

Comment: Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x value", "Sin(x^2)"}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}], will enlarge the axes labels.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works:

```
Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {
    Style["x value", Purple, FontFamily -> "Zapfino", FontSize -> 24], 
    Style[x^2, Orange, FontFamily -> "Zapfino", FontSize -> 24]
    }]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Aaargh, my eyes...

Comment: @SimonWoods Sorry, I forgot [you're a font purist](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/61) :)