# Reproducing the xkcd "Self-Description" comic

Tags: image-processing, generative-art, charts

Trying to brush up on my programming, I wanted to see if I can reproduce at least the first two panels of [the following comic](http://www.xkcd.com/688/) in *Mathematica*:

[image]

I have some code for trying to reproduce the first panel, but I think it could be improved a lot:

```
pie[bw_] :=
PieChart[bw, BaseStyle -> GrayLevel[0, 1], 
             ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, GrayLevel[0, 1]]], 
             ChartLabels -> Placed[{"fraction of\nblack", "fraction of\nwhite"}, 
             "RadialCallout"], ChartStyle -> {Black, White}, SectorOrigin -> -5 Pi/6]

FixedPoint[N[Normalize[ImageLevels[Binarize[Rasterize[pie[#], "Image",
                       ImageSize -> Large]]][[All, 2]], Total]] &, {0.1, 1}] // pie
```

[image]

My problem has been in trying to add the second panel, and making sure the `FixedPoint` accounts for the amount of black and white in both panels. I tried using `Row` and `Framed` with `Histogram`, but I could not make it look decent. Can you all help me remake this comic?

I will be happy with just the first two panels, but I will of course be very impressed if you can somehow manage the third!

Comment: Hihi, I have seen it, but I am more interested in the self-referential nature on the image, so I used FixedPoint. I guess that is for postprocessing however.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to "but I think it could be improved a lot:", which I got wrong ;)

Comment: There is an excellent article on this very question on the Wolfram Blog. Follow [this link](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/09/07/self-description/)

Comment: @shrx. my comment will take the OP to a page were he/she will find an answer, but it is not an answer in itself. Link only answers are not the kind of answers we want on this site.

Comment: http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/09/07/self-description/

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs)?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a slightly improved/updated version of the solution developed by [Peter Frentrup](http://forums.xkcd.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=68230&sid=7811d55ae38f78cbc98c8faa874afbce) and [published at Jan 15, 2010](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=55212&hilit=688&sid=0c05fa6227bedd71970247ca09b26d9e&start=120#p1968190) on the [xkcd forum](http://forums.xkcd.com/). The changes I have made are to [put `"Image"` as the second argument for `Rasterize`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94535/280), explicitly convert the result to grayscale and use `ImageData` for extracting channel values (all these features were not present in *Mathematica* 6 with which the original code was developed).

The implementation:

```
d = 0.1;
pw = GoldenRatio - d/2;
font = "Comic Sans MS";

b2g[g_, b1_, b2_, b3_] := Graphics[{Thick,
   (* panel frames *)
   Table[With[{x = i*(pw + d)}, 
     Line[{{x, 0}, {x + pw, 0}, {x + pw, 1}, {x, 1}, {x, 0}}]], {i, 0, 2}],
   {(* left panel *)
    With[{cx = pw - 0.5, cy = 0.5},
     {Circle[{cx, cy}, 0.4],
      Disk[{cx, cy}, 0.4, 7/6 \[Pi] + {-\[Pi], \[Pi]} ((b1 + b2 + b3)/3)],
      With[{c = Cos[7/6 \[Pi]], s = Sin[7/6 \[Pi]]},
       {Line[{{cx, cy}, {cx + 0.55 c, cy + 0.55 s}, {d, cy + 0.55 s}}],
        White,
        Line[{{cx + 0.4 c, cy + 0.4 s}, {cx + 0.3 c, cy + 0.3 s}}]}],
      With[{c = Cos[3/4 \[Pi]], s = Sin[3/4 \[Pi]]},
       Line[{{cx + 0.3 c, cy + 0.3 s}, {cx + 0.5 c, cy + 0.5 s}, {d, 
          cy + 0.5 s}}]],
      Text[Style["FRACTION OF\nTHIS IMAGE  \nWHICH IS BLACK",
        Background -> White,
        FontWeight -> Bold,
        FontFamily -> font,
        TextAlignment -> Left,
        FontSize -> Scaled[0.05/(3*pw + 2*d)]], {d/2, d/2}, {-1, -1}],
      Text[Style["FRACTION OF\nTHIS IMAGE  \nWHICH IS WHITE",
        Background -> White,
        FontWeight -> Bold,
        FontFamily -> font,
        TextAlignment -> Left,
        FontSize -> Scaled[0.05/(3*pw + 2*d)]],
       {d/2, 1 - d/2}, {-1, 1}]}]
    },
   {(* middle panel*)
    With[{lef = pw + 3 d, rig = 2 pw, bot = 1.5 d, top = 1 - 3 d},
     {Line[{{lef, top}, {lef, bot}, {rig, bot}}],
      Table[With[{w = 0.3 (rig - lef)},
        With[{x = lef + i * w - w/3},
         {Rectangle[{x, bot}, {x + w/3, 
            bot + (top - bot)*{b1, b2, b3}[[i]]/(Max[b1, b2, b3]*1.2)}],
          Text[Style[i,
            FontWeight -> Bold,
            FontFamily -> font,
            TextAlignment -> Left,
            FontSize -> Scaled[0.06/(3*pw + 2*d)]],
           {x + w/6, bot - d/4}, {0, 1}]}]],
       {i, 3}],
      Text[Style["AMOUNT OF\nBLACK INK\nBY PANEL:",
        FontWeight -> Bold,
        FontFamily -> font,
        TextAlignment -> Left,
        FontSize -> Scaled[0.05/(3*pw + 2*d)]],
       {pw + 1.5 d, 1 - 0.5 d}, {-1, 1}]
      }]
    },
   {(* right panel *)
    With[{lef = 2 pw + 4 d, rig = 3 pw + d, w = 3 pw + 2 d},
     With[{y0 = 0.4 - (rig - lef)/(2 w), h = (rig - lef)/w, dd = d/3},
      {Arrowheads[0.01],
       Arrow[{{lef - dd, y0 - dd}, {lef - dd, y0 + h + 2 dd}}],
       Arrow[{{lef - dd, y0 - dd}, {rig + 2 dd, y0 - dd}}],
       Line[{{lef - 1.3 dd, y0}, {lef - 0.7 dd, y0}}],
       Line[{{lef, y0 - 1.3 dd}, {lef, y0 - 0.7 dd}}],
       Text[Style["0",
         FontWeight -> Bold,
         FontFamily -> font,
         TextAlignment -> Left,
         FontSize -> Scaled[0.05/(3*pw + 2*d)]],
        {lef - 2 dd, y0}, {1, 0}],
       Text[Style["0",
         FontWeight -> Bold,
         FontFamily -> font,
         TextAlignment -> Left,
         FontSize -> Scaled[0.05/(3*pw + 2*d)]],
        {lef, y0 - 2 dd}, {0, 1}],
       Inset[g, {lef, y0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{1, 1}*h]],
       Text[Style["LOCATION OF\nBLACK INK IN\nTHIS IMAGE",
         Background -> White,
         FontWeight -> Bold,
         FontFamily -> font,
         TextAlignment -> Left,
         FontSize -> Scaled[0.05/(3*pw + 2*d)]],
        {2 pw + 3 d, 1 - d/2}, {-1, 1}]}]
     ]
    }}]

step[{g_, b1_, b2_, b3_}] := Module[{g2, pix},
  g2 = ColorConvert[Rasterize[b2g[g, b1, b2, b3], "Image", ImageSize -> 1000],
     "Grayscale"];
  pix = ImageData[g2];
  {g2,
   1 - Mean[
     Flatten[pix[[All, ;; \[LeftCeiling]Length[pix[[1]]]/3\[RightCeiling]]]]],
   1 - Mean[
     Flatten[pix[[
       All, \[LeftFloor]Length[pix[[1]]]/3\[RightFloor] ;; \[LeftCeiling](
         2 Length[pix[[1]]])/3\[RightCeiling]]]]],
   1 - Mean[
     Flatten[pix[[All, \[LeftFloor](2 Length[pix[[1]]])/3\[RightFloor] ;;]]]]}
  ]
```

Creating the image:

```
First@FixedPoint[step, {Graphics[{}], 0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  SameTest -> (Norm[Rest[#1 - #2]] < 1*^-3 &)]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

A quick example how to generate the first two frames. Just the basic layout, no fancy annotations, but you should get the idea.

First, define the functions that draw the frames:

```
frame1[{int1_, int2_}] := 
 PieChart[{(int1 + int2)/2, 1 - (int1 + int2)/2}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Black, White}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[1], Thick]], 
  ImageSize -> 150, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
  FrameStyle -> Thick]
frame2[{int1_, int2_}] := 
 Framed[BarChart[{int1, int2}, ChartStyle -> Black, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", BarSpacing -> 0.8, Ticks -> None, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ImageMargins -> 10, 
   AspectRatio -> 1
   ], FrameStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> {150, 148}]
```

Then, iterate over the objective function, which in this case computes the intensity (gray level) of the frames:

```
FixedPoint[(1 - 
      ImageMeasurements[Rasterize@#, "MeanIntensity"] & /@ {
     frame1[#], frame2[#]
     }) &, {0.5, 0.5}]
Row[{frame1[%], frame2[%]}]
```

> ```
> {0.239555, 0.404095}
> ```

[image: output charts]