# Generate a smooth random function (2D curve) with endpoints specification?

Tags: differential-equations, random, splines

Here is a PDE example, adapted from [Wolfram Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html):

```
bsol = First[NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] ==
0.1*D[u[x, t], x, x] - u[x, t] D[u[x, t], x],
u[x, 0] == 1 - x^2, u[-1, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0}, 
u, {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 4}]]
```

In my work, I need to change the initial condition (IC) to a smooth random function, but with endpoints located at $u(-1, 0) = u(1, 0) = 0$, which should be suitable for being an IC of the PDE in `NDSolve`.
To this end, I use

```
ini[x_] = BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], SplineClosed -> True][(x + 1)/2];
```

After plotting,

```
Plot[ini[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: something like this]

we find that the endpoints are not satisfied with $u(-1, 0) = u(1, 0) = 0$. But I cannot come up with an simple way to do this. Given a `BSplineFunction` through the two end-points, I specified the endpoints as follows:

```
Join[{{-1, 0}}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], {{1, 0}}]
```

but it doesn't work. I think it's almost there... I really hope somebody can help me out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the first coordinate in the `Join` correct?

Comment: Try this: `BSplineFunction[
 Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n - 1], {0.}],
 SplineClosed -> True
 ]`

Comment: I think `SplineClosed -> True` somehow destroys your zero boundary condition. With `SplineClosed -> False` it works as Henrik showed.

Comment: Thank you for the correct me @user21, corrected it.

Comment: Thanks @Thies Heidecke by `SplineClosed -> True` I just want to make the two end-points the same... see @ Henrik Schumacher also suggest `SplineClosed -> True`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Could you explain a little what is `n`, why `n-1`, and why `{0.}` works? Thanks you very much! I try `ini[x_] = 
 BSplineFunction[Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 11-1], {0.}], 
   SplineClosed -> True][(x + 1)/2]`. However, both `ini[-1]` and `ini[1]` close to zero but not exactly.

Comment: That's why i said try `SpineClosed -> False`, then it works. The manually added zero endpoints will make sure they match zero, `SpineClosed -> True` is for periodic boundary conditions which you don't need here.

Comment: Here is another suggestion for you to consider, which I can elaborate later on when I can borrow a computer. Take any function satisfying your endpoint conditions (e.g. an `InterpolatingPolynomial[]`), and then perturb it with 1D Perlin noise, just like what I did in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159630).

Comment: A second possibility is to use `BrownianBridgeProcess[]` with `RandomFunction[]` to generate a bunch of points, which you can then feed to a [cubic periodic spline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10277).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me expand on one of the comments I gave earlier.

As I mentioned, one can use `BrownianBridgeProcess[]` with `RandomFunction[]` to generate a set of points that can then be passed to `Interpolation[]` to get a random smooth function with the desired endpoint conditions:

```
BlockRandom[(* for reproducibility *)
            SeedRandom["somefunction", Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
            jsxs = Interpolation[MapAt[Rescale[#, {0, 2}, {-1, 1}] &, 
                                       RandomFunction[BrownianBridgeProcess[0, 2],
                                                      {0, 2, 1/32}]["Path"], {All, 1}],
                                 Method -> "Spline"]];
```

Plot the random function:

```
Plot[jsxs[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: random function]

Use it in the PDE:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] == 0.1 D[u[x, t], x, x] - u[x, t] D[u[x, t], x],
                    u[x, 0] == jsxs[x], u[-1, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0}, u,
                   {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}];

Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: PDE solution with smooth random BC]