# How add noise to a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, stochastic-calculus

I have a differential equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\operatorname{sech}(x-1)$$

I want to add noise to it and try to solve it numerically, but it seems that I am programming something wrong, because there is no noise. I am trying to do this by adding a random number.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {α = 1, β = 1/20, γ = 1, 
  h = 1, ω = 2 Pi 1/2, μ = 1, xs = -1, xe = 1}

f = Sech[x[t] - xe]

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
    ArcTan[1 D[f, x[t]]] + RandomReal[{-1/10, 1/10}], 
   x[0] == xs}, {x}, {t, 0, 500}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], xe}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 40]
```

Comment: `NDSolve[]` does not have a `Hold*` attribute, so `RandomReal[{-1/10, 1/10}]` gets evaluated at once.

Comment: @J.M. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe add noise=RandomReal[{-1/10, 1/10}] right after the definition of f and then sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == ArcTan[1 D[f, x[t]]] + noise, x[0] == xs}, {x}, {t, 0, 500}]?

Comment: @DanieleBinosi
No, it doesn't work

Comment: @dtn yes my bad, I realized it when it was too late

Comment: @dtn Can you convert it into an ItoProcess?

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159614)

Comment: @DanieleBinosi No, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to make random noise over the range `t` = 0 to 10:

```
ttab=Table[i/10,{i,0,100}];

Noisetab=Table[Random[Real, {-1/10, 1/10}], {101}]

Noise=Interpolation[Table[{ttab[[i]],Noisetab[[i]]},{i,101}]]
```

Plot the noise.

```
Plot[Noise[t],{t,0,10}]
```

[image]

You can then add `Noise[t]` to your differential equation.  If you want more or fewer points in your noise or a different range, you can make adjustments.

Editing your NDSolve statement and plotting:

```
sys = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == ArcTan[1*D[f, x[t]]] + Noise[t], x[0] == xs}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], xe}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you!

Comment: I did it a little differently: `x'[t] == ArcTan[1 D[f, x[t]]] + 
  k Sin[RandomReal[{-100, 100}] t] Sin[
    RandomReal[{-100, 100}] t] Sin[RandomReal[{-100, 100}] t]`

Comment: That works too.   I am sure there are many ways to randomize functions of time that are suitable.