# Sketching Normal Probability Distributions Graphs

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Hi can someone please tell me how I can sketch a simple normal probability distribuition statement such as:
'The height of a certain population of adult males is normally distributed with mean 176cm and standard deviation 6cm.' 
How can I do a quick sketch just to illustrate?
Thanks

Comment: Is this a Mathematica related question? If so, I suggest you to look into the MMA documentation: NormalDistribution, PDF and Plot.

Answer (score 4):

Using definitions from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/134):

```
xkcdConvert[
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[176, 6], x], {x, 100, 200}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"height",  "PDF"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Distribution of height"]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for sketchiness.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The whole point really !