# Create recursive sequence of functions with memoization

Tags: function-construction, memoization

I am trying to create a sequence of functions and have it properly memoize the results. The recursive operation is simply convolution, so it possible there is a better way to do this (obviously, if I could find a closed form expression for the n-th convolution, that would be ideal, but I'm not certain I can do that). Here is my current code

```
f[x_, c2_] := (
 Exp[-c2^2/2 + c2 Sqrt[-Log[2 π] - 2 Log[x]]] + 
 Exp[-c2^2/2 - c2 Sqrt[-Log[2 π] - 2 Log[x]]]
) / Sqrt[(-Log[2 π] - 2 Log[x])]

LogExpect[x_, shift_] := Piecewise[{{f[Exp[x], shift] Exp[x], x < -1/2 Log[2 π]}}, 0]

LogExpectN[t_, n_] := Module[{xx}, 
  LogExpectN[t, n] = Convolve[LogExpectN[xx, n - 1], LogExpect[xx, 0], xx, t]
]
LogExpectN[t_, 1] = LogExpect[t, 0]
```

In general this works, as it will properly calculate `LogExpectN[t,5]` for example, and it will memorize that specific result, but if I ask it for `LogExpectN[2 t,5]` or `LogExpectN[x,5]` it has to redo the copmutation completely, instead of just plugging `2t` or `y` into the function it already found and thus there is no speed up from the memoization. Is there a way to get the behavior I want?

Edit: By changing the the recursive definition to use a pattern, I have improved things

```
LogExpectN[t_, n_] := Module[{xx}, LogExpectN[t_, n] = Convolve[LogExpectN[xx, n - 1], LogExpect[xx, 0], xx, t]]
```

However, This only works if I evaluate consecutive values of `n` in order. FOr example, after setting the base case for `n=1`, I can calculate for `n=2` and then `n=3`, but if I try to calculate `n=3` directly, it will give me an expression in terms of the internal variable `xx$<numbers>$`. I am not really sure what is going on here.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [(53)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/53/121)

Answer (score 2):

Memoize a worker function.

```
f[x_] := f[x] = (Print["Memoized ", x]; f[x - 1] + 1);
f[0] = 0;
{f[3], f[3]}
(*the first f[3] prints trice, the second does not print*)
```

Then, use the worker function to memoize your main function.

```
SetAttributes[g, HoldFirst]
g[x_] := g[x] = f[x];
{g[2 2], g[2 2 + 1]}
(*g[2 2] prints 4, g[2 2 + 1] prints 5*)
```

Check that the downvalues of the main function have your required behavior.

```
DownValues[g]
(*there are entries for 2 2 and 2 2 + 1*)
```

Note that you cannot combine the worker function and the main function in one step because `HoldFirst` will not allow to get to the stopping `h[0]`.

```
SetAttributes[h, HoldFirst]; 
h[x_] := h[x] = (Print["Memoized ", x]; h[x - 1] + 1);
h[0] = 0;
h[3]
(*Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded*)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Consider

```
LogExpectN[t, n] = worker[n][t]
```

Because there are two variables, there are two memoizations involved. One to compute the `n`-th worker function and another to avoid replacing `t` in that worker function. The code before this update takes care of second type of memoization. The first memoization is trickier because you are computing a function.

```
f[x_, c2_] := (Exp[-c2^2/2 + c2 Sqrt[-Log[2 π] - 2 Log[x]]] + 
 Exp[-c2^2/2 - c2 Sqrt[-Log[2 π] - 2 Log[x]]])/
   Sqrt[(-Log[2 π] - 2 Log[x])];

LogExpectN[t_, n_] := LogExpectN[t, n] = (Print["Memoizing t=", t]; worker[n][t]);

worker[n_] := 
  worker[n] = 
   Module[{xx, tt, integral}, Print["Memoizing n=", n]; 
    integral = Convolve[worker[n - 1][xx], stoppper[0][xx], xx, tt]; 
     Function @@ {tt, integral}];

worker[1] = stoppper[0];

stoppper[shift_] := 
  Function[{x}, 
   Piecewise[{{f[Exp[x], shift] Exp[x], x < -1/2 Log[2 π]}}, 0]];

LogExpectN[t, 2]
(*Prints t=t and n=2*)

LogExpectN[t, 3]
(*Prints t=t and n=3*)

LogExpectN[3 t, 2]
(*Prints t=3 t only*)
```

Comment: Thanks. When I manage to apply this to my code I will accept the answer. Still trying to figure out the how and why of this.

Comment: After futzing around, I can't get this approach to work.

Comment: @irh Maybe, your problem is needing to evaluate the integral before memoizing the worker function. In the update, check the usage of `Function @@`.