# Compound Statements and returning earlier results in () parentheses

Tags: programming, return-value

I am trying to debug some script and need to `Print[]` out some results, sometimes before, and sometimes after, certain executions.

These 3 trials exemplify my question, and the last one is where my problem is -- How do I print out previously calculated results with in parenthesis? (e.g. "previous result is: ..." should be visible)

```
In[12]:= ClearAll[f, x];
f[x_] := f[x] = Which[
   x == 0, 1,
   x == 1, (Print["at x=1 "]; 1),
   x >= 1, (x*f[x - 1]; Print["main one..."])
   ]

In[14]:= f[2]

During evaluation of In[14]:= at x=1 

During evaluation of In[14]:= main one...

In[15]:= ClearAll[g, x];
g[x_] := g[x] = Which[
   x == 0, 1,
   x == 1, (Print["at x=1 "]; 1),
   x >= 1, (x*g[x - 1]; Print["main one..."])
   ]

In[17]:= g[2]

During evaluation of In[17]:= at x=1 

During evaluation of In[17]:= main one...

In[22]:= ClearAll[h, x];
h[x_] := h[x] = Which[
   x == 0, 1,
   x == 1, (Print["at x=1 "]; 1),
   x >= 1, (Return[x*h[x - 1]]; Print["previous result is: ..."])
   ]

In[24]:= h[3]

During evaluation of In[24]:= at x=1 

Out[24]= 6
```

This http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html?view=all wasn't too helpful, except I think it returns only the last expression in a pair of `()`. These examples only show the `Print[]` operation before the desired return value... [Create recursive sequence of functions with memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176544/create-recursive-sequence-of-functions-with-memoization)

**UPDATE**

Maybe I should clarify.

I want this:

```
ClearAll[h, x];
h[x_] := h[x] = Which[
   x == 0, 1,
   x == 1, (Print["at x=1 "]; 1),
   x >= 1, (x*h[x - 1]; Print["leaving"])
   ]

h[4]

at x=1 

leaving

leaving

leaving
```

but also the result to be used in a further, continuing calculation. This way I know it has successfully left this case of `Which[]`.

Comment: [`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html).

Comment: Your use of Return prevents the code after Return from being executed.

Comment: in the last one above, without the return, it will only print out 'previous result is:...'. How do I get the result (e.g. 24 for f[4] *and* a message at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform some actions after computing the result but before returning it, you can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to store the result temporarily:

```
ClearAll[h, x];
h[x_] := h[x] = Which[
   x == 0, 1,
   x == 1, (Print["at x=1 "]; 1),
   x >= 1, With[{res=x*h[x - 1]}, Print["leaving"]; res]
   ]

h[4]
(* at x=1 *)
(* leaving *)
(* leaving *)
(* leaving *)
(* 24 *)
```

For this particular example, you can further use the following, more Mathematica-like approach:

```
ClearAll[h, x];
h[0] = 1;
h[1] := (Print["at x=1"]; 1)
h[x_] := h[x] = With[{res=x*h[x - 1]}, Print["leaving"]; res]
```

An alternative to `With` and @CarlWoll's answer might also be to (ab)use [`EchoFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EchoFunction.html):

```
ClearAll[h, x];
h[0] = 1;
h[1] := (Print["at x=1"]; 1)
h[x_] := h[x] = EchoFunction["leaving" &][x*h[x - 1]]
```

Comment: Both great answers! I guess for compactness though I'll try to avoid clutter with a helper function and go with With[].  Now to try and utilize it in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180143/recursion-stuck-for-a-memoizing-function

Answer (score 1):

You could define a helper function:

```
myprint[control_, x_]:=(Print[StringForm[control, x]]; x)
```

Then:

```
ClearAll[h, x];
h[x_] := h[x] = Which[
    x == 0, 1,
    x == 1, myprint["at x=`1`", x],
    x >= 1, myprint["previous result is: `1`", x*h[x - 1]]
]

h[4]
```

> at x=1
>
> previous result is: 2
>
> previous result is: 6
>
> previous result is: 24
>
> 24

Comment: An alternative to a custom helper function might be to use ``EchoFunction[StringTemplate["previous result is: `1`"]][x * h[x - 1]]``