# Converting an Image into a Mathematica Plot?

Tags: plotting

Consider the following graphical representation of the [No Free Lunch Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) found from Google Image:

> [image]

What I'd like to do (if possible) is convert this into a Mathematica Plot so that I can (i) add an extra function to it and (ii) adjust the plot labels. Does Wolfram technology make this possible (through some sort of "Image -> Plot" function?)?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Wolfram blog 2012/10/05](https://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/) xkcd-sytle diagrams article.

Comment: Sounds like the OP is asking if he can convert a JPEG, PDF,BMP or other graphic file into Mathematica plot data.  If you plot a simple graph like myPlot=Plot[x,{x,0,1}]  and then do a ?myPlot, you obtain the format of Mathematica's graphics.  It contains lines, points, colors, other data to generate the plot.  I do not know if there is any software that can for example convert a PDF file to Mathematica's graphics format.  Maybe others know.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1333219).

Answer (score 2):

```
f2 = 1/((x - 3)^2 + 1/7);
f1 = 1 + 1/2 Sin[x] + 1/5 Sin[2 x] + 1/7 Sin[3 x];
g = Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All, FrameTicks -> None, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> {{ True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Performance", "Type"}, FrameStyle -> 18, 
  PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome", "BoldColor"}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Dashing[{0.05}], Line[{{0, 1}, {12, 1}}]}]
xkcdConvert[g]
```

This yields

[image] 
[image]

using a magnificent `xkcdConvert` function of [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-plots)