# Plot problems: vertical lines and letters

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, code-request

In few words, I would make this graph:

[image]

My many problems are the following:

How do I plot a vertical line? What's the equation?

How do I add the letters on the lines?

How to make the Ticks like $P_0$ $P_1$ and so on?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You may want to use `Graphics` and just draw lines that look that way. Don't see why you would want to model this with equations.

Comment: Perhaps you just want the [drawing tools](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html#990684267).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  Graphics[{Line[{{1, 2}, {3, 2}}], Line[{{3, 2}, {3, 1}}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.10, 4}, {-0.1, 2.5}}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Ticks -> {{{1, 
       Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(0\)]\)", Italic, 16, 
        Black]}, {3, 
       Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(1\)]\)", Italic, 16, 
        Black]}}, {{1, 
       Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)", Italic, 16, 
        Black]}, {2, 
       Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)", Italic, 16, 
        Black]}}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["T(K)", 16, Italic, Black], 
     Style["P(Pa)", 16, Italic, Black]}],

  Graphics[{Text[Style["A", Black, 16], {1, 2.15}], 
    Text[Style["B", Black, 16], {3, 2.15}], 
    Text[Style["C", Black, 16], {3.15, 1}]}]

  }]
```

with the effect

[image]

To my taste this is more straightforward than to draw it by equations.

However, you definitely can draw these lined using standard Plot-family functions. Consider, for example, this:

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot[{1, y}, {y, 0.5, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}],
  ParametricPlot[{x, 1}, {x, 0.5, 2}]
  }]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Wow that is wondrous!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

#### ListPlot

```
coords = {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}};

labeledcoords = MapThread[Labeled, 
    {coords, {"A", "B", "C"}, {Above, Above, Below}}];

ListLinePlot[labeledcoords, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {T[k], P[Subscript[p, a]]}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03],
  Ticks -> {Thread[{{1, 3}, Subscript[T, #] & /@ {1, 2}}], 
      Thread[{{1, 2}, Subscript[P, #] & /@ {1, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

To get a hand-drawn look use [Simon Woods' xkcdConvert](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/125):

```
 xkcdConvert @ %
```

[image]

#### Graphics

```
Graphics[{Thick, Line[Partition[coords, 2, 1]], 
    MapThread[Text, {Style[#, 14] & /@ {"A", "B", "C"}, 
        coords , {{0, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3}}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {T[k], P[Subscript[p, a]]}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03], 
  Ticks -> {Thread[{{1, 3}, Subscript[T, #] & /@ {1, 2}}], 
      Thread[{{1, 2}, Subscript[P, #] & /@ {1, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

#### ParametricPlot

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{ {2, 1 <= x < 3}, {1, x == 3}}, Undefined]

ParametricPlot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AxesLabel -> {T[k], P[Subscript[p, a]]}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03], PlotStyle -> Black,
  Ticks -> {Thread[{{1, 3}, Subscript[T, #] & /@ {1, 2}}], 
      Thread[{{1, 2}, Subscript[P, #] & /@ {1, 2}}]},
  Epilog -> MapThread[Text, 
   {Style[#, 14] & /@ {"A", "B", "C"}, coords, {{0, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The famous code "xkcdConvert" was remembered again. It's amazing.