# Where is Abbott? How to make logograms from the film "Arrival"?

Tags: graphics, generative-art

The film *Arrival* showed Wolfram Language code in action analysing alien logograms. A recent
[blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/01/31/analyzing-and-translating-an-alien-language-arrival-logograms-and-the-wolfram-language/) describes some details and
[mentions](https://www.liveedu.tv/christopherwolfram/videos/LAAJL-the-code-behind-arrival-the-movie/)
a live-coding video by Christopher Wolfam. See also Stephen Wolfram's
[blog post](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2016/11/quick-how-might-the-alien-spacecraft-work/).

The logograms appear to be hand drawn in ink, and I seek help from the community to reproduce them via the Wolfram Language. Some examples follow.

[image: example logograms]

**Three Questions**
What techniques can you suggest to improve the match between computer-generated logograms and those which appear in the movie?
Specifically, how to improve:
1) background circular strokes
2) blobs
3) tendrils

Comment: Abbott is in death process.

Answer (score 20):

For making tendrils, I used `AnglePath` on 1/f noise from `NoiseGen`.

```
NoiseGen[n_, e_] :=
   Block[{f, fe = Range[n/2]^e, d = {}},
      f = E^(I 2.0 \[Pi] RandomReal[{0., 1.}, n/2])/fe;
      f[[-1]] = Re[f[[-1]]];
      d = Join[d, Chop[InverseFourier[
             Join[{0}, f, Conjugate[Reverse[Drop[f, -1]]]]]]];
      Rescale[d]]
```

For making blobs and blurring lines, I borrowed [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-to-make-an-inkblot/) from the answer by @Sjoerd C. de Vries.

A long definition of Logogram

```
Logogram[{rmin_, rmax_}, {wmin_, wmax_}, cv_, nc_, {dmin_, dmax_},
         nd_, b_, phi0_, seed_,
         {rbmin_, rbmax_}, {pmin_, pmax_}, {bmin_, bmax_}, nb_, phi1_,
         {nxmin_, nxmax_}, {tlenmin_, tlenmax_}, noiseExp_, scale_, 
         ntendrils_] :=

   Block[{radius = 1000., r, c, p, w, t, dp, g, nx, tlen, noise, c0},
     SeedRandom[seed];
     Binarize[Blur[Dilation[
        Graphics[{CapForm["Round"],

     (* circles composing circular stroke *)
        Table[
          r = RandomReal[radius*{rmin, rmax}];
          c = RandomReal[{-r, r}*cv, 2];
          p = RandomReal[{0, 6.283}, 2];
          w = Thickness[RandomReal[{wmin, wmax}]];
          {w, Circle[c, r, p + phi0]},
        {i, 1, nc}],

   (* additional disks composing circular stroke *)
        Table[
          r = RandomReal[radius*{rmin, rmax}];
          t = RandomReal[{0, 6.283}] + phi0;
          Disk[r*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, RandomReal[radius*{dmin, dmax}, 2]],
        {i, 1, nd}],

   (* disks composing blob on circular stroke *)
        Table[
          r = RandomReal[radius*{rbmin, rbmax}];
          dp = RandomReal[{pmin, pmax}];
          Disk[r*{Cos[phi1 + dp], Sin[phi1 + dp]}, 
               RandomReal[radius*{bmin, bmax}, 2]],
        {i, 1, nb}],

   (* tendrils on blob *)
        g = Table[
          nx = RandomReal[{nxmin, nxmax}];
          tlen = 2*RandomInteger[{tlenmin, tlenmax}];
          noise = nx*NoiseGen[tlen, noiseExp];
          noise = noise - Mean[noise];
          c0 = radius*{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &[phi1 + RandomReal[{pmin, pmax}]];
       Transpose[
         c0 + scale*
           Transpose[(-1)^RandomInteger[{0, 1}] AnglePath[noise]]],
      {i, 1, ntendrils}];
   Thickness[0.008], Map[Line, g]

   }, ImageSize -> 1000],
   DiskMatrix[2]], 3], b]
  ]
```

`Manipulate` to experiment.

```
Manipulate[
   Logogram[{rmin, rmax}, {wmin, wmax}, cv, nc, {dmin, dmax},
        nd, b, phi0, seed,
        {rbmin, rbmax}, {pmin, pmax}, {bmin, bmax}, nb, phi1,
        {nxmin, nxmax}, {tlenmin, tlenmax}, noiseExp, scale, ntendrils],

     Style["Circular Brush Stroke", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold],
     {{rmin, 0.98, "Minimum Circle Radius"}, 0.9, 1.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{rmax, 1.02, "Maximum Circle Radius"}, 0.9, 1.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{wmin, 0.0003, "Minimum Line Thickness"}, 0.0002, 0.008, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{wmax, 0.0010, "Maximum Line Thickness"}, 0.0002, 0.008, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{cv, 0.05, "Circle Centre Variation"}, 0.01, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{nc, 300, "Number of Circles"}, 20, 1000, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{phi0, 5.0, "Angle of Circle Gap"}, 0.0, 6.3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{dmin, 0.010, "Minimum Disk Radius"}, 0.001, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{dmax, 0.030, "Maximum Disk Radius"}, 0.001, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{nd, 50, "Number of Disks"}, 10, 300, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,

     Style["", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold], Style["Blob", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold],
     {{rbmin, 0.98, "Minimum Radial Distance"}, 0.9, 1.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{rbmax, 1.02, "Maximum Radial Distance"}, 0.9, 1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{bmin, 0.020, "Minimum Blob Radius"}, 0.001, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{bmax, 0.070, "Maximum Blob Radius"}, 0.001, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{nb, 30, "Number of Blob Disks"}, 5, 200, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{phi1, 2.0, "Initial Blob Angle"}, 0.0, 6.3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{pmin, 0.0, "Minimum Angular Extent"}, 0.0, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{pmax, 0.8, "Maximum Angular Extent"}, 0.1, 2.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,

     Style["", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold], Style["Tendrils", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold],
     {{nxmin, 0.1, "Minimum Curliness"}, 0.01, 1.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{nxmax, 0.5, "Maximum Curliness"}, 0.03, 1.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{tlenmin, 10, "Minimum Tendril Length"}, 2, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{tlenmax, 20, "Maximum Tendril Length"}, 2, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,
     {{noiseExp, 1.0, "Noise Exponent"}, 0.1, 3.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{scale, 10.0, "Tendril Step Size"}, 1.0, 50.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{ntendrils, 7, "Number Of Tendrils"}, 2, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,

     Style["", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold], Style["Overall Parameters", 12, Bold], Style["", 12, Bold],
     {{b, 0.8, "Binarize Threshold"}, 0.1, 1.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{seed, 0, "Random Number Seed"}, 0, 1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter,

     ControlPlacement -> Left, SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

[image: manipulate logogram]

Comment: Could someone make me two? Wife Daughter