# How to generate blobs of a given circularity?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I'm trying to generate some "imaginary" geographic regions (think of it as islands, for instance), by generating random blobs/blots. Currently, I'm using Szabloc's [blotc[] function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-to-make-an-inkblot). However, for my application, I'm looking for some way to determine the circularity of the blob beforehand (defined in MMA's `ComponentMeasurements` [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html), i.e. $2\pi*r/p$, with polygonal length $p$ and equivalent disk radius $r$).

Currently, I'm simply generating a bunch of blots and then selecting these with a circularity value I want, but as you can see, the process is inefficient, and blots with small circularity values are underrepresented (ideally I'd like to uniformly sample circularity values close to 0 up to close to 1).

```
(*Szabloc's function blotc[]*)
blotc[smoothness_ : 20, points_Integer : 10] := 
 With[{fun = Exp[-smoothness #.#] &, 
   pts = RandomReal[1, {points, 2}]}, 
  With[{fc = 
     Compile[{xl, yl}, Total[fun[# - {xl, yl}] & /@ pts] > .5]}, 
   RegionPlot[fc[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, Frame -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black]]]

(*Let's generate a bunch of blots varying the two parameters in the function.
This part takes about 1.5 minutes 1000 blots in a "normal" laptop. 
It'll throw some warning regarding real numbers, but works regardless*)

myBlots = 
  Table[blotc[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}]], 1000];

(*Let's compute the circularities, form the binary images*)
myCircularities = 
  ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@Image[#], "Circularity"] & /@ 
   myBlots;

(*We show the histogram to see the distribution of circularities' frequencies*)
Histogram[Flatten[Values[myCircularities]], 20]
```

[image]

A solution would look like:

```
myCustomBlob[myCircularity_]:=
```

And ideally would produce a graphic object that I can then binarize myself, in case I need to rescale the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way to deal with this would be to change the blotc function to generate assymmetric blobs in the first place.

```
blotc2[smoothness_ : 20, points_Integer : 10, symm_ : 0.5] := 
    With[{fun = Exp[-smoothness #.#] &, 
    pts = Transpose[{RandomReal[1 - symm, points], RandomReal[symm, points]}]}, 
    With[{fc = Compile[{xl, yl}, Total[fun[# - {xl, yl}] & /@ pts] > .5]}, 
       RegionPlot[fc[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, Frame -> False, 
       PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black]]]
```

If you run with the default symm set to 0.5, it works as before. Setting symm to 0.9

```
Table[blotc2[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}], 0.9], 50]
```

gives lots of vertically oriented blobs while symm = 0.1 gives horizontally oriented blobs. If you want more flexibility, you can use a rotation matrix to get an arbitrary angle by replacing the definition of pts with:

```
pts = Dot[RotationMatrix[deg Degree], #] &/@ RandomReal[1, {points, 2}]]
```

(where deg is now an input parameter replacing symm). And of course you could skew it or use other transformations.