# What's the difference between EdgeDetect and MorphologicalPerimeter (for a white background)?

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to understand the differences between `EdgeDetect` and `MorphologicalPerimeter` (while researching [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4246/700)). I understand that, if the image background is not white, they will yield completely different results:

[image]

However, I am not sure whether they are guaranteed to return the same result if the background is white. In my tests, they do:

[image]

Could someone confirm this conclusion, or show a counter-example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they're **not** the same, and will not, in general, give the same result because they're two very different operations.

- **`MorphologicalPerimeter`** gives a Boolean output according to the following logic:

  1. `1` — If the pixel value is `1` (i.e., white) and at least `1` pixel in its 8-pixel neighbourhood is `0`.
  2. `0` in all other cases.

  Here's an example with a simple `20x20` image with 1 black pixel along the diagonal. You can actually follow the logic above to verify the output (assume 0 outside the edge for pixels along the border)

  ```
  img = ColorNegate@Image@IdentityMatrix[20];
  MorphologicalParameter[img]
  ```

  [image]
- **`EdgeDetect`**, by default, uses the [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) which is a lot more complicated, multi-step algorithm unlike `MorphologicalPerimeter`. Roughly speaking, it convolves it with a Gaussian filter, followed by a non-maximum suppression step, which basically sets all pixels that aren't a local-maxima to zero. You can read more about it in the Wikipedia article.

  Performing an edge detection on the above image gives you:

  ```
  EdgeDetect[img]
  ```

  [image]

  You can visibly see the difference between the two images above, especially at the corners and the borders.

Comment: thanks for this very clear answer!

Answer (score 5):

As R.M already indicated both methods are completely different. `EdgeDetect` uses gradient based methods, which detect areas in which gradients change sharply. This works nicely on grayscale and color images, as gradients are easy to define there. The basic parameter here is the scale of the gradients that are taken into account.

`MorphologicalPerimeter` on the other hand, uses a strictly binary approach as explained by R.M. So, how can it work on grayscale and color images then? Well, simple, it uses `Binarize` or something equivalent internally. You can see that the parameters of `Binarize` and `MorphologicalPerimeter` behave identically:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The basic parameter of `MorphologicalPerimeter` is the threshold, which is principally different from the gradient scale of `EdgeDetect`.

That `EdgeDetect` and `MorphologicalPerimeter` are not identical, even in your "figure 8" example where they seem similar can be easily determined using:

```
ImageData[MorphologicalPerimeter[Graphics[Style[Text["8"], 400]]]] == 
 ImageData[EdgeDetect[Graphics[Style[Text["8"], 400]]]]

(*
==> False
*)
```

In the zebra example `MorphologicalPerimeter` can output more than a black image if you tweak the scale parameter:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

In the help file it says "MorphologicalPerimeter[image] is equivalent to MorphologicalPerimeter[image,0]" treats values above t as foreground.. So, using value other than 0 gives the result you need.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that answers the question. I'm asking: for a white background, are `MorphologicalPerimeter` (with its implied zero as second parameter) the same as `EdgeDetect`?

Comment: well the point is: the function yields a binary image in which pixels considered to be on the morphological perimeter have value 1 and others have value 0. So every thing is above 0 so it's all black...