# "Covering up" text in Graphics

Tags: graphics, text, graphics3d

Consider the following code:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[], Opacity[1.0], Blue, 
Polygon[{{-.2, -.3, -.3}, {-.2, .3, -.3}, {-.2, .3, .3}, {-.2, \
-.3, .3}}]}], 
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], Cos[th]}, {th, 
0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Doctored somewhat from another question on this site.) It produces a sphere, with an opaque red surface, except for two "portholes", which allow one to see the blue rectangle inside.

Now consider the following minor tweak, replacing the square by some text:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[], Opacity[1.0], Blue, 
Text["Surprise!", {0, 0, 0}]}], 
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], Cos[th]}, {th, 
0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The output (which I don't know how to save as a rotating GIF [side question?]) shows the blue text *over* the red sphere, whether or not I am "looking" through the porthole or not.

The reason for this is in the help:

> Text is drawn in front of all other objects.

Is there way to treat Text like other Graphics primitives, so that indeed it will be a "Surprise!" when you look through the porthole? That is, to get behavior similar to that of the blue rectangle?

Perhaps I should clarify I am most interested in being able to change the "z order" of the Text. But the fact that it doesn't rotate with the rest of the Graphics objects (using the mouse) is also kind of annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: This was in fact the reason for me to ask [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/637/57).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `Inset`:

```
  Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[], Opacity[1.0], Blue, 
  Inset[Graphics[Text[Style["Surprise!", Green, 24]]], {0, 0, 0}]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], Cos[th]}, {th, 
   0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}]
```

which gives

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Texture`:

```
  text = Style["Surprise!!", 128];
  vrtxtxtrcoords = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0,  1}}; 
  Show[{Graphics3D[{Texture[text], 
  Polygon[{{-.2, -.3, -.3}, {-.2, .3, -.3}, {-.2, .3, .3}, {-.2,  -.3, .3}},  
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> vrtxtxtrcoords]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], Cos[th]}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}]
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I voted for this, then I un-voted because this doesn't appear to work on my system: "Inset is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive."  Yet, [`Inset` was supposedly last modified in v7](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html).  Is this just another documentation oversight or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it does work without error in V8.0.4.0. But `Inset` documentation does not include anything that suggest it would work.

Comment: `Inset` in 3D is a V8 feature.  Currently it is restricted to a form that always faces the user (like `Text`) but can be obscured by other objects (unlike `Text`.)

Comment: My vote is restored.

Comment: I had a tough time picking.  In the end, the Texture method seems the easiest and closest to what I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

For this purpose I made a function that puts an arbitrary expression into a 3D graphic. It's described on [this page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/label3D.html), going back originally to [this MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/pemqb9z6l2o/q7gFjzsNLU4J), I'll copy the code here:

```
label3D[s_, pos_, xVec_, tiltAngle_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ra, width, height, r}, 
   ra = Rasterize[
     Style[HoldForm[s], FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Style]], 
      Magnification -> 10], 
     Evaluate@
      Apply[Sequence, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Rasterize]]], 
     "Image"];
   {width, height} = ImageDimensions[ra];
   r = SetAlphaChannel[ra, 
     With[{color = 
        Apply[List, 
         ColorConvert[
          "TransparentColor" /. {opts} /. {"TransparentColor" -> 
             Apply[RGBColor, ImageData[ra][[2, 2]]]}, "RGB"]]}, 
      Binarize[ra, (Norm[# - color] > .005) &]]];
   Translate[(* //to make lefthand corner pos*)
    Rotate[(*   //around z axis*)
     Rotate[(* //around y axis*)
      Rotate[(* //tilt around x axis*)
       Scale[(*//to make width equal|
        xVec|*){EdgeForm[FrameStyle /. {opts} /. FrameStyle -> None], 
         Texture[ImageData@r],(* //
         Texture fills polygon initially in the xz plane*)
         Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, 0, height}, {0, 0,
             height}}, 
          VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
             1}}]}, Norm[xVec]/width, {0, 0, 0}], 
       tiltAngle, {1, 0, 0}],(* //x rotation*)
      Arg[Chop@N[Norm[xVec[[1 ;; 2]]] + I xVec[[3]]]], {0, -1, 
       0}],(* //y rotation*)
     Arg[Chop@N[xVec[[1]] + I xVec[[2]]]], {0, 0, 1}],(* //z rotation*)
    pos]];
SetAttributes[label3D, HoldFirst]
```

With this, you can draw your test as follows:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[]},
    {Glow[Purple], 
     With[{position = {0, -.5, 0}, direction = {0, Cos[.1], Sin[.1]}, 
       tiltAngle = 0},
      label3D["Surprise!", position, direction, tiltAngle, 
       FontColor -> Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]
      ]}
    }], ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], 
    Cos[th]}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]},
 ViewPoint -> {2, .1, .5}]
```

[image: surprise]

Note that although the text was rasterized in this approach, the background is transparent. The text also maintains its orientation with respect to the other objects. I'm going with this rasterized approach because 3D graphics eventually always require rasterization anyway when you want to export them at a reasonable file size.

Since I was just doing another gif animation, I thought this post could also use one:

```
frames = Table[
  Show[{Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], 
       Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .99]}, {Glow[Purple], 
       With[{position = {0, -.5, 0}, 
         direction = {0, Cos[.1], Sin[.1]}, tiltAngle = 0}, 
        label3D["Surprise!", position, direction, tiltAngle, 
         FontColor -> Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]}}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], Cos[th]}, {th,
       0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}, 
   ViewVector -> { 
     3.5 {Cos[Pi/4 (1 - Sin[a/2]^2)], 
       Cos[a] Sin[Pi/4 (1 - Sin[a/2]^2)], 
       Sin[a] Sin[Pi/4 (1 - Sin[a/2]^2)]}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewAngle -> .6, 
   ViewCenter -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
  , {a, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}];
Export["surprise.gif", frames, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 
  Join[.03 & /@ Range[20], {1}, .03 & /@ Range[20]]]
```

[image: gif animation]

Answer (score 16):

You can generate actual 3D data describing the text by Importing from PDF.

```
wordData = ImportString[ExportString["Surprise", 
  "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]];
Graphics3D[Tube[#, 0.2] & /@ Map[Append[#, 0] &, wordData, {2}]]
```

[image]

Or, in reference to Sjoerd's comment to the OP,

```
wordData = ImportString[ExportString[Style["\[Euro]", 
  FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]];
Graphics3D[Polygon /@ Map[Append[#, 0] &, wordData, {2}]]
```

[image]

Then, you can insert that in your image.  The `Tube` primitive doesn't run too smoothly, though.  Let's try a line.

```
word3D =Line /@  Map[{0,-0.5,-0.2}+Prepend[#,0]&,
  wordData/40,{2}] ;
Show[{Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[]}, word3D}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], Cos[th]}, 
    {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] < .9], 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}]
```

Comment: This is problematic with closed-shape characters. "oae" etc. do not render properly because holes are filled. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @Yves Imported PDF represents letters using `FilledCurve`, which represents holes easily.  There should be enough information in the `FilledCurve` to extend to a 3D polygon representing the character with a hole. That's a bit more work, though, and is exactly why I used `Tube` and `Line`, rather than `Polygon` for the main answer.

Comment: Yup, with versions prior to 7 this worked just fine. That is why I fervently wish that `FilledCurve` were adapted to work as a 3D primitive as well. That should be awesome. I think David Park´s `Presentation` package offers something with a `ParametricPlot` based workaround, but workaround it remains...

Comment: @YvesKlett There's a Demonstration by Michael Schreiber that uses this Import[Export PDF technique to get polygons with holes projected onto a cube. That might help: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NumberedCube/