# How to fill in an irregular border of an image

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

I have the following code which draws a graphic, and colors the regions in it in different colors:

```
g = {{Circle[#, 1 - Sqrt[2]/2] & /@ Tuples[0.5 {-1, 1}, 2]}, 
     {Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}};

graphic = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]]]
```

[image: starting image]

```
image = Rasterize[graphic, "Image", ImageSize -> 800];

regions = MorphologicalComponents[image, 0.9];

newimage = ImageResize[
   Colorize[regions, 
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", Mod[Sin[#^2], 1]] &), 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
   Scaled[0.5]
   ]
```

[image: colored version]

I'd like the color for the region that is outside all of the circles to be black.  What's the best way to do this?

(The ideal solution would still work if I set `PlotRangePadding -> None` on the original graphic, which will cause the exterior to be several components instead of just one.)

Comment: I've done something like this as part of the answer [linked here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245) - may have time to adapt it for your question in a few minutes...

Comment: The simplest answer is `DeleteBorderComponents` - see my updated answer. Still, combining it with an alpha channel gives more flexibility, so I defined a new function `deleteBorder` for that purpose.

Comment: @Jens Interesting, since as far as I can tell `DeleteBorderComponents` claims to only work for binary images (and matrices.)

Comment: Yes indeed - maybe it works for your image because of the black lines bounding the inside. Anyway, it does work for your case, but I think the `deleteBorder` function I defined is of much more general utility.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Original attempt, experimentation**

OK, I have an answer based on an alpha channel but it required more morphological manipulations first.

The good thing is that it should work for other shapes, and requires *only* the final product `newimage`. However, to make it work reliably, I needed to increase the image size to avoid some boundary lines bleeding into each other.

```
newimage = 
 ImageResize[
  Colorize[regions, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", Mod[Sin[#^2], 1]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], Scaled[1]]
```

Here is the image processing:

```
imAlpha = ImageCompose[
  newimage,
  SetAlphaChannel[#, ColorNegate[#]] &@Erosion[
    FillingTransform@SelectComponents[
      MorphologicalPerimeter[
       Binarize[newimage],
       CornerNeighbors -> False
       ],
      "EnclosingComponentCount", # == 1 &
      ], .5
    ]
  ]
```

[image: black border]

**Edit: streamlined version**

Now I combined my approaches from above (which relies on `SelectComponents`) with the border color selection from [this earlier answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245) (using `Binarize` with a custom test function) to make a function `deleteBorder` that can remove a homogeneous border background from *an arbitrary image* `im`:

```
Options[deleteBorder] = {Tolerance -> .005};
deleteBorder[im_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
   rgb = ImageData[ColorConvert[im, "RGB"]][[2, 2]],
   tol = OptionValue[Tolerance]
   },
  SetAlphaChannel[im, ColorNegate[#]] &@
   SelectComponents[Binarize[im, Norm[# - rgb] <= tol &],
    "EnclosingComponentCount", # == 0 &
    ]
  ]
```

It works by setting the alpha channel to a binarized version of `im` in which the outermost region is transparent.

Here is another example:

```
im2 = Rasterize[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[4 Pi t], Cos[3 Pi t], 
    Sin[2 Pi t + Pi/3]}, {t, 0, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Brown, Tube[.03]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   Background -> Green, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], "Image", 
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: swirlsGreen]

```
deleteBorder[im2]
```

[image: swirlsGreenAlpha]

You can now superimpose this result on any other image and the border region (appearing white above) will  show as transparent. E.g., try `Show[%, Background -> Red]`.

To show that this works independently of the background color, let's do:

```
im3 = Rasterize[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[4 Pi t], Cos[3 Pi t], 
    Sin[2 Pi t + Pi/3]}, {t, 0, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[.03]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   Background -> Magenta, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], "Image", 
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: swirlmagenta]

```
Show[deleteBorder[im3], Background -> Red]
```

[image: swirlRed]

**Edit 2: combining with `DeleteBorderComponents`**

The question has an image whose border has different uniform colors in different pieces *and* perhaps these pieces are disjoint, as shown here:

```
g = {{Circle[#, 1 - Sqrt[2]/2] & /@ 
     Tuples[0.5 {-1, 1}, 2]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}};
graphic = 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]], 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];
image = Rasterize[graphic, "Image", ImageSize -> 800];
regions = MorphologicalComponents[image, 0.9];
newimage = 
  ImageResize[
   Colorize[regions, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", Mod[Sin[#^2], 1]] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], Scaled[1]];
```

[image: borderTHin]

Here is a very simple way to do make the border black:

```
DeleteBorderComponents[newimage]
```

[image: thinbackground]

Here I use the built-in function `DeleteBorderComponents` to immediately get rid of the border and set its color to `Black`.

That's all there is to it - **this basically is the simplest answer to the original question!** But it's the boring route.

With my function `deleteBorder` you can go much further than this:

```
Show[deleteBorder[DeleteBorderComponents[newimage]], 
 Background -> Blue]
```

[image: blueThinBorder]

`deleteBorder` replaces `Black` by a transparent region. This actually makes the black lines between the circles transparent too, and we can now still choose an arbitrary background color (`Blue`), or superimpose the result onto a different image.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the image processing tools to do this. In short, you use `FillingTransform` to fill the inner parts and create a mask and then use `ImageApply` to set the pixels in the region given by mask to your desired colour.

```
mask = ImageResize[FillingTransform[ColorNegate@Binarize@image] // ColorNegate, Scaled@0.5];

Clear[f]
f[__] := {0, 0, 1}; (* RGB values of the chosen colour *)
ImageApply[f, newimage, Masking -> mask]
```

[image]

However in this specific case, with the way `MorphologicalComponents` works, the space outside all the circles in your figure will be assigned the label `1`. So you could simply do something like:

```
Clear@f
f[1] = Blue;
f[x_] := ColorData["SolarColors", Mod[Sin[x^2], 1]]
Colorize[regions, ColorFunction -> f, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Comment: This is what I'd come up with, although it feels hacky to me.  I edited the question slightly (but this is still a valid answer.)

Comment: That's so easy. My approach would have used an alpha channel but that causes colors in the middle to be transparent too if they're the same as outside. So +1.

Answer (score 10):

The function `ComponentMeasurements` has the option `"BorderComponents"` which when set to `False` will ignore components that are connected to the border. You could use this to filter for the internal components only. For example

```
internal = ComponentMeasurements[regions, "Label", "BorderComponents" -> False];

newimage = 
 ImageResize[
  Colorize[regions /. Append[internal, _Integer -> 0], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", Mod[Sin[#^2], 1]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], Scaled[0.5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This also works when multiple regions are touching the border, e.g.

```
graphic = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]], 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]

image = Rasterize[graphic, "Image", ImageSize -> 800];
regions = MorphologicalComponents[image, 0.9];
internal = ComponentMeasurements[regions, "Label", "BorderComponents" -> False];

newimage = ImageResize[
  Colorize[regions /. Append[internal, _Integer -> 0], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", Mod[Sin[#^2], 1]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], Scaled[0.5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

As R.M observed the border region is numbered `1`.  We can therefore do:

```
ArrayPlot[regions /. 1 -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixPlot[regions /. 1 -> Black, Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 7 does not have the `Colorize` function but we can whip up something:

```
rls = # -> RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3] & /@ Union @@ regions;
PrependTo[rls, 1 -> Black];

MatrixPlot[regions /. rls, Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]