# Fill a Circle in an Image

Tags: image-processing, image

Let's suppose I have something like this (the image resulting from this):

```
ColorNegate[Rasterize[Graphics[Circle[{100, 100}, 50]]]]
```

Now, what I want to do is fill the inside of the circle (in the image, not transforming Circle->Disk :) ) with White (the color of the circle).

Ideas?

Comment: `Binarize@FillingTransform@
  ColorNegate[Rasterize[Graphics[Circle[{100, 100}, 50]]]]` works for your specific case, though without the binarize the color is different to the edge

Comment: Also see here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/how-to-fill-in-an-irregular-border-of-an-image

Comment: Oh... Of course it's FillingTransform. I didn't know about the Binarize. Thank you. If you want to create an answer, and explain maybe better the Binarize part, I'll accept it.

Comment: there you are, hopefully a better explanation of the binarization...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FillingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingTransform.html) is what you're after:

```
img = FillingTransform@ColorNegate[Rasterize[Graphics[Circle[{100, 100}, 50]]]]
```

[image]

But this gives a gray fill because your image wasn't binary to begin with. Easy to fix, e.g. with a subsequent `Binarize`:

```
Binarize@img
```

[image]

Alternatively, [`ColorReplace[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorReplace.html?q=ColorReplace) might provide a more general solution.

```
ColorReplace[img, Gray -> White]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Using `RegionImage`:** (Introduced Sept 14, 2017)

```
RegionImage[Disk[]]
```

[image]