# How to get 2D graphics into 3D without background?

Tags: graphics

Consider the following code:

```
g=Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}],
            {Green,Opacity[0.5],Rectangle[{0,0.5},{1,1}]},
            Red, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}],
            White, Disk[{1/2, 1/(2Sqrt[3])}, 1/(2Sqrt[3])]},
           Background->None];
Graphics3D[{{Texture[g],
             Polygon[{{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{1,1,0},{1,0,0}},
                     VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}]},
            {Texture[g],
             Polygon[{{0,0,1},{0,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,1}},
                     VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}]}},
           Lighting->{{"Ambient", White}},
           ViewPoint->{1,4,7}]
```

This gives the following graphics:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can easily see, the part outside of the figures is opaque white, despite of the `Background->None` option. Also `Background->RGBColor[1,1,1,0]` didn't help, nor did passing the Graphics through `Rasterize` with the option `Background->None`

Here's roughly what I'd want to get (any inaccuracies are caused by my lacking GIMP-fu :-)):

[image: What I would want it to look like]

Looking for a solution I found [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/129) but couldn't get it work for my case. Also, if I understand it correctly, it doesn't derive the transparency from the graphics but just replaces a certain colour with fully transparent, which wouldn't work with the semi-transparent green rectangle.

Combining the 2D graphics with another one using `Show` does respect `Background->None` and `Opacity` on the green rectangle, so it's not a problem with the graphics itself.

Therefore my question: Is it possible to embed 2D graphics into 3D while keeping the transparency of the 2D image, and if so, how?

Comment: Can't try it on the computer I'm in, but how about getting `ImageData[Image[g]]`, replace all the white (`{1., 1., 1.}`) with transparent (`{0., 0., 0., 0.}`) components, and then give that as the argument to `Texture[]`?

Comment: @J.M.: See my third-to-last paragraph.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I've now found the solution. The trick is to extract the data from the raster and pass it to the texture directly (for some reason I also have to reverse the list to get the same result):

```
gtexture=Texture[Rasterize[g, Background -> None][[1,1]]/255 //Reverse];
Graphics3D[{{gtexture,
             Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
                   VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
            {gtexture,
             Polygon[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}},
                   VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
           Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},
           ViewPoint -> {1, 4, 7}]
```

This gives the desired result:

[image: result]

Comment: Update for v12.3: as far as I can tell, using just `gtexture = Texture[Rasterize[g, Background -> None]]` will do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution partially based on [this](http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2009/02/howto-display-2d-plot-in-3d.html) blog post. I needed to change some of your definitions, but I think the following should work. First, define a function that does some things for us:

```
to3d[plot_, height_, opacity_] := Module[{newplot}, newplot = First@Graphics[plot]; 
  newplot = N@newplot 
    /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} :> {x, y, height} 
    /. Disk[x_, y_] :> Cylinder[{x, x + {0, 0, 0.001}}, y];
  newplot /. GraphicsComplex[xx__] -> {Opacity[opacity], GraphicsComplex[xx]}]
```

Define your shapes separately now:

```
r = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], {Green, Opacity[0.5], 
     Polygon[{{0, 1}, {0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}, {1, 1}}]}}, 
   Background -> None];
t = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Red, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}], White, 
    Disk[{1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])}, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])]}, Background -> None];
```

(Note the changed Rectangle -> Polygon definition. Polygon is valid for both 2D and 3D). Put everything together:

```
Graphics3D[{to3d[r, 1, 0.5], to3d[t, 1.01, 0.5], to3d[r, 0, 0.5], 
   to3d[t, .01, 0.5]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Giving: [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note, I'm not sure the `GraphicsComplex` part of the `to3d` function is necessary, but it works with it in, so I just left it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's... *an* approach:

```
g = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], {Green, Opacity[0.5],
     Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {1, 1}]}, Red, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}], White, 
    Disk[{1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])}, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])]}];

lifted = N[g] /. {
    {x_Real, y_Real} :> {z, y, x},
    Rectangle :> Cuboid,
    Disk :> Sphere};

zlevelI = 0;
zlevel[] := (zlevelI = zlevelI + .001);

Show[
 Graphics3D @@ (lifted /. z :> 1 + zlevel[]),
 Graphics3D @@ (lifted /. z :> 0 + zlevel[])]
```

[image]

You get the idea. It appears to be... *moderately* generalizable:

```
g = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], {Green, Opacity[0.5],
     Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {1, 1}]}, Red, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}], White, 
    Disk[{1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])}, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])]}];

g2 = Plot[{Sin[x*2], Sin[4 x], Sin[6 x]}, {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick];

lift = {
   {x_Real, y_Real} :> {z, y, x},
   Rectangle :> Cuboid,
   Disk :> Sphere};

lifted = N[g] /. lift;
lifted2 = N[g2] /. lift;

zlevelI = 0;
zlevel[] := (zlevelI = zlevelI + .001);

Show[
 Graphics3D @@ (lifted /. z :> 1 + zlevel[]),
 Graphics3D @@ (lifted2 /. z :> 0)]
```

[image]

But it's definitely not ideal.

Comment: The `Disk`→`Sphere` replacement is visibly wrong. Maybe a `Tube` would be a better option. But a similar stacking done by hand I've indeed used as workaround (but using `Polygon` objects in 3D). As you say, it's not ideal. If you make the z stacking too large (for sufficiently complex pictures), it can get visible, while if you make it too small, you may get artefacts from rounding errors. And of course you are limited to certain perspectives (though that was not a problem in my application). Anyway, the automated calculation of the z stacking is an interesting solution. +1.

Comment: Yea I was just trying to get the idea across. The Sphere is there for lollerskates and a proper z-ordering would require a more involved replacement. E.g. capturing `obj_[coords_] :>` to apply a uniform Z to the object as a whole instead of iterating on each coordinate.