# Make continuous 3D tube out of 2D image (Mathematica 8)

Tags: graphics3d, image, opacity

I have the following image with transparency:

[image]
which I want to paste repeatedly into a 3D space to make it like a tube, something like this (but denser):

[image: Tube Test]

I tried using the code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11561/how-to-get-2d-graphics-into-3d-without-background) but it tells me that "Image is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive", and although the code from the question works, it has the same problem as in the question, **it is not transparent**.

So what should I use to make the transparency render? Or is there a better approach to my problem?

This is the slightly edited code I used:

```
g = Import["C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\Tube.png"];
Graphics3D[
Table[{{Texture[g], 
Polygon[{{0, 0, z}, {0, 1, z}, {1, 1, z}, {1, 0, z}}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
1}}]}}, {z, 0, 1, 1/3}], Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
ViewPoint -> {1, 4, 7}]
```

Edit: I need this to work on 8.0, although Image3D works it is not implemented there, what can I do then?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean "paste repeatedly into a 3D space to make it like a tube"?  Edit your question to include the code that you have written, even though it does not fully meet your need.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Done.

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the Tube.png image in the question

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks for the suggestion, also done!

Comment: Although you're asking for a solution in an older version, the topic is already covered elsewhere:  [How to extrude a 3D image from a binary 2D image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6206/how-to-extrude-a-3d-image-from-a-binary-2d-image). Answers that apply to version 8 can also be found there.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzimv.png"];  
i = ImageResize[i, 200];    

Image3D[Table[i, {200}]]
```

[image]

If it's just for display, there is no need to create multiple copies of the image - just make a 3D image one pixel deep and use `BoxRatios` to stretch it vertically:

```
Image3D[{i}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it works, but sadly I am stuck in 8.0 and Image3D was introduced in 9.0. Is there a similar function I can use?

Comment: @AnonymousPi, AFAIK there is nothing similar to Image3D in version 8, so you will need to use Graphics3D in some way. I suggest you edit the question to state that you need a version 8 solution, and unaccept this answer (questions without an accepted answer tend to get more views)