# How can I overlap image on Graphics3D at a specific position?

Tags: graphics3d, image

I make a `Polygon` with size of {width=0,length=50,height=30}; I want to overlap `Image` on `Polygon` at position {width=0,length=25,height=15}.  For this purpose I wrote some code:

myImage=

[image]

```
     Show[Rasterize[Show[Graphics3D[Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 30}, {0, 50, 30}, {0, 50, 0}}], 
                               Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False
                                   ](*Graphi3D is closed here*)
                        ](*Show is closed*),
                    "Image",Background -> None, ImageSize -> {300,300}
                   ](*RasterSize is closed here*), 
          Graphics[Inset[Image[myImage(*its a variable*), ImageSize -> {50, 50}],Scaled[{25, 15}]]]
        ](*Show is closed here*)
```

After evaluation of the above code I faced two problems

1. Graphics3D is not rotated,
2. `Image`is not overlapped,

I want to overlap `Image` at a specific position on `Polygon` and if we have rotated `Polygon` automatically that overlapping `Image` was also rotated.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Covering up" text in Graphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4833/covering-up-text-in-graphics)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Texture` to draw your image on the polygon.

```
myImage=RandomImage[0.5, {15, 15}];

Graphics3D[{Texture@myImage, 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 30}, {0, 50, 30}, {0, 50, 0}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed->False]
```

( With thanks to cormullion for the `Boxed->False` option. )

> [image: Mathematica graphics]  (* Boxed-> True *)

```
myImage=ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]; (* Boxed-> True *)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myImage = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LF9n.jpg"]; (* Boxed-> False *)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the nice illustrative answer. I would like to add that if someone wants to have the box look like cube, you can simply set the `ImageAspectRatio->1` and `AspectRatio->1`

Answer (score 5):

The good Doctor beat me, but anyway:

```
poly = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 30}, {0, 50, 30}, {0, 50, 0}};
texture = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LF9n.jpg"];
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> "Neutral", Texture[texture], 
  Polygon[poly, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 
      1, 0}}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: butterfly on a page]

Comment: @image_doctor,@ cormullion Thank you for your information...           I have one more doubt,how can I overlap two Images on same polygon at different positions

Comment: @subbu You can use `ImageCompose` to combine images into a single image, then use that as the texture. There are many options for positioning the images...

Comment: already i played with `ImageCompose` still i didn't get it,how can I overlap two or more `Images` on `polygon`...If you don't mine can you explain ?