# Text Annotation Disappears in Wrapped 3D Graphics

Tags: graphics3d

In a 3D graphic, if I wrap a figure, for example,

```
imagewrapped = 
 With[{Lx = 10, Ly = 10, Nx = 5, Ny = 5, r0 = 2, ftsz = 12}, 
  Graphics3D[{Table[{Sphere[{ix Lx, iy Ly, 0}, r0]}, {ix, 1, Nx}, {iy,
       1, Ny}], Red, 
    Table[Text[Style[ix, ftsz, Bold], {ix Lx, 0, 0}], {ix, 1, Nx}], 
    Cyan, Table[
     Text[Style[iy, ftsz, Bold], {0, iy Ly, 0}], {iy, 1, Ny}]}, 
   Boxed -> False, Lighting -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

[image: image wrapped]

some text disappear. How can I wrap the figure without loosing information?

Comment: Why did you decide to shrinkwrap the figure?  It seems to look ok when shrinkwrap is False.

Comment: @ David, actually, I have other primitives in my final figure. It will have huge white margins, that's why I need to wrap it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Among the answers linked by Mr. Wizard, there's also my `label3D` function. Looking at that, I think in your case it would work as a replacement for `Text` as well. In that answer, I set a `HoldFirst` attribute, but I think it's not that convenient here. So I would suggest executing the definition for `label3D` in [the linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245), followed by

```
ClearAttributes[label3D, HoldFirst]

imagewrapped = 
 With[{Lx = 10, Ly = 10, Nx = 5, Ny = 5, r0 = 2, ftsz = 12}, 
  Graphics3D[{Table[{Sphere[{ix Lx, iy Ly, 0}, r0]}, {ix, 1, Nx}, {iy,
       1, Ny}], Glow[Red], 
    Table[label3D[
      Style[ix, ftsz, Red, Bold], {ix Lx, 0, 0}, {-5, 0, 0}, 0], {ix, 
      1, Nx}], Glow[Cyan], Table[
     label3D[Style[iy, ftsz, Cyan, Bold], {0, iy Ly, 0}, {0, 5, 0}, 
      0], {iy, 1, Ny}]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> Automatic, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

[image: 3d labels]

This seems to be treated correctly by `ShrinkWrap`. To make the labels look as much like the `Text` labels, I gave them a `Glow` to prevent them to display with shading.

Answer (score 3):

The text seems to be laid on after the ShrinkWrapped size is determined.  One simple suggestion is to include an *almost* transparent (`Opacity[1/255]`) sphere at the position of each letter to prevent clipping.  This is less than ideal for several reasons, among them:

- The spheres change size along with the graphic while the text remains an absolute size.
- The spheres as subject to perspective scaling while the text is not.
- Even when carefully sized the edges of the spheres do not perfectly align with the text so the wrapping will be inexact.

A better approach might be to create actual 3D text as Mark did [here.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4839/121)  That should be respected by the ShrinkWrap algorithm along with the other 3D primitives.

Answer (score 3):

As a variant of Mr.Wizard's suggestion, you might place an essentially clear cuboid around the  figure with text.  The following is inserted into `Graphics3D[{...}]`

```
{Opacity[0.01], EdgeForm[], Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {50, 50, 2}]}
```

`EdgeForm[]` prevents the edges from being displayed.

[image: Mathematica graphics]