# How to obtain sheared text label effects?

Tags: plotting, labeling

How to make the text labels of 3D plots look always like coplanar with the specific axes planes no matter how the viewpoint/view angle changes?

Here are examples of such effect:

[image: example]
[image]

Comment: Not with inbuilt standard options. This will most likely be a quite messy affair (e.g. using textures).

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9007/862)

Comment: Potentially useful tip: `Texture` may be not only a raster, but also a [vector object with text in textual form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47273/280).

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21401/245)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really the answer, but a comment. I need this format to place an image. I think the "Presentations" package of David Park could help. It enables one to draw the text like this:

[image]

Comment: What I do is upload an image using the answer box, then copy the URL and paste it into my comment without posting the answer. Of course then people still need to click the link to see the image.

Comment: Maybe a code sample then? :)

Comment: @Kuba I am sorry, I gave this answer 2 years ago, and did not keep the code. However, I remember that the example I gave is very close to the examples collected in Presentations of David Park and is quite straightforward.