# Bad rendering of rotated text in 3D graphics in notebooks

Tags: graphics3d, rendering, rotation

Why is my rotated text so badly rendered in 3D graphics in notebooks (the exported pdf are OK).  It happens for me with v9 or v10.1.0 and OSX (10.9.5).

Notice that the rendering is good in 2D graphics.

Here is the difference between rotated text in 2D vs 3D graphics:

```
Graphics[{Text[Style[Rotate["Hello", 5 Degree], 80], {0, 0}], Circle[]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Text[Style[Rotate["Hello", 5 Degree], 80], {0, 0, 0}], Sphere[]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[]}, Epilog -> Text[Style[Rotate["Hello", 5 Degree], 80], {0.5, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Both the 3D text look good for me with mma 10.1 on OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Just to make sure: Anti-aliasing is set to the highest quality in Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics, right?

Comment: @Pickett Right, anti-aliasing is on, i checked that first. Any problem for you ? What OS and MMA version do you have ?

Comment: I also see the bad rendering on two different computers with OS X and with versions 8 and 10. Maybe it depends on the graphics card.

Comment: As a possible workaround, you could use `label3D` from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245) and do: `Graphics3D[{label3D["Hello",{-1/2,-1,0},RotationMatrix[5 Degree,{0,-1,0}].{1,0,0},0,FontFamily->"Times"],Sphere[]}]`

Comment: @Jens On my MacBook Pro, I have two NVIDIA cards, the rendering is the same (bad) whatever the card I use ... What are your graphics card ?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your nice `label3D` function (i was aware of the `Rasterize` /`Texture`/`Polygon` approach but missed that post). It might be indeed very useful though the text is now not static anymore but rotates with the chosen ViewPoint.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for the info. Just in case, what graphics card do you have ?

Comment: @SquareOne NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB