# Add delay to the final frame of a GIF?

Tags: export, animation, gif-format

I'd like for there to be a pause during the final frame in my animation, before it loops.

Here's some tweekable starter code:

```
frames = Import["ExampleData/cellularautomaton.gif"];

Export["~/cellularautomaton.gif", frames, "Interlaced" -> True, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> Table[0.1, Length[frames]], 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> \[Infinity]]
```

I looked at the docs for .GIF, nothing there on this. Also, I thought of padding the list with repetitions of the last frame, but that is a waste of space, and the GIF mime type supports this.

Comment: I believe the only solution to this is the ugly brute force way: give it a bunch of duplicate copies of the last frame.

Comment: @george2079 has it right, there's no delay-by-frame options.

Comment: having said that, @Karsten7 's answer does work. I don't know how universally that will be supported by different viewers however.

Comment: @george2079 Providing a list as `DisplayDuration` has worked pretty much since forever. See, e.g., [this old post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245). So there definitely **is** a delay-by frame option.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply increase the display duration for the last frame.

```
Export["test.GIF", frames, "Interlaced" -> True,   
 "DisplayDurations" -> ReplacePart[Table[0.1, Length[frames]], -1 -> 1.0], 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞]
```

Citing the [GIF documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GIF.html):

> - "DisplayDurations"->{d1, d2, ...} specifies the display durations for each frame in an animated GIF. If the list of display durations is shorter than the number of frames, the sequence is repeated as necessary.
> - With the default setting "DisplayDurations"-> Automatic, the display time will vary on different viewer applications.

Comment: "All too easy" - I forgot I was using a list!

Comment: This could be a separate questions, but what about changing the "AnimationDirection" to "ForwardBackward" in the gif? Would I have to double the number of frames or is there an undocumented option?

Comment: @M.R. AFAIK there is nothing like an "AnimationDirection" for GIFs. It's not part of the file specification and it's not how GIFs work.  If you want to create a "ForwardBackward" GIF, you'll have to create a complete "ForwardBackward" list of frames as one loop. If you do so just using *Mathematica* the file size will probably be twice. However, other tools (e.g. GIMP) can do a much better job optimizing a GIF (for example using combine frames instead of replace frames), which results in much smaller file sizes.

Comment: @M.R. [This GIF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAVLz.gif) is *Mathematica* exported forward (2 KB), [this GIF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r5uNh.gif) is *Mathematica* exported forward and backward (4 KB), and [this GIF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6O07Q.gif) is the forward and backward GIF optimized with GIMP (1 KB).

Comment: Nice! Also seems the minimum display duration is 0.015 second, can you confirm?

Comment: @M.R. In the GIF file format specifications it is called delay time. Its minimum is 0 and its smallest nonzero number is one hundredths of a second, which is also the minimum increment. But browsers will use a fixed value that is specific to the browser if the delay is under a certain threshold (that is browser specific, again).