# Create GIF looping animation

Tags: plotting, export, animation, gif-format

I created the GIF animation with the plot of a sinusoidal wave moving  towards the LHS of the image, suggested [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/465460).

```
gif = Table[Plot[Sin[a + x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 10, 0.1}];
Export["sinSmooth.gif", gif]
```

After showing all the correct motion, the GIF stops. Most of the GIFs created in this site don't, instead.

In [the same link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/465460) it is suggested how to let the animation go backwards after reaching the end:

```
gif = Table[Plot[Sin[a + x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 10, 0.1}];
Export["sinSmoother.gif",Flatten[{gif, Table[gif[[i]], {i, Length[gif] - 1, 2, -1}]}]]
```

But anyway, after completing one or two cycles (depending on the image viewer used), even this way it stops.

What about creating a continuous loop?

Is there an option (in the `Plot`, `Block` or `Export` function) which can make the GIF continuously being reproduced, regardless of the image viewer?

Comment: please paste your code or show a minimal example !

Comment: @AliHashmi I just made as you suggested.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As partly mentioned in this: [Add delay to the final frame of a GIF?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115851/add-delay-to-the-final-frame-of-a-gif?rq=1)   we can use `"AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞` to loop a GIF indefinitely:

```
Export["C:\\Users\\Ali Hashmi\\Desktop\\test.gif", gif, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞]
```

Comment: I can't make it to work on 12.1. Any idea why?

Comment: @samwolfe `AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity` spits out an error but works anyway.

Comment: Note that the quotes are _very_ important, without them the option won't have any effect!