# How to rescale a Graphics3D object?

Tags: graphics3d

I've created a `Graphics3D` object by extruding a binary 2D image (as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6208/685)).

```
pts = ImageData[ColorNegate@Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWO6k.png"], "Bit"];
g = RegionPlot3D[pts[[Sequence @@ Round@{i, j}]] == 1, {i, 1, #1}, {j, 1, #2},
  {z, 0, 300}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> False, Axes -> True, 
  Boxed -> False] & @@ Dimensions[pts]
```

[image]

This object has dimensions 600 $\times$ 600 $\times$ 300 and it is centered on (300, 300, 150). In other words, all coordinates are within the ranges of the given dimensions.

My need is to be able to rescale this object by preserving the same `Graphics3D` structure (i.e., including vertices, polygons, vertex normals, etc.). The new ranges of dimensions I'm looking for are ((-0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, 0.5), (-0.25, 0.25)).

I had no troubles to rescale the coordinates of the `GraphicsComplex`, but these are not enough to then export the `Graphics3D` as an .obj file. A second approach that I took was to  use `TetGenLink` to recompute the needed information, but since my object has also concavities this did not work as expected.

Has anyone done this before? Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `RescalingTransform`:

```
Graphics3D[{
            GeometricTransformation[
                          First@g, 
                          RescalingTransform[{{1, 600}, {1, 600}, {0, 300}}, 
                                             {{-.5, .5}, {-.5, .5}, {-.25, .25}}]]}
          , Axes -> True]
```

[image]