# Generating cylindrical geometry via extruding a section

Tags: programming, geometry

Toady I want to build geometry as shown below:

[image]

I know the *Mathematica* owns the *built-in* like `Cylinder[]`, `Sphere[]` and so on, but it lacks of a function that could construct user-defined geometry, so I have a trial as below:

**TengentLine**

```
 lineCofficient[x1_, y1_, r1_, x2_, y2_, r2_, style_] := Block[
 {},
   First@Solve[
   {(k x1 - y1 + b)/Sqrt[1 + k^2] == r1  style, 
    (k x2 - y2 + b)/Sqrt[1 + k^2] == r2 style},
   {k, b}]
 ]
```

**tangentPoint**

```
 tangentPoint[x1_, y1_, r1_, x2_, y2_, r2_, style_] := Block[
  {k, b},
 {
   Solve[
    {y == k x + b /.lineCofficient[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2,style],
    (x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 == r1^2}, {x, y}],
   Solve
    [{y == k x + b /. lineCofficient[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2,r2,style],
    (x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2 == r2^2}, {x, y}]
 } // Flatten[#, 1] &
]
```

**My geometry**

```
  FinalGeometry[x1_, y1_, z1_, r1_, x2_, y2_, z2_, r2_, h_] := Block[
  {x, y, one, two, three, four},
  Graphics3D[
  {Cylinder[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x1, y1, h}}, r1],
   Cylinder[{{x2, y2, z2}, {x2, y2, h}}, r2],

  one = Flatten[
    List[
      Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, -1], {{z1}, {z1}}, 2],
     Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, -1], {{h}, {h}}, 2]], 1];         

  two = Flatten[
     List[
     Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, 1], {{z1}, {z1}}, 2], 
     Join[{x, y} /. tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, 1], {{h}, {h}}, 2]], 1];

  three = Flatten[
    List[
     Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, -1], {{z1}, {z1}}, 2],
     Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, 1], {{z1}, {z1}}, 2]], 1];

  four = Flatten[
    List[
      Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, -1], {{h}, {h}}, 2], 
      Join[{x, y} /.tangentPoint[x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, 1], {{h}, {h}}, 2]], 1];

  Sequence @@
    (Polygon /@ 
      Flatten[{Partition[one, 3, 1], Partition[two, 3, 1], 
       Partition[three, 3, 1], Partition[four, 3, 1]}, 1])
  },
    BoxRatios -> Automatic
  ]
 ]
```

**Using my function:**

```
 FinalGeometry[0, 0, 0, 3, 12, 0, 0, 2, 2]
```

[image]

However, I felt my method is *tedious and ingeneral*. In addition, there are many other geometry "by extruding a section" like 3D software Autodesk Inventor.

So my question is:

- Is there a good and easy method to realize my function `FinalGeometry[]`?
- Is there possible to construct a function that can generate **a geometry that can rotate freely** **(not a static image)** by extruding a section?

Comment: Related: [How to extrude a 3D image from a binary 2D image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6206).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,I think it `isn't duplicte`,because (6206) is `just a image`,`not a geomatry that can rotate`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,I would like to use a geomatry that can rotate freely to construct a robot model,Can you help me?

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate since he seems to want an analytic representation of the solid.  Unfortunately I think the answer is simply 'no there is not a straightforward general approach'

Comment: @george2079 Okay.  As you can see I did not close the question. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,In Jens's method,`ColorReplace and Raster3D` is not in V8,in addition,halirutan's solution takes many time to calculate and it is hard to rotate.

Comment: Does this do the sort of thing you are looking for? -  `extrude = {0, 0, 1}; rule2Dto3D = {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} :> {x, y, 0}; ruleLine2Polygon = Line[{p_?VectorQ, q_?VectorQ}] :> Polygon[{p, q, q + extrude, p + extrude}];
ruleCircle2Cylinder = Circle[p_?VectorQ, r_?AtomQ] :> Cylinder[{p, p + extrude}, r]; object2D = {Line[{{0, 0}, {8, 0}}], Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Circle[{8, 0}, 1]};
object3D = object2D /. rule2Dto3D /. {ruleLine2Polygon, ruleCircle2Cylinder}; {Graphics@object2D, Graphics3D@object3D}`. It is limited to extruding line segments and circles, but extra 2D to 3D rules could be added.

Comment: @Stephen Luttrell,Oh,thanks,You can add this to answer,and make a example(for my geomatry that shown).

Comment: @Tangshutao Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,My vision is 8.0.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an extended version of the brief suggestion that I gave in my comment above.

Solve for the tangent points.

```
Solve[{#.# &[{x1, y1} - {0, 0}] == 3^2, #.# &[{x2, y2} - {12, 0}] == 2^2, 
  (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) == -((x1 - 0)/(y1 - 0)) == -((x2 - 12)/(y2 - 0))}, 
  {x1, y1, x2, y2}]

(* This gives 4 solutions *)
```

Define the extrusion vector.

```
extrude = {0, 0, 2};
```

CAVEAT: The various pattern tests that I use are somewhat incomplete.

Define a rule for embedding a 2D coordinate in the `z == 0` plane.

```
rule2Dto3D = {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0};
```

Define a rule for converting a circle to an extruded cylinder.

```
ruleCircle2Cylinder = Circle[p_?VectorQ, r_?NumericQ] :> Cylinder[{p, p + extrude}, r];
```

Define a rule for converting a list of line segments (assumed closed) to a box with caps on its bottom and top.

```
ruleClosedLine2Box = Line[p : {(_?VectorQ) ..}] :> 
  {Polygon[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[2]] + extrude, #[[1]] + extrude}] & /@ Partition[p, 2, 1], 
  Polygon[p], Polygon[(# + extrude) & /@ p]};
```

Define the 2D object — this uses one of the tangent points solutions (see above).

```
object2D = {Circle[{0, 0}, 3], Circle[{12, 0}, 2],
  Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x2, -y2}, {x1, -y1}, {x1, y1}}] /.
  {x1 -> 1/4, y1 -> -(Sqrt[143]/4), x2 -> 73/6, y2 -> -(Sqrt[143]/6)}};
```

Extrude the 2D object to create a 3D object.

```
object3D = object2D /. rule2Dto3D /. {ruleClosedLine2Box, ruleCircle2Cylinder};
```

Display the 2D and 3D objects.

```
{Graphics@object2D, Graphics3D@object3D}
```

[image]