# Extrude 2D cross-section to 3D shape with shrinkfactor

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I would like to create a 3D shape from extrusion and scaling of a 2D contour. The 2D contour that I have looks like this:

[image]

and it consists of a bunch of points (here plotted with `ListPlot` with `Joined->True`).

I have looked at a bunch of questions and answers here on Mathematica.SE, notably [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55459/construct-a-function-that-can-generate-a-geometry-by-extruding-a-section) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6206/how-to-extrude-a-3d-image-from-a-binary-2d-image), but I don't see how to apply those to my problem in any straightforward manner.

For the sake of a MWE I will switch to a circle from this point on:

```
xdata = Table[x, {x, -1, 1, 0.05}];
ydata = Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1, 0.05}];
circData = {Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], Transpose[{xdata, -ydata}]};
ListPlot[circData, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

The extruded shape that I would like to make then looks like this:

[image]

It is a shape consisting of slices of the contour with constant radius $r_0$ over some range let's say $-1 < z < 1$ and decrease in radius with $z$ at the tips according to $r(z)=r_0\sqrt{1-(z-1)^2}$ and $r(z)=r_0\sqrt{1-(z+1)^2}$ (depending on which tip).

**My question is: how can I do this extrusion for the set of listdata that I have?**

Just to be clear, to create the 3D shape for the circle I cheated and used the formula for a circle and a sphere like this:

```
p = Plot3D[{1 + Sqrt[1 - y^2 - x^2 ], -1 - 
     Sqrt[1 - y^2 - x^2 ]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange}, Lighting -> Automatic, Mesh -> Automatic, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None];
q = RegionPlot3D[
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange}, Lighting -> Automatic, Mesh -> Automatic, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None];
Show[p, q]
```

**Is there a way to achieve the same with the data from a list?**

---

**[Adaptation to thicknessFunc by @Halirutan and accompanying re-scaling]**

To make the thicknessFunc more generic I adapted it to:

```
thicknessFunc[z_, body_, 
  b_] := (HeavisideTheta[z] - HeavisideTheta[z - b])*
   Sqrt[b^2 - (z - b)^2] + 
  b (HeavisideTheta[z - b] - 
     HeavisideTheta[z - body - b]) + (HeavisideTheta[z - body - b] - 
     HeavisideTheta[z - body - 2 b])*Sqrt[b^2 - (z - body - b)^2]
```

such that you can set the radius of the circular parts by setting $b$. A consequence of this is that you have to rescale the thicknessFunc in append with $1/b$ like

```
Append[1/b thicknessFunc[u,2]*fdata[t], u]
```

I don't fully understand why, but I guess it has to do with the fact that `fdata` is multiplied by `thicknessFunc` and therefore needs the straight ends of `thicknessFunc` to be at 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in theory pretty simple. Think of it as two separated steps. First, you need function that models your extrusion-thickness, which has in the middle always the same value and at both ends it should round up like a circle. You can do this with `Piecewise` or, as I show here, with a combination of Heaviside functions:

```
thicknessFunc[z_, 
  body_] := (HeavisideTheta[z] - HeavisideTheta[z - 1])*
   Sqrt[1 - (1 - z)^2] + (HeavisideTheta[z - 1] - 
    HeavisideTheta[z - body - 1]) + (HeavisideTheta[z - body - 1] - 
     HeavisideTheta[z - body - 2])*Sqrt[1 - (z - body - 1)^2]
```

the parameter `body` is the size of the constant middle part. Here with the size of 2 ranging from 1 to 3:

```
Plot[thicknessFunc[u, 2], {u, 0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The other part is that you can interpolate your points, so that you get a function `fdata[t_]` which gets a single parameter `t` and runs along your points for `t` ranging from 0 to 1 (you can actually use whatever you like here):

```
data = Table[(1/4 Sin[5 phi]^2 + 1) {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/50}];
With[
  {ip = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}, PeriodicInterpolation -> True] & /@ Transpose[data]},
  fdata[t_] := Through[ip[t]]
 ]

ParametricPlot[fdata[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `fdata[t]` always returns points `{x,y}`. Now we turn this into a 3d function by combining the `thicknessFunc` with `fdata`. Our final function `f3d` will have two parameters: `t` which *walks* around the contour if increase it and `u` which defines our height and uses the `thicknessFunc` to scale the contour:

```
f3d[t_, u_] := Append[thicknessFunc[u,2]*fdata[t], u]
```

Note that only the `{x,y}` points of the contour are scaled and to make this work, your contour points need to lie around the zero point `{0,0}` as in your example. That's it, the rest is only plotting

```
ParametricPlot3D[f3d[t, u], {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 4}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 10]}, Axes -> None, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Would there been any way to have "direct edges" in the function `thicknessFunc`? When looking at the answer I was somehow expected `thicknessFunc[u, 4]` to give a rectangular shape.. :)

Comment: @Öskå In its current form not. `body` really gives the length of the constant middle part and the round corners are always added. You have to change `thicknessFunc` to make the shape more rectangular, but I'm not sure how `ParametricPlot3D` will handle such an abrupt jumpg.

Comment: This works brilliantly, except for one thing that I cannot figure out: the cross-section for my own data is scaled to half the size in the extruded shape?! If I put a factor 2 inside the append (like `Append[2*thicknessFunc[u,2]*fdata[t], u]`) then it is fixed, but I really don't understand. I will add this to my question in an edit

Comment: @Michiel Can you include the points of your 2d shape in your question? With this, we can work with your data and see what you see. Or if your data is too large, then put the list of points to pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks, but never mind. I already figured out the issue (see my edit in the question). Of course, the error was due to an adaptation that I made to your code, so I've only got myself to blame.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the thorough answer, it really makes for beautiful shapes now!!

Answer (score 3):

How about this.  Generate a list of 2D points:

```
pts = Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/6], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/6]}, {k, 0, 6}];
ListLinePlot[pts]
```

[image]

and we'll use a scaling function to form the caps.

```
Plot[Sqrt[1 - (Abs@z - 1)^2], {z, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
sfunc[pt_] := Module[{z = Last@pt}, Piecewise[{{pt, -1 < Last@pt < 1}}, 
  {{Sqrt[1 - (Abs@z - 1)^2], Sqrt[1 - (Abs@z - 1)^2], 1}*pt}]]
```

[image]

Create the extrusion

```
ext = Partition[Flatten@Table[sfunc[Join[#, {z}]] & /@ pts, {z, -2, 2, 0.05}], 3];
```

and plot it

```
Graphics3D@(Polygon@ext)
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed the route that I explored at first, but it is not entirely what I was looking for, because this remains a body of slices instead of a complete surface.