# Zero-order interpolation not going fully around

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, interpolation

Connected to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/extrude-2d-cross-section-to-3d-shape-with-shrinkfactor), I want to do a zero-order interpolation of a bunch of datapoints which is periodic. The code I use is as follows:

```
dataSource = {{-0.225, 0.250}, {0.000, 0.250}, {0.225, 0.250}, {0.225,
0.250}, {0.296, 0.231}, {0.367, 0.108}, {0.367, 0.107}, {0.354, 
0.048}, {0.341, 0.025}, {0.341, 
0.025}, {0.265, -0.082}, {0.189, -0.190}, {0.189, -0.190}, {0.131, 
-0.238}, {0.072, -0.250}, {0.072, -0.250}, {0.000, -0.250}, {-0.072, 
-0.250}, {-0.072, -0.250}, {-0.131, -0.238}, {-0.189, -0.190}, 
{-0.189, -0.190}, {-0.265, -0.082}, {-0.341, 0.025}, {-0.341, 
0.025}, {-0.354, 0.048}, {-0.367, 0.107}, {-0.367, 0.107}, {-0.296,
0.231}, {-0.225, 0.250}}

With[{ip = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True] & /@ Transpose[dataSource]}, 
fdata[t_] := Through[ip[t]]]

ParametricPlot[fdata[t], {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

What I don't understand is why it doesn't draw the full contour? If I use `InterpolationOrder -> 1` it does work, but I don't want to do that for other reasons. **Can someone explain what is the problem that does not allow a periodic interpolation?**

**For clarification, the reason I don't want to use the first order interpolation** is that it creates visual artifacts later on in the process:

[image]

As you can see the zero order extruded shape is nice and smooth, but with the gap from the cross-section. The first order extruded shape does not have this gap, but has a strange visual artifact.

The dataset for this last part is:

```
dataSource={{-0.225,0.250},{-0.192,0.250},{-0.160,0.250},{-0.128,0.250},{-0.096,0.250},{-0.064,0.250},{-0.032,0.250},{0.000,0.250},{0.032,0.250},{0.064,0.250},{0.096,0.250},{0.128,0.250},{0.160,0.250},{0.192,0.250},{0.225,0.250},{0.225,0.250},{0.230,0.250},{0.236,0.250},{0.242,0.249},{0.248,0.248},{0.254,0.247},{0.260,0.245},{0.266,0.244},{0.272,0.242},{0.278,0.240},{0.284,0.237},{0.290,0.234},{0.296,0.231},{0.302,0.227},{0.308,0.223},{0.314,0.219},{0.320,0.214},{0.326,0.208},{0.331,0.202},{0.337,0.195},{0.343,0.186},{0.349,0.176},{0.355,0.164},{0.361,0.148},{0.367,0.108},{0.367,0.107},{0.366,0.090},{0.365,0.083},{0.364,0.077},{0.363,0.072},{0.362,0.068},{0.361,0.065},{0.359,0.061},{0.358,0.058},{0.357,0.055},{0.356,0.053},{0.355,0.050},{0.354,0.048},{0.353,0.045},{0.352,0.043},{0.351,0.041},{0.350,0.039},{0.349,0.037},{0.347,0.035},{0.346,0.033},{0.345,0.032},{0.344,0.030},{0.343,0.028},{0.342,0.027},{0.341,0.025},{0.341,0.025},{0.330,0.010},{0.319,-0.006},{0.308,-0.021},{0.297,-0.036},{0.287,-0.052},{0.276,-0.067},{0.265,-0.082},{0.254,-0.098},{0.243,-0.113},{0.232,-0.128},{0.221,-0.144},{0.211,-0.159},{0.200,-0.174},{0.189,-0.190},{0.189,-0.190},{0.184,-0.196},{0.179,-0.202},{0.174,-0.207},{0.169,-0.212},{0.165,-0.216},{0.160,-0.220},{0.155,-0.224},{0.150,-0.227},{0.145,-0.230},{0.140,-0.233},{0.136,-0.235},{0.131,-0.238},{0.126,-0.240},{0.121,-0.242},{0.116,-0.243},{0.111,-0.245},{0.106,-0.246},{0.102,-0.247},{0.097,-0.248},{0.092,-0.249},{0.087,-0.249},{0.082,-0.250},{0.077,-0.250},{0.072,-0.250},{0.072,-0.250},{0.062,-0.250},{0.052,-0.250},{0.041,-0.250},{0.031,-0.250},{0.021,-0.250},{0.010,-0.250},{0.000,-0.250},{-0.010,-0.250},{-0.021,-0.250},{-0.031,-0.250},{-0.041,-0.250},{-0.052,-0.250},{-0.062,-0.250},{-0.072,-0.250},{-0.072,-0.250},{-0.077,-0.250},{-0.082,-0.250},{-0.087,-0.249},{-0.092,-0.249},{-0.097,-0.248},{-0.102,-0.247},{-0.106,-0.246},{-0.111,-0.245},{-0.116,-0.243},{-0.121,-0.242},{-0.126,-0.240},{-0.131,-0.238},{-0.136,-0.235},{-0.140,-0.233},{-0.145,-0.230},{-0.150,-0.227},{-0.155,-0.224},{-0.160,-0.220},{-0.165,-0.216},{-0.169,-0.212},{-0.174,-0.207},{-0.179,-0.202},{-0.184,-0.196},{-0.189,-0.190},{-0.189,-0.190},{-0.200,-0.174},{-0.211,-0.159},{-0.221,-0.144},{-0.232,-0.128},{-0.243,-0.113},{-0.254,-0.098},{-0.265,-0.082},{-0.276,-0.067},{-0.287,-0.052},{-0.297,-0.036},{-0.308,-0.021},{-0.319,-0.006},{-0.330,0.010},{-0.341,0.025},{-0.341,0.025},{-0.342,0.027},{-0.343,0.028},{-0.344,0.030},{-0.345,0.032},{-0.346,0.033},{-0.347,0.035},{-0.349,0.037},{-0.350,0.039},{-0.351,0.041},{-0.352,0.043},{-0.353,0.045},{-0.354,0.048},{-0.355,0.050},{-0.356,0.053},{-0.357,0.055},{-0.358,0.058},{-0.359,0.061},{-0.361,0.065},{-0.362,0.068},{-0.363,0.072},{-0.364,0.077},{-0.365,0.083},{-0.366,0.090},{-0.367,0.107},{-0.367,0.107},{-0.361,0.148},{-0.355,0.164},{-0.349,0.176},{-0.343,0.186},{-0.337,0.195},{-0.331,0.202},{-0.326,0.208},{-0.320,0.214},{-0.314,0.219},{-0.308,0.223},{-0.302,0.227},{-0.296,0.231},{-0.290,0.234},{-0.284,0.237},{-0.278,0.240},{-0.272,0.242},{-0.266,0.244},{-0.260,0.245},{-0.254,0.247},{-0.248,0.248},{-0.242,0.249},{-0.236,0.250},{-0.230,0.250},{-0.225,0.250}};
```

Comment: i dont understand why you get a plot at all. a zero order interpolation of 2d data it seems should give you discrete points (?).  what do you get if you plot beyond the range 0-1?

Comment: on furthe thought i suspect if you `Plot[ftdata[t][[1]],{t,0,1}]` this will begin to make sense.

Comment: Why not use `ListLinePlot[dataSource]`? This gives the same plot you seem to want. After all, a zero-order interpolation means connecting the points with straight lines, and this is what ListLinePLot is designed for.

Comment: sorry i cant actually run things here. my thought is the interpolation function is correct and you are seeing an  artifact of the way plot handles discontinuous functions

Comment: doesn't extending the plot range to eg 1.001 close it?  I'm still at a loss as to why you dont just use the first order interpolation.

Comment: @Michiel it did for me ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FQDCZ.png))

Comment: I think you ought to keep first-order interpolation and ask a question about how to get rid of the visual artifacts.

Comment: I just see one dataset of length 30 posted in your answer. Where can I find the longer dataset you mentioned?

Comment: Are you sure the gap that you get for the new dataSource is from [order 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lhOI1.png)? It seems like it may actually come from your [order 0](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xBZH.png). Even so, [changing your t to 1.001](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DZBL2.png) solves the problem.

Comment: I tried your method with `t = 1.001` and did not see any discontinuities in the graph ([for](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Ko2.png) [both](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFh5.png) `dataSource`s). My last comment was referring to you mentioning in your question that order 1 produces artifact, while in fact it doesn't (order 0 does). I suggest just using order 1 from now on.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Michiel and @seismatica I got an automatic flag for excessive comments.  Please consider summarizing any important points and including them in the question, or an answer, then deleting some comments.

Comment: @george2079 You too (see above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though OP's problem is resolved in the question's comments, I hope to provide an explanation of why the gap appears in the parametric plot. Namely, I think `InterpolationOrder -> 0` (specifically as an option to `ListInterpolation`*) is the culprit, as it starts with a jump/step from the first data point to the second data point.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a result, the interpolating function actually starts with the **second** point and ends with the last point, which means that this parametric plot does not start and end with the same point--hence the gap--*even if* the first and last points of the datset are identical. Try changing the second point of this dataset to match the last point (just use my code below) and you will see the gap disappear. Also observe in my plots that fx0 does not start and end at the same point (fy0 does, but only by coincidence).

This is in contrast to `InterpolationOrder -> 1`, whose interpolating function actually starts with the first point (and not second like the zero-order one does). Therefore, its parametric plot indeed closes whenever the first and last point of the dataset are the same (they do in this case).

```
dataSource = {{-0.225, 0.250}, {0.000, 0.250}, {0.225, 0.250}, {0.225,
     0.250}, {0.296, 0.231}, {0.367, 0.108}, {0.367, 0.107}, {0.354, 
    0.048}, {0.341, 0.025}, {0.341, 
    0.025}, {0.265, -0.082}, {0.189, -0.190}, {0.189, -0.190}, \
{0.131, -0.238}, {0.072, -0.250}, {0.072, -0.250}, {0.000, -0.250}, \
{-0.072, -0.250}, {-0.072, -0.250}, {-0.131, -0.238}, {-0.189, \
-0.190}, {-0.189, -0.190}, {-0.265, -0.082}, {-0.341, 0.025}, {-0.341,
     0.025}, {-0.354, 0.048}, {-0.367, 0.107}, {-0.367, 
    0.107}, {-0.296, 0.231}, {-0.225, 0.250}};

{fx0, fy0} = 
  ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     PeriodicInterpolation -> True] & /@ Transpose[dataSource];
{fx1, fy1} = 
  ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
     PeriodicInterpolation -> True] & /@ Transpose[dataSource];

{{fx0[#], fy0[#]} & /@ {0, 1}, {fx1[#], fy1[#]} & /@ {0, 1}} // 
 TableForm[#, 
   TableHeadings -> {{"InterpolationOrder \[Rule] 0", 
      "InterpolationOrder \[Rule] 1"}, {"First plot point", 
      "Last plot point"}, {"x", "y"}}] &

Plot[{fx0[t], fx1[t], fy0[t], fy1[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Red, Opacity[0.5]}, Blue, {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"fx0", "fx1", "fy0", "fy1"}]

ParametricPlot[#, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {{0, 1}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[5]]] & /@ {{fx0[t], 
    fy0[t]}, {fx1[t], fy1[t]}} // 
 Grid[{{"InterpolationOrder \[Rule] 0", 
     "InterpolationOrder \[Rule] 1"}, #}, Frame -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> *

It seems that `InterpolationOrder -> 0` behaves this way for `ListInterpolation` (and `Interpolation`). It doesn't seem to behave this way as an option for `ListLinePlot` in the [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0puyxkh7ci-glqey3) for `InterpolationOrder`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Terrific summary of the problem and our discussion in the comments. Thanks again

Comment: good catch noting the inconsistency in the `ListLinePlot` and `ListInterpolation` implementations.  Of course both strictly follow what the docs say: "yields a collection of flat regions, with steps at each data point "

Answer (score 3):

End running the problem we can readily construct our own "zero order" interpolation function:

```
 myzero[t_] := (#[[1 + (Ceiling[Mod[t, 1]  (Length@# - 1) ] )]]) &@ dataSource
```

which gives your desired plot:

```
 ParametricPlot[myzero[t], {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> same closed figure as your `InterpolationOrder-> 1` result

note the function `myzero` is exactly the same as your `fdata` except that it returns the first point when the argument is exactly zero.

You might see if this fixes your extrusion result, though I concur with the comment that you should try to figure out whats wrong with the first order case.

Answer (score 2):

A similar thing happens in this question: [How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/how-can-the-behavior-of-interpolationorder-0-be-controlled)

As [@seismatica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14587/seismatica) has pointed out, `ListInterpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0][0]` yields `data[[2]]`, not `data[[1]]` as might be expected.  Thus the range of the interpolating function, over the fundamental domain does not include the first point in `data`.  This holds even if `PeriodicInterpolation -> True` is set -- unless one goes beyond the domain.  For instance the following produce closed curves:

```
ParametricPlot[fdata[t], {t, 0 - $MachineEpsilon, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
ParametricPlot[fdata[t], {t, 0, 1 + $MachineEpsilon}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

A more straightforward way to get a closed curve is

```
ParametricPlot[fdata[Mod[t, 1]], {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]