# Extruding a weird 2D shape to make a prismatic 3D shape

Tags: graphics3d

I have the outline of a 2D shape defined by a periodic radius `R[θ]`. I would like to extrude this linearly to a prismatic 3D object that has my cross-sectional shape. I could extrude the outline, as shown below, but I need it to be filled, or at least capped. It would have been nice if I could use the `Tube` `Graphics3D` option and specify the radius as a function of theta.
There must be a simple way to do this.  Any suggestions ?

```
shape = PolarPlot[R[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> False,
     PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.02]}]

shape3d = ParametricPlot3D[{R6[θ] Cos[θ], R6[θ] Sin[θ], z}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {z, -2, 5}, 
     Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: my shape]

Comment: See if this is what you would like: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/extrude-2d-cross-section-to-3d-shape-with-shrinkfactor

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Michael Seifert's answer is the easiest for curves that can be plotted parametrically, but there is a slightly more general method that can be used to construct an extrusion of any curve that can be plotted in 2D.

First, note that one can always extract the points from a 2D plotted curve, because *Mathematica* never forgets. For instance, with the curve provided in the question:

```
R[θ_] := (1 + 0.5 Sin[2 θ]);
shape1 = PolarPlot[R[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thickness[0.02]}
 ];
```

the points are located via

```
points = (Flatten @ shape1[[1]])[[2, 1]]
```

Other information about the curve can be found similarly, and using that info and list manipulations, we can use `Polygon`s to construct a surface. Here is an extrusion function that does what is necessary:

```
Options[Extrude] = Join[Options[Graphics3D], {Closed -> True, Capped -> True}];

Extrude[curve_, {zmin_, zmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{info, points, color, tube, caps},
   info = Flatten @ {curve[[1]]};
   points = Select[info, Head[#] === Line &][[1, 1]];
   If[OptionValue[Closed], points = points ~Join~ {points[[1]]}];
   color = Select[info, Head[#] === Directive &];
   If[Length[color] == 0, color = Orange, color = First @ Select[color[[1]], ColorQ]];

   tube = Polygon[
     Partition[
      Flatten[
       Transpose[points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #} & /@ {zmin, zmax}], 1], 3, 1]
    ];

   If[OptionValue[Closed] && OptionValue[Capped],
    caps = Polygon[points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #}] & /@ {zmin, zmax};
    tube = Flatten@{tube, caps},
    tube = {tube}
   ];

   Graphics3D[
    Flatten @ {EdgeForm[None], color, #} & /@ tube,
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]]
   ]
  ];
```

For the case in hand, we get

```
Extrude[shape1, {-2, 5}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: shape1]
[image: ext1]

This is really a lot of work for the same result that Michael's answer gives more easily, but we can use this to close and extrude *any* plotted 2D curve:

```
shape2 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, Axes -> False]
Extrude[shape2, {-2, 5}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: shape2]
[image: ext2]

This will not work with `Graphics` primitives, as they do not provide a list of points that can be extracted (well, it will work with a `Graphics[Line[...]]`). Also, to close a non-closed shape, it simply connects the first and last points, which might not be the behavior always desired. Lastly, note that one can leave the caps off:

```
shape3 = Graphics[
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 0}}]]
Extrude[shape3, {-2, 5}, Capped -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: shape3]
[image: ext3]

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You could create parametric plots for the endcaps as well:

```
tube = ParametricPlot3D[{R6[θ] Cos[θ], R6[θ] Sin[θ], z}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {z, -2, 5},
                        Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None]
endcap1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r R6[θ] Cos[θ], r R6[θ] Sin[θ], 5}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 1},
                           Mesh -> False];
endcap2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r R6[θ] Cos[θ], r R6[θ] Sin[θ], -2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 1},
                           Mesh -> False];
Show[tube, endcap1, endcap2]
```

[image: Weird tube with endcaps]

Answer (score 6):

This answer was written to demonstrate that you can use `BSplineSurface[]` to render custom prisms, so that you won't need to carry as many polygons around as the other answers. To wit,

```
(* Lee's method, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(89)90003-1 *)
parametrizeCurve[pts_List, a : (_?NumericQ) : 1/2] := 
    FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^a, Total]] /;
    MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ]

shape1 = First[Cases[Normal[PolarPlot[1 + 0.5 Sin[2 θ], {θ, 0, 2 π},
                                      MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 45]],
                     Line[l_] :> l, ∞]];

tvals = parametrizeCurve[shape1, 1]; (* chord-length parametrization *)
knots = Join[{0, 0}, ArrayPad[tvals, -1], {1, 1}];
{zmin, zmax} = {-1, 2};
prispts = Outer[Append, shape1, {zmin, zmax}, 1];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Polygon[Transpose[prispts]],
            BSplineSurface[prispts,
                           SplineDegree -> 1, SplineKnots -> {knots, {0, 0, 1, 1}}]},
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: custom prism]

Of course, you can omit the `Polygon[]` caps:

[image: capless custom prism]

Comment: I don't have access to [Lee's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(89)90003-1).  Could you explain a bit of how that method works in your own words?

Comment: Certainly; I discussed centripetal parametrization [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898), and Shutao gave explicit formulae [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40174).

Comment: Thank you.  I apparently have seen and voted for that answer but sadly I have no memory of it.  Thanks for directing me to it again!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `ArrayMesh` to get your curve in 2D, then use `RegionProduct` to extrude in 3D.

```
raw = ImageTake[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCn1v.png"], {1, 250}];
im = Binarize[FillingTransform[ColorNegate[raw]]];

RegionProduct[RegionBoundary[ArrayMesh[ImageData[im]]], Line[{{0.}, {1000.}}]]
```

[image]

## Update

In **Version 11**, we can use [`ImageMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html) to lower the `MeshCellCount`:

```
raw = ImageTake[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCn1v.png"], {1, 250}];
im = FillingTransform[ColorNegate[raw]];

reg = RegionProduct[RegionBoundary[ImageMesh[im]], Line[{{0.}, {1000.}}]]
```

[image]

```
MeshCellCount[reg]
```

> ```
> {128, 192, 64}
> ```