# Strategies for creating 3D text

Tags: graphics3d, generative-art, 3d-printing

I am interested in using *Mathematica* to create 3D text for printing.  I stumbled upon [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6208) which works very well in a slightly modified form:

```
text3D[text_String, mult_] := ListPlot3D[
  ClusteringComponents[
   ImageRotate@ImagePad[ImageReflect[
      ImageCrop@First@
        ColorSeparate@
         Rasterize@
          Graphics[{Text[Style[text, Bold, 60]]}], 
      Left -> Right], 5, White]], Boxed -> False, Mesh -> False, 
  Axes -> False, DataRange -> {{0, mult}, {0, mult}}]
```

It seems to work well, except for one peculiar instance:

```
text3D["Hello",5]
```

[image]

```
text3D["I",5]
```

[image]

```
text3D["I am",5]
```

[image]

Something is unusual about printing just the letter "I", and I can't place my finger on it.  Adding spaces around the I ("    I    ") does not have an effect, but printing ".I." does (although I would like to have the letter I by itself).

There are **two** questions:

1. What is the root problem here, and how can it be solved?
2. What are some other strategies for creating 3D text in an efficient manner?

Comment: Maybe `text3D["I",1]`

Comment: @EvanCarslake  It [doesn't look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH47s.png) the size has a significant effect on the shape of the I.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With a bit more work, we can take a similar approach to J.M.'s answer to build a water tight model with a base.

```
text = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["Hello"], _Text]
```

[image]

```
elongate[{a_, b_}] := With[{d = 0.05 (b - a)}, {a - d, b + d}]

full = DiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle @@ Transpose[elongate /@ RegionBounds[text]]]
```

[image]

```
diff = RegionDifference[full, text]
```

[image]

```
etext = RegionProduct[RegionBoundary[text], Line[{{0.}, {2.}}]]
```

[image]

```
final = DiscretizeGraphics @ Show[
  etext,
  RegionProduct[text, Point[{2.}]],
  RegionProduct[diff, Point[{0.}]],
  RegionProduct[full, Point[{-1.}]],
  RegionProduct[RegionBoundary[full], Line[{{-1.}, {0.}}]]
]
```

[image]

The only defects here are misoriented faces (which can be fixed with `RepairMesh`), but this is indeed a water tight model:

```
FindMeshDefects[final]
```

[image]

Comment: An interesting approach.  I'm behind the times on my Mathematica versions and look forward to some of the new-to-v11 routines.

Comment: Building up the extruded text worked for my application and it doesn't take forever on a RPi, so this is the "right" answer for my question.  However, there's a bunch of useful info in the other answers provided.

Answer (score 26):

> What are some other strategies for creating 3D text in an efficient manner?

Here's one way, using `MeshRegion[]` functionality:

```
RegionProduct[DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style["Hello", Bold, FontFamily -> "Calibri"]],
                                 _Text, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],
              MeshRegion[{{0}, {4}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]
```

[image: 3D "Hello"]

```
RegionProduct[DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style["I", FontFamily -> "Source Code Pro"]], _Text, 
                                 MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],
              MeshRegion[{{0}, {2}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]
```

[image: 3D "I"]

Comment: So "extrude" is `RegionProduct`!  Excellent!  I was looking for this the other day.

Comment: More specifically, the `RegionProduct` with a line segment.

Comment: @Szabolcs I spent much of my searching time looking for "mathematica text extrusion".  Your comment makes me think I should change the title of this question.

Comment: I like the speed and simplicity of this answer.  The problem I'm having is that it does not seem to make manifold/watertight objects.  I'm still debugging, and hoping it's some type of error with overlapping vertices that can be resolved.

Comment: Yeah, that will take a bit more work, @bob. Chip's solution looks fine, but let me think of a way to modify mine...

Answer (score 16):

*I'm posting a second answer because this method is completely different from my first answer.*

Another way to make 3D printable text is with `ImageMesh`:

```
hello = Rasterize[Graphics[{Text[Style["Hello", Bold, 60]]}], "Image"];
text = ColorNegate[ImagePad[ImageCrop[hello], 6, White]];

stack = Image3D @ Join[
  ConstantArray[text, 20],
  ConstantArray[ColorConvert[ConstantImage[1, ImageDimensions[text]], "RGB"], 5]
];

ImageMesh[stack, Method -> "DualMarchingCubes"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the solution:
DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style["I", FontFamily -> "Source Code Pro"]], _Text]
worked earlier on e.g. v11.3, but on v13.0 rather than creating a mesh of the formatted string 'I' it now creates one of the whole style expression instead:
'Style["I", FontFamily -> "Source Code Pro"]'

Comment: This seems like a comment rather than an answer to the orriginal question.

Comment: True @bbgodfrey, as a new contributor, I don't think Martin could post comments. The behavior sounds like a bug; I don't have v13 installed as of yet to confirm.