# How to plot 3D curly brace

Tags: graphics

How do I plot a 3D curly brace that is scalable, but the curly parts remain intact, and can be altered where the labeling tip points to?

update:

I have tried insetting the string `{` into my graphics, and it looks more professional than the `BSplineCurve` I previously used, but still lacks adjustability.

```
Inset[
 First@ImportString@
   ExportString[
    Style["{", RGBColor[0.25, 0.25, 0.25], FontSize -> 12, 
     FontFamily -> "Cambria Math"], "PDF"],
 {0.12, 0, 1/2 + 0.045}, Center, 45]
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems like a straightforward but very tedious task. What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Look at previous attempts, for example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4374/scale-insetted-characters-to-plot

Comment: @Szabolcs, I've been using `BSplineCurve` to make the braces and adjust it by `GeometricTransformation`. It looks somewhat unprofessional though.

Comment: @user18792, OK I'll take a look.

Comment: What do you mean by 3D? Something like in this question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128412/strategies-for-creating-3d-text

Comment: @ChipHurst, 3D as in 3 dimensions, like in `Graphics3D` or `Plot3D`

Comment: @L.Quen Sure, but it's still not clear to me what you want. Do you want a floating glyph in 3D, or something more along the lines of the link I pasted above, or something completely different?

Comment: @ChipHurst, Floating glyph i guess that denotes a length in 3d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to get most of what you want, stolen from Szabolcs [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/38205):

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["{", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text];
polyBase = FirstCase[Normal@Show[reg], _Polygon, None, Infinity];
poly = Polygon[
   Prepend[#, ConstantArray[0, Length[#[[1]]]]] &@
     Map[Rescale, Transpose@polyBase[[1]]] // Transpose
   ];
```

That gives you a polygon, which you can just mess with using [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html).

Here's the base Polygon:

```
poly // Graphics3D
```

[image: base p]

Note that you can change it with transformations:

```
GeometricTransformation[poly, 
  ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 3}]] // Graphics3D
```

[image: scaled p]

And since it has been [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html)-d that now spans the z range [0, 3]. See also [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html) and [`TranslationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TranslationTransform.html).

Comment: pretty much what I want haha.