# Issue related to BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics

Tags: graphics, bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 11.3, fixed in 12.3 (and possibly as early as 12.1)**

---

I was revisiting an [earlier problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128424/7167) of mine related to designing 3D objects with extruded text for 3D printing.  The accepted answer no longer works in V11.3 if a certain subset of letters are used.  For example, while this works as expected:

```
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text[#], _Text] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "C"]
```

a slight modification results in failure to discretize the graphics.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text[# <> #], _Text] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "C"]
```

[image]

Working through various pairs of letters, it appears as if `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` fails if neither of the letters contains an annulus (correct math term?).  So "AA" and "AC" will both work, but with "CE" and "CD", only the latter text will be rendered properly.

[image]

Of the single letter options, only lower case "i" and lower case "j" fail, which somehow makes sense because in these two cases, there exists two regions, neither of which have an annulus.

All of these problems are not present in the 11.2 version on the Raspberry Pi.

[image]

While this is primarily a public service announcement, I am looking for ***suggestions for workarounds to creating letter-shaped regions***.  My application requires that it work on both traditional desktop platforms as well as the Raspberry Pi, so timing does become a concern.

Comment: I observe the same with version 11.3 on Windows 7 x64. Tagging as a bug.

Comment: With version 12.3.1 I do not reproduce the bug.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for checking, I'm still on 12.1 with my home computer and I don't see the problem there either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is worth reporting this issue to support.

To see what might be going on, try [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics) instead:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Text["CC"], _Text]
```

[image]

You'll notice that the output appears to be a non-simple polygon, and I think this is why [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics) fails to produce a region. To workaround this issue, you can insert a small space between the letters:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["C\[VeryThinSpace]C"], _Text]
```

[image]

**Update**

The OP in a comment mentioned that my workaround doesn't help for letters that have disconnected pieces, e.g., "i".

Another possibility for creating a region from letters is to use an [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString)/[`ExportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString) round trip to the "PDF" format, which creates a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object, and then discretize the resulting [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object. For example:

```
g = First @ ImportString @ ExportString[Style["Ci", 100], "PDF"]
```

[image]

The output is a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object:

```
g //Head
```

> Graphics

Use [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion) on this graphics object:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[g, MaxCellMeasure->Infinity]
```

[image]

Comment: I had picked up on the same issue with `DiscretizeGraphics`; your workaround is very nice.

Comment: The `\[VeryThinSpace]` solution does not work with lower case i and j since spaces cannot be added below the dots (obviously).

Comment: @bobthechemist I've updated my answer with another method that hopefully proves useful.

Comment: PDF's are now imported by default as Images instead of Graphics. Therefore, this change is needed:  `ImportString[ExportString[Style["Ci", 100], "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}]`