# Exporting spline to dxf

Tags: export

I created a spline to be exported to the DXf extension:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {5, 1}};
g = Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts]}]
Export["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\Arquivo.dxf", g]
```

I have applications to open the generated file, but my system informs me that it cannot be opened by these applications because it contains a flaw. Is there a parameter that needs to be inserted in my code?

Comment: Does it work for you in 3D? `pts = Append[0] /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {5, 1}};
    g = Graphics3D[{BezierCurve[pts]}];
    Export["model.dxf", g];`

Comment: @ChipHurst The problem effectively disappears in 3D

Comment: In 2D, There is a error message : "Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{10,20,30},{0.,0.}} cannot be transposed."

Comment: ... and there is this kind of thing in the DXF file : "List(List(10,20,30),List(0.,0.))"

Comment: I will try to do in 3d

Comment: I think this method could be adopted (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128412/strategies-for-creating-3d-text), I started down that path for FilledCurve to .dxf, but never finished. The idea is to extrude the curve by epsilon in the out of plane direction.