# Numbers in love - can we reproduce Giacomo Balla's extruded digits?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, generative-art

[Giacomo Balla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Balla) (1871 - 1958) was an Italian painter best known as a key proponent of [Futurism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurism). In his paintings, he depicted light, movement and speed. Balla's oil painting "Numeri innamorati" (Numbers in love) was created in 1920. The original size of the work is 76,5 x 54 cm.

[image]

The best starting point I found was J.M.'s answer to this question:

[Strategies for creating 3D text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128412/strategies-for-creating-3d-text)

```
RegionProduct[DiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["8", FontFamily -> "Alegreya SC"]], _Text, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],
 MeshRegion[{{0}, {4}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]
```

[image]

Being unfamiliar with `MeshRegions` and related functions, I don't know how to proceed from here. I don't want to reproduce the painting, but only extrude the numbers as shown:

- Black front
- Grayish, shadowy, diagonal extrusions
- An appropriate font (the upper parts of `3` and `5` must be flat, not curved)

Thank you in advance for your answers and hints.

Comment: Seems like other than lighting, one can also modify glow and specularity in mathematica as shown in the links that follow https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlTheResponseOfA3DSurfaceToLighting.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphicsAndSound.html#20392

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- `Mono` fonts seems flat.
- We use `RegionProduct` with `Point` and `Line` and `RegionBoundary`.

```
fonts = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["8543", 
     FontFamily -> "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"]], _Text];
above = RegionProduct[fonts, Point[{10.}]];
below = RegionProduct[fonts, Point[{0.}]];
body = RegionProduct[RegionBoundary@fonts, Line[{{0.}, {10.}}]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Black, above, Red, below, FaceForm[White], 
  body}, ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 10}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Accent"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, cvgmt, such a nice and short (!) solution

Comment: In my Windows 11 system, I only found `"Harlow Solid Italic"` is flat. `fonts = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["8543", FontFamily -> "Harlow Solid Italic", 
    FontSlant -> Plain]], _Text]`