# How to define a 3D region delimited by a prism with base given by the vertices of a polygon?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, regions, polygons

I have an arbitrary polygon, not necessarily convex, described by the coordinates of its vertices. I need to obtain the 3D Region `R` delimited by a prism with base defined by the polygon and a given height `h` (such as I can for example `RegionPlot3D[R]`).
Polygon example

```
Graphics[
    Line[{{2, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-1.5, 1}, {-1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5},{1.5, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}}]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is closely related to:

[How to extrude a 3D image from a binary 2D image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6206/5478)

and [one of answers (J.M.)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128415/5478) does exactly that:

```
poly = Polygon[{{2, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-1.5, 1}, {-1.5, 
    0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}}];

With[{h = 2}, 
  region = RegionProduct[
      poly, MeshRegion[{{0}, {h}}, Line[{1, 2}]]
  ]
] // Show[#, Axes -> True] &
```

[image]

```
Volume@region
```

> ```
> 5.
> ```