# Combining MeshRegions of generated 3D shapes and RandomPolygons

Tags: graphics, mesh, polygons, regions

I am interested in generating 3D a joint `BoundaryMeshRegion` or a `MeshRegion` from different shapes and polygons. This works for `RandomPolygon`:

i):

```
r1 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Graphics[RandomPolygon[15, 
    DataRange -> {{0.02, 0.08}, {-0.02, 0.04}}]]];
r2 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Graphics[RandomPolygon[12, 
    DataRange -> {{0.00, 0.03}, {-0.02, 0.03}}]]]
bnd1 = RegionProduct[r1, MeshRegion[{{0.01}, {0.05}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
bnd2 = RegionProduct[r2, MeshRegion[{{0}, {0.02}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
un1 = RegionUnion[bnd1, bnd2];
Show[un1, Boxed->True, Axes->True]
```

[image: Unified Region of two 3D generations of RandomPolygon]

I also wanted to include the shape of a country and combine it with a random polygon or another country shape a similar manner, which is possible as long as they are combined in 2D-state:

ii):

```
r3 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[CountryData["Spain", "Shape"], 
  ImageSize -> Medium, Axes -> True]
r4 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Graphics[RandomPolygon[15, 
    DataRange -> {{0.05, 0.3}, {-0.08, 0.08}}]]];
bnd3 = RegionUnion[r3, r4];
un2 = RegionProduct[bnd3, MeshRegion[{{0}, {0.02}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
Show[un2, Boxed->True, Axes->True]
```

[image: Unified Region of two 3D generations of RandomPolygon and a countriyshape respectively]

However, as soon as one tries to combine a generated 3D shape of a country with a generated 3D shape of the Polygon, the following output results:

iii):

```
bnd31 = RegionProduct[r3, MeshRegion[{{0.0}, {0.02}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
r5 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Graphics[RandomPolygon[8, 
    DataRange -> {{0.03, 0.12}, {-0.06, 0.06}}]]];
bnd32 = RegionProduct[r5, MeshRegion[{{0.015}, {0.03}}, Line[{1, 2}]]];
RegionUnion[bnd31, bnd32];
```

[image: Output of iii)]

In some cases Mathematica crashes.

How would I solve this issue? My aim is to combine a 3D shape of a country with a 3D shape of `RandomPolygon`, so that both shapes have different heights with respect to each other. The volumes need to be connected with each other though (similarly to ii)), as I would like to apply a `RegionMemberFunction` in a later step.

The code for the 3D-shape generation was found here:
[How to extrude a 3D image from a binary 2D image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6206/how-to-extrude-a-3d-image-from-a-binary-2d-image/6208#6208)

I am running on Mathematica 12.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Would you please give also the definition of `bnd3`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  ```bnd3 = RegionUnion[r3, r4];``` ; I have spotted the mistake you are reffering to in i), meant to be: ```un1 = RegionUnion[bnd1, bnd2];``` instead ```un1 = RegionUnion[bnd2, bnd3];```

Comment: Jeff, did you know that can edit your post? =)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Just realized and did that. Sorry for the confusion. :D

Comment: Oh my, that's a nasty problem. You should definitely tell support about it. There is a chance that this will get fixed in the next four to five years... ;) I think the problem is that `bnd32` is a nonconnected `BoundaryMeshRegion` and the algorithm `RegionUnion` of `BoundaryMeshRegion`s is somehow dependend on the hidden that each region is connected. Huge mess if you ask me. Unfortunately, I have no idea at the moment how to bypass this. Btw. the Boolean region tools in _Mathematica_ are buggy also in many other ways. It is really frustrating.