# Distances between points in periodic cube

Tags: numerics, algebraic-manipulation, computational-geometry

**Question**

> How can one implement more efficiently/elegantly/memory savvily the following function which returns a matrix of all Euclidian distances between points in 3D within a cube of width `size`, while accounting for the periodicity of the cube?

I have tried

```
Clear[PeriodicDistance];
PeriodicDistance[x_, size_: 1] := Module[{xm, ym, zm},
xm = {Outer[EuclideanDistance, x[[;; , 1]], x[[;; , 1]]], 
size - Outer[EuclideanDistance, x[[;; , 1]], x[[;; , 1]]]};
xm = Map[Min[Abs[#]] &, Transpose[xm, {3, 1, 2}], {2}];
ym = {Outer[EuclideanDistance, x[[;; , 2]], x[[;; , 2]]], 
size - Outer[EuclideanDistance, x[[;; , 2]], x[[;; , 2]]]};
ym = Map[Min[Abs[#]] &, Transpose[ym, {3, 1, 2}], {2}];
zm = {Outer[EuclideanDistance, x[[;; , 3]], x[[;; , 3]]], 
size - Outer[EuclideanDistance, x[[;; , 3]], x[[;; , 3]]]};
zm = Map[Min[Abs[#]] &, Transpose[zm, {3, 1, 2}], {2}];
Sqrt[xm^2 + ym^2 + zm^2]
]
```

As a side question, is it possible to carry out such computation within mathematica using e.g. octree so that it could be scaled up to millions on points?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How can it be less than O(n^2) in memory or speed? That's the information-theoretic lower bound.

Comment: Well I am not asking for the impossible ;-). Are you implying the code I wrote is already at the theoretical lower bound?

Comment: "Millions of points" would produce a matrix with *tens of trillions* of (nonzero) entries.  I don't see scaling up to that in *Mathematica* any time soon :-).

Comment: @chris Hi Chris, great question and very instructive answers. Quick question about a slight extension, how could we e.g. extend Heike's method to non-cubic boxes? (say a cubic box where for instance one dimension is elongated.)

Comment: @user929304 it seems you just need to replace Norm by something anisotropic ? As in `Norm1 := Sqrt[3] Norm[#/{1, 2}] &` ?? I have not checked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `x` is a list of points between which you want to calculate the distance. If so, then I think your code can be condensed to something like

```
PeriodicDistance[x_, size_: 1] := Outer[Norm@Mod[#2 - #1, size, -size/2] &, x, x, 1]
```

**Edit**

A faster version of the code above is something like

```
PeriodicDistance3[x_, size_: 1] := 
   Map[Norm, Mod[Outer[Subtract, x, x, 1], size, -size/2], {-2}]
```

On my system this is about as efficient as the code in the original question, whereas the previous version is a factor 2 to 3 slower.

Comment: I sort of knew someone would come with something shorter! Impressive. I didn't realize Mod could take two arguments. The beauty of your solution is that it works in any dimensions as well.

Comment: It's shorter, but it seems to be slower as well. For 200 points it's three times as slow as the original code. I'll see if I can speed things up.

Comment: @Heike The main source of inefficiency is that `Outer` is unable to utilize `Listability` of built-in functions. In a very similar situation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/639#639), I used a different method utilizing that. Unfortunately, `Norm` also suffers from that drawback, which is why I did not use it in that answer.

Answer (score 10):

Very late to the party, but I'll show a method that's faster than anything posted so far and will be hard to beat.

First let's define our `PeriodicDistance`:

```
PeriodicDistance = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}, {size, _Real}}, 
   Sqrt@Total[((x - y) - size*Round[(x - y)/size])^2], 
   CompilationTarget :> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Now our distance matrix:

```
PeriodicDistanceMatrix[dat_?MatrixQ, size_Real:1.0] := 
 With[{tr = Transpose[dat]}, Map[PeriodicDistance[dat[[#]], tr, size] &, Range@Length@dat]]
```

Some Timings:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {2000, 3}];

(* This answer *)

PeriodicDistanceMatrix[data]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* 0.265632 *)

(* Heike's faster version *)

PeriodicDistanceB[data]; //AbsoluteTiming

(* 2.599099 *)

(* J.M.'s answer *)

PeriodicDistance[data]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* 6.246279 *)

(* O.P.'s version *)

PeriodicDistance2[data]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* 10.026386 *)
```

And yes, all the outputs are identical.

**Edit**

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"] (* for v10 *)

BenchmarkPlot[{RunnyKine, Heike, JM}, RandomReal[1, {#, 3}] &, 2^Range[6, 14]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! will look at it after flying to canada :-)

Comment: @chris, You're Welcome and fly safe :). I didn't think anyone was going to look at this since it's been almost 2 years since you posed this question.

Comment: I know this is slightly unrelated, because the OP asked for distances on a periodic cube, but how could you implement your method for a periodic rectangle? As in, one side goes from [0,Pi] and the other [0, 2Pi]

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do it than this?


`PeriodicDistance[v1_, v2_, bound_] := 
 Norm[bound[[#]]/2 - Abs[bound[[#]]/2 - Abs[v1[[#]] - v2[[#]]]] & /@ {1, 2}]`

Comment: @Jesse, do you want it `Compile`d like in my answer?

Comment: @RunnyKine I was more looking for a sexier way to access the arguments than using [[#]] and mapping to {1,2}.

Answer (score 9):

You want something like

```
PeriodicDistance[pts_, size_: 1] := 
 Outer[EuclideanDistance, size*FractionalPart[pts/size], 
  size*FractionalPart[pts/size], 1]
```

But what you did is a bit different in terms of how you wrap things periodically. If it is really as you intended, replace size everywhere by 2*size.

```
PeriodicDistanceB[pts_, size_: 1] := 
 Outer[EuclideanDistance, 2*size*FractionalPart[pts/(2*size)], 
  2*size*FractionalPart[pts/(2*size)], 1]
```

Comment: It seems (?) neither give the answer I want: e.g. `PeriodicDistanceB[{{0.1, 0, 0}, {0.9, 0, 0}}]` should return `{{0., 0.2}, {0.2, 0.}}` not `{{0., 0.8}, {0.8, 0.}}`

Comment: Ah. I see the issue. Roughly, you are using the closest distance possible, allowing for taking points to be in neighboring cubes rather than the same one if that happens to make them closer. At this point I'd say use one of the other proposed methods, assuming they do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I've had to do this operation once when I was doing research on Voronoi diagrams. Heike's method is nice. Here is one possible alternative, making use of a fold-over technique to account for periodicity:

```
cPerDist = Compile[{{v1, _Real, 1}, {v2, _Real, 1}, {size, _Real}}, 
  Norm[size/2 - Abs[size/2 - Abs[v1 - v2]]]];

PeriodicDistance[x_?MatrixQ, size_:1] := Outer[cPerDist[#1, #2, size] &, x, x, 1]
```

(You might want to look at a plot of the function $\frac12-\left|\frac12-\left|x\right|\right|$ to get an idea of how the fold-over works.)

Here, we generate and use a compiled function, since this will seem to be used many times on inexact numbers. If you need exact expressions for the lengths, it should be straightforward to write an uncompiled version of `cPerDist`.

Try it out:

```
PeriodicDistance[{{0.1, 0, 0}, {0.9, 0, 0}}]
{{0., 0.2}, {0.2, 0.}}

pts = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; RandomReal[1, {12, 3}]];

PeriodicDistance[pts]
{{0.,0.369061,0.557349,0.273739,0.580937,0.607056,0.630916,0.414241,0.149751,0.214448,0.577028,0.467806},
{0.369061,0.,0.431869,0.636656,0.611335,0.628004,0.641477,0.584125,0.465563,0.34617,0.454007,0.574909},
{0.557349,0.431869,0.,0.653288,0.526924,0.323731,0.230079,0.450194,0.538027,0.589348,0.581119,0.669271},
{0.273739,0.636656,0.653288,0.,0.521814,0.433284,0.539068,0.278055,0.201587,0.392315,0.607604,0.52001},
{0.580937,0.611335,0.526924,0.521814,0.,0.333371,0.527569,0.529642,0.484959,0.691898,0.237093,0.474143},
{0.607056,0.628004,0.323731,0.433284,0.333371,0.,0.308742,0.343472,0.590752,0.69726,0.468426,0.596956},
{0.630916,0.641477,0.230079,0.539068,0.527569,0.308742,0.,0.486608,0.564332,0.543762,0.589842,0.62605},
{0.414241,0.584125,0.450194,0.278055,0.529642,0.343472,0.486608,0.,0.396313,0.377811,0.538572,0.380586},
{0.149751,0.465563,0.538027,0.201587,0.484959,0.590752,0.564332,0.396313,0.,0.307534,0.602186,0.56417},
{0.214448,0.34617,0.589348,0.392315,0.691898,0.69726,0.543762,0.377811,0.307534,0.,0.600932,0.352568},
{0.577028,0.454007,0.581119,0.607604,0.237093,0.468426,0.589842,0.538572,0.602186,0.600932,0.,0.276919},
{0.467806,0.574909,0.669271,0.52001,0.474143,0.596956,0.62605,0.380586,0.56417,0.352568,0.276919,0.}}
```

Some limited tests I did indicate that the method is at least as fast as Heike's.

Comment: Thanks. For 2000 3D points I get `PeriodicDistance[pts]; // Timing  {9.88636,Null}` whereas Heike's code yields `PeriodicDistance3[pts]; // Timing
{5.40553,Null}` Did you do 3D Voronoi Triangulation in mathematica?

Comment: Hmm, they took about the same length of time (give or take a hundredths of a second) on my box. Oh well. I was looking at both two and three dimensions, so I wrote my routines to work for arbitrary dimensions.