# Order items by closest to the previous

Tags: graphics, recursion

I have a list of 2D points (a table, imagine the data of a parametric plot shuffled)

I would like to join the points with a line that starts from one of them and always goes to the closest one.

I tried therefore to sort the points doing the following:

- take out the first element,
- search the closest in the remaining list
- bring it to the front
- recurse

so that I can then use ListLinePlot

As a first step I tried to do it in 1D (yes, in this case a simple sorting is sufficient, but not in the 2D case)

However,I have a problem, because I do not know how to specify that a variable IS a list.

Concretely

```
BringToFront = 
 Function[{list, pos}, Prepend[list[[pos]], Drop[list, {pos}]]]

BringClosestToFront = 
 Fuction[{list, val}, 
  BringToFront[list, Nearest[list ->Automatic, val]]]

Follow[{}] = {};
Follow[list] = 
 Prepend[list[[1]], 
  Follow[BringClosestToFront[Drop[list, 1], list[[1]]]]]
```

And the BringClosestToFront is not accepted, with a

```
Part::partd: Part specification list[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

I am also worried of the speed of this recursive solution. Do you thing there may be a way to specify it in a more procedural way (i.e. implement insertion-sort)?

Comment: `Prepend` and `Append` based solution can indeed become comparatively slow...

Comment: An alternate style to define functions, using set delayed,  is: `f[x_List,pos_Integer]:=x[[pos]]`.

Comment: This is not what you asked for, but, in case it suits your final objectives better, have you checked `FindShortestTour`?

Comment: For some ideas you can check [this previous thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding/) or [this related MathGroup post][http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Mar/msg00529.html]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FindShortestTour` can solve your problem. You need only choose the greedy algorithm. For example, using the same data as image_doctor:

```
SeedRandom[6];
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}];

FindShortestTour[data, Method -> "Greedy"]
```

> {61.2702, {1, 7, 2, 3, 6, 4, 10, 5, 9, 8}}

```
Show[
  Graphics[{Line[data[[{1, 7, 2, 3, 6, 4, 10, 5, 9, 8}]]], 
     PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[data]}],
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: [greedy.png]]

BTW, the graphics output was generated for me by V9's predictive interface. I didn't write any code for it at all.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another recursive solution based on Nest using an index to the point in the list from which to start.

```
order[points_List, index_Integer] :=  
Nest[With[{elem = Nearest[Last@#, Last@First@#]}, 
 {Join[First@#,elem], DeleteCases[Last@#, elem]}] &, 
 {{points[[index]]}, Drop[points, {index}]}, Length@points - 1] // First
```

It looks more complicated than it actually is ( I know that a more concise implementation is out there ). It begins with a list of the form,  {{start point},{other points}}. Then moves the nearest point from other points onto the end of the start point list. It continues using the last element of the extended list to find the nearest element in the list of remaining points.

Using BG's `data`:

```
ListLinePlot@order[data, 1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot@order[data, 5]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As a guide to speed, 10 thousand elements took around 44 seconds:

```
SeedRandom[6];
data2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10^4, 2}];

Timing[order[data2, 1];]
```

> {43.8883, Null}

A less readable version which maintains duplicate points and is around 20+% faster is as follows:

```
order[points_, index_] := 
 Nest[With[{p = 
       First@Position[Last@#, 
         First@Nearest[Last@#, Last@First@#]]}, {Join[First@#, 
       Take[Last@#, p]], Drop[Last@#, p]}] &, {{points[[index]]}, 
    Drop[points, {index}]}, Length@points - 1] // First
```

Comment: You have used `Length[l]` in your code, but `l` is undefined. I assume this should be `Length[points]`, which may affect the speed estimate.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks for that, a cut and paste job that went badly wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot of syntax I didn't know from your code!

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera that's very kind of you to say. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

One simple way :

```
SeedRandom[6];
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}] ;

findNearest[list_, point_] := SortBy[list, EuclideanDistance[#, point] &][[1]]

copy = data;
output = NestList[findNearest[copy = DeleteCases[copy, #], #] &, copy[[1]], Length[copy] - 1];

GraphicsColumn[{ListLinePlot[data], ListLinePlot[output]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the NestList as a for loop, and the self assignment (overwrite) inside the function argument are very interesting!

Comment: ok,then I temporarily disable and tick it again later

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version based on a recursively defined function `f`:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := f[{x~Join~y[[#]], Drop[y, #]} &@Nearest[y -> Automatic, Last@x]];
f[{x_, {}}] := x;

data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {1000, 2}];
output = f[{{First[data]}, Rest[data]}];
ListLinePlot[output, Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your compact solution!

Comment: This seems to produce the same output as `FindShortestTour` for the given example and it's faster.