# Generating a list of contour pixels for a morphological component

Tags: image-processing

I have a set of pixilated shapes, and after transforming each shape into a morphological component, I want to be able to return the coordinates for pixels that lie on the contour of the shape.  More specifically, I want pixels that have some number of background neighbors in their von Neumann or Moore neighborhoods.

Say this "shape" is a phrase like the following:

http://pixelduke.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/jnbdec2008-hello-world-example2.png

We can isolate and color all of the morphological components / pixilated shapes we care about as follows:

```
shape = Import["http://pixelduke.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/jnbdec2008-hello-world-example2.png"]
m = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[ImageCrop[shape, {300, 100}]]] // Colorize
```

How can we return a von Neumann or Moore-neighborhood connected set of contour pixels for each component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Isolating boundary pixels of each component:

```
EdgeDetect[Image[m /. x_Integer /; x =!= # -> 0 // Rescale]] & /@ (Union[Flatten[m]]-1)
```

[image]

2) If you need to wrap a polygon around each - please see:

- [**Character edge finding**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/637/13)
- [**Fourier Descriptors**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FourierDescriptors/)
- [**Using Formulas… for Everything—From a Complex Analysis Class to Political Cartoons to Music Album Covers**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/19/using-formulas-for-everything-from-a-complex-analysis-class-to-political-cartoons-to-music-album-covers/)
- [**Even More Formulas… for
  Everything—From Filled Algebraic Curves to the Twitter Bird, the
  American Flag, Chocolate Easter Bunnies, and the Superman Solid**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/08/15/even-more-formulas-for-everything-from-filled-algebraic-curves-to-the-twitter-bird-the-american-flag-chocolate-easter-bunnies-and-the-superman-solid/)

Comment: Thanks.  As a quick question, can you explain the Range[12] choice?

Comment: @user9408 In your image you have 10 letter and 2 punctuation signs. Also `Union[Flatten[m]] `. Could you please register a name here so it is easier to refer to it?

Comment: Sorry, there's no trouble with your answer, and I accepted it.  The "trouble" comment wasn't referring to your answer, and I'll delete it.